# Product of Divisors

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, division

## Challenge

Given a positive integer, return the product of its divisors, including itself.

This is [sequence A007955 in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A007955).

## Test Cases

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 8
5: 5
6: 36
7: 7
8: 64
9: 27
10: 100
12: 1728
14: 196
24: 331776
25: 125
28: 21952
30: 810000
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins!

Comment: Interesting note (though probably not that useful for this challenge): the product of all divisors of n is always n^((number of divisors of n)/2).

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÑP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MSA//@NTAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ñ    # divisors
 P   # product
```

Comment: By first look I'd say this solution belongs under P, but something holds me off..

Comment: This problem is obviously NP.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 3 bytes

```
â ×
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4iDX&input=MjQ=)

### Explanation

```
â ×  // implicit integer input

â    // get integer divisors
  ×  // get product of array
```

Comment: Damn it, how did you ninja me?! :p Will delete mine when I get to a computer (whenever that might be).

Comment: @Shaggy I'm surprised, since I just found out about both `â` and `×` when writing this answer

Comment: I was slowed down by the min. character limit!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Leaky Nun!

```python
f=lambda i,k=1:k>i or k**(i%k<1)*f(i,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCoMwEADvfcVeCrtxD93YQhH1I6WHiE27RKPEXHx9GpjTDMx@5t8W21L8sLh1mh0oh0G6MCpsCYIxqNfQCxmPtTRCxVevoBEWPTImF78fFBYhal5iWe5sKw@2T25v7@4CsCeNGeuAqPwB)

Comment: `(1,k)[i%k<1]` is equivalent to `k**(i%k<1)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ÆDP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm0vA////jUwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
Z\p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pyqm4P9/MwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

*-1 thanks to ovs*

```hs
f n=product[x|x<-[2..n],n`mod`x<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcLRCoIwFAbgVzmXCr/ijloG2hv4BGvkyCTJzWEK56J3X318L/t5P5clxol8F7Z1PB67lq@0meY89wZ@cOs4SKtMdHb21JGzob9TchPKrhS22e@UCGgiSVPSCowSFWqccEaDC1QBxVAV@L8GNygLE38)

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 12 bytes

```
/o
\i@/Bdt&*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00HfKaVETev/fyMTAA)

#### Explanation

This is just the regular framework for decimal I/O:

```
/o
\i@/...
```

Then the program is:

```
B    Get all divisors of the input.
dt   Get the stack depth minus 1.
&*   Multiply the top two stack elements that many times, folding multiplication
     over the stack.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 43 bytes

```
[ dup [1,b] [ dupd divisor? ] count 2 / ^ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY09C8IwGIT3/opzl2pi6@fgKC4u4lQqxDRqsE1i8kYQ8bfXUhWO4zk4eM5CkvXtYb/dbZa4KW9UjUbQta/UC3NR4cvnaCRpa36z1qcGziuip/PaEIK6R2Vkd18l290SQXpB8pokA5AKBG1cpJC8wMAxQYYcU8wwxwJsDMbBMvAuOfgckzHebYEqOhRseCrRc4VKP3Swfo0S0sbOyjHCEWXbCPcX2Ui9KYWslfDtBw)

Uses the formula `n^((number of divisors of n)/2)`.

Usually `mod 0 =` (7 bytes) is shorter than `divisor?` (8 bytes), but the latter is used here to auto-load `math.functions` to disambiguate `^` (which happens to appear in a regex lib). Auto-use is weird. The unambiguous alternative to `^` exists (`fpow`), but it's longer.

```
[                ! anonymous lambda
  dup [1,b]      ! ( n {1..n} )
  [ ... ] count  ! count the elements that satisfy the predicate...
    dupd         !   ( n i -- n n i )
    divisor?     !   ( n ? ) tests if i is a divisor of n
  2 / ^          ! halve the divisor count and raise n to the power
]
```

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```
USE: math.primes.factors
[ divisors product ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsIwEEX3@YrrD5Q@rI@6FnHTjbgSFzFObbBNazIRRPz2GlqFy@UODJxTScWdHY6HfbkrcCdrqEEruR4rstLcyE278kax7szvbPSlRW@J@dVbbRiOHp6MCu8bsS8LOGUlq1qIGZgcQ5vesxNvJEiRYY4cCyyxwhpJjCRFMkcakiNdIYvxCVbbYoIFQksuqkZbJ0646qd2YQaD7uoV4zy0sv@jOs8jK4JqSNrhCw)

Uses `divisors` built-in, but obviously the library import is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
*Fs{yP
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aFs%7ByP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A12%0A14%0A24%0A25%0A28%0A30&debug=0).

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCa1AvPL/f2MDAA)

Comment: Me scrolling through answers: plain monospaced code, plain monospaced code, plain... bold, serif code? :-P

Comment: @ETHproductions Hehe.

Comment: @ETHproductions I actually coded this answer on iOS which means I can't actually see the characters.

Comment: That's... quite impressive.

Comment: @ETHproductions remember ESMin?

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Now that is a name I have not heard in a long, long time... ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Well, at least Neim has a codepage...and ESMin is essentially superseded by Japt...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ESMin is/was a completely different beast from Japt... it had a codepage, but the codepage was had 1024 chars :P

Comment: @MamaFunRoll Well, they're both essentially JavaScript, just ESMin is much longer and uses Unicode. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
v=scan():1;prod(v[!v[1]%%v])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8y2ODkxT0PTytC6oCg/RaMsWrEs2jBWVbUsVvO/2X8A)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 26 bytes

```
31 C9 8D 71 01 89 F8 FF C1 99 F7 F9 85 D2 75 03 0F AF F1 39 F9 7C EE 89 F0 C3
```

The above code defines a function that takes a single parameter (the input value, a positive integer) in `EDI` (following the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) used on Gnu/Unix), and returns a single result (the product of divisors) in `EAX`.

Internally, it computes the product of divisors using an (extremely inefficient) iterative algorithm, similar to [pizzapants184's C submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130466/58518). Basically, it uses a counter to loop through *all* of the values between 1 and the input value, checking to see if the current counter value is a divisor of the input. If so, it multiplies that into the running total product.

**Ungolfed assembly language mnemonics:**

```
; Parameter is passed in EDI (a positive integer)
ComputeProductOfDivisors:
   xor   ecx, ecx        ; ECX <= 0  (our counter)
   lea   esi, [rcx + 1]  ; ESI <= 1  (our running total)
.CheckCounter:
   mov   eax, edi        ; put input value (parameter) in EAX
   inc   ecx             ; increment counter
   cdq                   ; sign-extend EAX to EDX:EAX
   idiv  ecx             ; divide EDX:EAX by ECX
   test  edx, edx        ; check the remainder to see if divided evenly
   jnz   .SkipThisOne    ; if remainder!=0, skip the next instruction
   imul  esi, ecx        ; if remainder==0, multiply running total by counter
.SkipThisOne:
   cmp   ecx, edi        ; are we done yet? compare counter to input value
   jl    .CheckCounter   ; if counter hasn't yet reached input value, keep looping
   
   mov   eax, esi        ; put our running total in EAX so it gets returned
   ret
```

The fact that the `IDIV` instruction uses hard-coded operands for the dividend cramps my style a bit, but I think this is pretty good for a language that has no built-ins but basic arithmetic and conditional branches!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
KΠ
```

Explanation:

```
K  # Gets the divisors of a number
 Π # Product of array
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJLzqAiLCIiLCIzMCJd)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 24 bytes

```
Prompt X
1
For(A,1,X
If not(remainder(X,A
AAns
End
```

Full program: prompts user for input; returns output in `Ans`, a [special variable](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/ans) that (basically) stores the value of the latest value calculated.

Explanation:

```
Prompt X             # 3 bytes, Prompt user for input, store in X
1                    # 2 bytes, store 1 in Ans for use later
For(A,1,X            # 7 bytes, for each value of A from 1 to X
If not(remainder(X,A # 8 bytes, If X is divisible by A...
AAns                 # 3 bytes, ...store (A * Ans) in Ans
End                  # 1 byte, end For( loop
```

Comment: You didn't actually include the bytecount.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Whoops! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
p,a;f(x){for(p=1,a=x;a;a--)p*=x%a?1:a;return p;}
```

-4 bytes thanks to Cody Gray

A function that takes in an integer and returns the product of it's divisors.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgEEXXeoohENBGF2mhi0ylF@lmSGqZRY1IWoTg2a3p6sHn/Tfb1zzXGg2hV1nvfk0qutGQy0hI1up4crmn@zgRpuf2SQEilsphgzdxUN@VFw27FMfCKMVRYHAwIjDc4NI4DPxXREzN8qrrz8sE/XV5hM4AG/CKtW7fIkv9AQ)

Ungolfed:

```
int proddiv(int input) {
    int total = 1, loopvar;
    for(loopvar = input; loopvar > 0; --loopvar) {
    // for loopvar from input down to 1...
        total *= (input % loopvar) ? 1 : loopvar;
        // ...If the loopvar is a divisor of the input, multiply the total by loopvar;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: You can save 4 bytes by (1) counting backwards, (2) removing the parentheses around the `p*=` expression, and (3) putting a statement in the body of the `for` loop to drop a comma. I also like to use global vars, rather than adding extra parameters. This avoids undefined behavior, without costing any bytes. Final version: `p,a;f(x){for(p=1,a=x;a;--a)p*=x%a?1:a;return p;}`

Comment: You can replace `return p;` with `p=p;` and save five bytes.

Comment: To save another byte, you can replace `p,a;f(x)` with `f(x,p,a)`.

Comment: If you use local instead of global variables, you can even get rid of the entire `return p;` and save not five, but nine bytes. ([TIO](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgEADP@oolIGijB1voIVb6kV4WxbKHGgmhCMG3W9PTwDATzDuE3pOsumhUR/HWpXWT6KtDh8aocvFV4NMu6FqnvMMHKcvvSlHBwdlpyHF2TgQerAOCB9wG55n@CSvbqJKcxDUuIO7xlScNpCFJUmq8jbf@Aw))

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgEADP@oolIGijh7TQQ7bSj/QiWsseakTSIgTfbpOeBoYZb17e9561wyir2uJSZLbOVjTGoconW4W7T7PD8lw/JUHG1imt8HaU5HehoGDj7DCEnB07gYUJgeAGl53jSP@E5bJXUQ7iHGYQ1/BIgwbSECUptb@Nt/4D)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7), 32 bytes

```js
n=>g=(i=n)=>i?i**!(n%i)*g(i-1):1
```

Saved a couple of bytes by borrowing Leaky's tip on [musicman's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130458/58974).

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>g=(i=n)=>i?i**!(n%i)*g(i-1):1
)(i.value=1)();oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)()
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

---

### Alternative (ES6), 32 bytes

```js
n=>g=(i=n)=>i?(n%i?1:i)*g(i-1):1
```

Comment: Why not just the ES6-compatible `(n%i?1:i)`? (This wouldn't save any byte, though.)

Comment: @Arnauld: because half 6 is clearly too early in the morning for phone golf! :D I had the ternary reversed when I spotted Leaky's tip!

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>24</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to lirtosiast

```
:√(Ans^sum(not(fPart(Ans/randIntNoRep(1,Ans
```

Comment: Do you need the `int(`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Shakespeare), 353 bytes

```
.
Ajax,.
Puck,.
Page,.
Act I:.
Scene I:.
[Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:
You cat
Puck:
Listen to thy heart
[Exit Ajax]
[Enter Page]
Scene II:.
Puck:
You sum you cat
Page:
Is Ajax nicer I?If so, is remainder of the quotient Ajax I nicer zero?If not, you product you I.Is Ajax nicer I?If so, let us return to scene II
Scene III:.
Page:
Open thy heart
[Exeunt]
```

Ungolfed version:

```
The Tragedy of the Product of a Moor's Factors in Venice.

Othello, a numerical man.
Desdemona, a product of his imagination.
Brabantio, a senator, possibly in charge of one Othello's factories.

Act I: In which tragedy occurs.

Scene I: Wherein Othello and Desdemona have an enlightened discussion.

[Enter Othello and Desdemona]

Othello:
  Thou art an angel!

Desdemona:
  Listen to thy heart.

[Exit Othello]
[Enter Brabantio]

Scene II: Wherein Brabantio expresses his internal monologue to Desdemona.

Desdemona:
  Thou art the sum of thyself and the wind!

Brabantio:
  Is Othello jollier than me?
  If so, is the remainder of the quotient of Othello and I better than nothing?
  If not, thou art the product of thyself and me.
  IS Othello jollier than me?
  If so, let us return to scene II!

Scene III: An Epilogue.

Brabantio:
  Open thy heart!

[Exeunt]
```

I'm using [this SPL compiler](https://github.com/drsam94/Spl) to run the program.

Run with:

```
$ python splc.py product-of-divisors.spl > product-of-divisors.c
$ gcc product-of-divisors.c -o pod.exe
$ echo 30 | ./pod
810000
```

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
ƒ*
```

Another language with built ins for `divisors` and `product`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///YJK3///8bmQAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @rak1507.

```apl
f←×/∘∪⊢∨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TD0/Ufdcx41LHqUdeiRx0rHvVu/v@obypQIk3B0OQ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```go
func p(n int)int{p,i:=1,1
for;i<=n;i++{if n%i<1{p*=i}}
return p}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEXXzSmGgtCYKAY30jbgwgN4hVKaMminIaSrkJO4KYKH8CjexlS7GN5i-O89nv04v23T3pq-g6FBYjjY0XnIzeDz1-TN7vQ5m4lasAUBkufpgpVYaiUVM6OrsNZUoRABDdAGaxXsVmOMzHV-cgQ2rp7Lz7NUCg6BZWkMCKUGVSXWcDwkCrG8spTfX11q3alAmeLIOcsiW13z_OcX)

#### Ungolfed

- -1 swapping `==0` for `<1` (@Steffan)

```go
func product(s []int) int {
	p := 1
	for _,e := range s {
		p *= e
	}
	return p
}
func divisors(n int) (d []int) {
	for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
		if n % i == 0 {
			d = append(d, i)
		}
	}
	return d
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBSgQxEEXXySk-A0LitDLiRpzJHVy4E5HQSYZi7CSk026GPombRvAQXsA7eBvTmXF04aY-9Qver6rXt22YPqJud3pr0WnynLoYUsbCdXnxPmR3cfP16QbfIqZghjaLHg-P5LNEKdhzFnGrcMWZCwlPjZ27pH3B9fO0jM8VLGcjZ8nmIXlEPvJKNPRCfUi98KhAYX7Q-wOOKnpddKPgiy6XlUkOHmfFVgqr6jADBR2j9UaYBiSLN_4NNXw8XnNfs-dbxX9BuF79BpUnXN6lstKzF9ScXnBanKSUc8qRPU0H_QY)

Comment: You can do `n%i<1` instead of `n%i==0`

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 22 bytes

```
[:|~b/a=b'\`a|q=q*a}?q
```

### Explanation

```
[:|           FOR a  = 1; a <= input (b); a++
 b/a=b'\`a    'a' is a proper divisor if integer division == float division
~         |   IF that's true
q=q*a         THEN multiply running total q (starts as 1) by that divsor
}             NEXT
?q            Print q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

- Thanks @ovs for 2 bytes: `m*=n%i>0 or i`

```python
i=n=input()
m=1
while i:m*=n%i>0 or i;i-=1
print m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2zzYzr6C0REOTK9fWkKs8IzMnVSHTKlfLNk81085AIb9IIdM6UxcoVVCUmVeikPv/v7EBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
n->n^(numdiv(n)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y4vTiOvNDcls0wjT1PfSPN/Wn6RRh5QzlBHwdhAR6GgKDOvBCigpKBrByTSgKo0Nf8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(n)prod(find(~mod(n,1:n)))
```

This defines an anonymous function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs6AoP0UjLTMvRaMuF8jK0zG0ytPU1PyfmFesYWyg@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45 bytes

```php
for($p=1;$d++<$argn;)$argn%$d?:$p*=$d;echo$p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkZKJk/T8tv0hDpcDW0FolRVvbBixjrQmmVFVS7K1UCrRsVVKsU5Mz8lUKrP//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

for those who can't view deleted answers (DavidC's answer), this is the code in Mathematica with the help of @MartinEnder

```
1##&@@Divisors@#&
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 45 bytes

`lambda _:_**(sum(_%-~i<1for i in range(_))/2)`

Let `x` be a number. Both `y` and `z` will be divisors of `x` if `y * z = x`. Therefore, `y = x / z`. Let's say a number `d` has 6 divisiors, due to this observation the divisors will be `a`, `b`, `c`, `d / a`, `d / b`, `d / b`. If we multiply all these numbers (the point of the puzzle), we obtain `d * d * d = d ^ 3`. In general, for `e` with  a number of `f` divisors, the product of said divisors will be `e ^ (f / 2)`, which is what the lambda does.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRId4qXktLo7g0VyNeVbcu08YwLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjXlNT30jzP1w0J7O4RAMiZahjaKipqR1taKRjaKJjBESmOkYWOsYGsVZcCgoFRZl5JRppGpmamv8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```java
n->{int r=n,d=0;for(;++d<n;)r*=n%d<1?d:1;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Ba8MwDIXv/RWiEEiW1DT0VscrPe4wdig7jR28OC7OUtnISiGU/PbM7baDeEJ6evp6fdUbHzrszfcSxq/BtdAOOkZ41Q7htgL4m0bWnOTqnYFL2uUnJofnj0/QdI7FwwrQpzwxshuEHbFl51G8IL@jpuktdKTZE1i14Ob55pCBFFZGbaX1lMuyNA3Kgp4UZqapD2ZfS@p4JASS8yIfD5IT8vspgoJaJmkU7LapKct/CIDTFLm7CD@yCImSbb7OdmYPmclwXQFWYIUOYZiOMeHlWBS/6fPqXvPyAw)

Thanks LeakyNun for saving 1 byte!

Comment: `n->{int r=n,d=0;for(;++d<n;)r*=n%d<1?d:1;return r;}`

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/5ebf758a930fa4f4140d49db53b3ce8359aa1b65?at=master), 4 bytes

Hex:

```
1A 3A 54 27
```

Explanation:

```
1A - Input as an integer
3A - Factors
54 - Product
27 - Output (with newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->r{eval (1..r).select{|c|r%c<1}*?*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166oOrUsMUdBw1BPr0hTrzg1JzW5pLomuaZINdnGsFbLXqv2P0jO2EBTLzexoLoms6agtKRYIS06M7b2PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 48 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
p=1:For i=1To[A1]:p=p*IIf([A1]mod i,1,i):Next:?p
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a)(1..$a|?{!($a%$_)})-join'*'|iex
```

-1 byte thanks to mazzy!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVFTw1BPTyWxxr5aEchTVYnXrNXUzcrPzFPXUq/JTK34//@/sQEA)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f@/ILEoMVdDJVFTw1BPTyWxxr5aEchTVYnXrNXUzcrPzFPXUq/JTK34//@/sQEA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 23 bytes

Hexdump:

```
44 8b c1 6a 01 41 8b c0 99 f7 f9 85 d2 75 04 5a
f7 ea 50 e2 f0 58 c3
```

Uses the Microsoft calling convention - input in `ecx`, output in `eax`. It only supports 32-bit intermediate and final results, to make the code shorter.

Assembly code (can be assembled by `ml64`):

```
.CODE
my  PROC
        mov r8d, ecx;   // r8 = input number
        push 1;         // number on stack = product
    myloop:
        mov eax, r8d;   // prepare divisor
        cdq;            // in edx:eax
        idiv ecx;       // divide
        test edx, edx;  // check remainder
        jnz myskip;     // nonzero? - not a divisor
        pop rdx;        // get product from stack
        imul edx;       // multiply
        push rax;       // save product on stack
    myskip:
        loop myloop;    // check next number, down to 0
        pop rax;        // restore stack to proper position
        ret;            // return
my    ENDP
END
```

I used x64 only for its calling convention - so I would not have to save and restore a general-purpose register - x64 calling conventions permit clobbering `r8` and `r9`.

I used a variant of `imul` with implicit input and output in `eax` - it has a shorter encoding (2 bytes), and doesn't require `mov` to return the result from the function at the end. So it actually multiplies the quotients, not the divisors; the final result remains correct.

Disassembly (to see instruction sizes):

```
00007FF7F91E1870 44 8B C1             mov         r8d,ecx  
00007FF7F91E1873 6A 01                push        1  
    myloop:
00007FF7F91E1875 41 8B C0             mov         eax,r8d  
00007FF7F91E1878 99                   cdq  
00007FF7F91E1879 F7 F9                idiv        eax,ecx  
00007FF7F91E187B 85 D2                test        edx,edx  
00007FF7F91E187D 75 04                jne         myloop+0Eh (07FF7F91E1883h)  
00007FF7F91E187F 5A                   pop         rdx  
00007FF7F91E1880 F7 EA                imul        edx  
00007FF7F91E1882 50                   push        rax  
    myskip:
00007FF7F91E1883 E2 F0                loop        myloop (07FF7F91E1875h)  
00007FF7F91E1885 58                   pop         rax  
00007FF7F91E1886 C3                   ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
ΠḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yChzu6/v8HAA)

builtins.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
*rk
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIqcmsiLCIzMCJd)

Multiplication analog of [the addition version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252241/107299).

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 60 bytes

```
A+N+S:-A>0,A-1+N+Q,(N mod A<1,S is Q*A;S=Q);S=1.
N+S:-N+N+S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/31HbTzvYStfRzkDHUdcQyAnU0fBTyM1PUXC0MdQJVsgsVgjUcrQOtg3UBBKGelxg5X4gXXr/rXQVjEy0/XQUyosyS1Jz8jT8NPX@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
ðΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//8IZzC/7/NwUA)

```
ð       implicit input; get list of divisors
 Π      product of list; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Fp
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUZwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MzAmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
Fp  # Implicit input
F   # Factors
 p  # Product
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

```
{[*] grep $_%%*,1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OlorViG9KLVAQSVeVVVLx1BPTyW@9r@1QnFipYKSSryVQnWahkq8Zq2SQlp@kQJQ2tjgPwA)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 19 bytes

```
*/}.I.(=<.)(%i.@>:)
```

Explanation coming later...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBFr6tXqeehq2NnqaGqqZeg52VpoKJlzYRM0A)

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 95, 88 bytes

```
function l(k)
n=0
l=1
do while(n<k)
n=n+1
if(MODULO(k,n)==0)then
l=l*n
end if
end do
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdC9DsIgEAfwnadghFqTQv1MZHPUdPIBGgstKR4NYnx8xLoYT5YjPy53/2B8iKGFZW8@lzQF34f2RqO@R0LzmYKFSIuSOib4r0gkNZIVkjWSDZItkh2SPRJRYcIZBY4k/xCOKXGGOm/U0NHvf0vmAddoPeT3kRNQFXFKkM7T52CdZnCYFRaCWMPOzfFyathYAleq4nHQkNtdAfNca@bS@XdJ6QU)

**Ungolfed:**

```
integer function l(k)
    implicit none
    integer :: n, k

    n=0
    l=1
    do while (n<k)
        n=n+1
        if (MODULO(k,n) == 0) then
            l=l*n
        end if
    end do

end function l
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 23 bytes

```
h(x)==x^(#divisors x/2)
```

This is a translation in Axiom of alephalpha solution

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [3 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
Þ┤â
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=KlwqLg==&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4Cjk=&flags=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `*\*.`

`*\` fold with multiplication

`*.` a list of factors of the input

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
f(x,y=1:x)=prod(y[x.%y.<1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jQqfS1tCqQtO2oCg/RaMyukJPtVLPxjBW839BUWZeSU6enkaanoahlbGBpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
─ε*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIZzW7X@/zfkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnsuCy5DI04DI04jI04TICIlMuIwsuYwMA)

**Explanation:**

```python
─    # Get a list of divisors of the (implicit) input-integer
 ε   # Reduce this list by:
  *  #  Subtracting
     # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 24 bytes

```python
f=compose(prod,divisors)
```

Straightforward and direct. Is there a shorter way to do it in Sage?

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap`, 31 bytes

```perl
map$.*="@F"%$_?1:$_,2..$_;$_=$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUBFT8tWycFNSVUl3t7QSiVex0hPTyXeWiXeVkXv/39Do3/5BSWZ@XnF/3UTCwA)