# Am I a Sophie Germain prime?

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, decision-problem, primes

A [Sophie Germain Prime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) is a [prime number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) **P** such that **2P+1** is prime as well. Given a *prime number* as input, your task is to determine whether it is a Sophie Germain Prime.

[Standard Input/Output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) rules and [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
This is a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem), so standard rules for this tag apply (returning two distinct and *consistent* values for each case, e.g: `True`/`False`).

---

## Test Cases

#### Truthy (Sophie Germain primes)

These are the first few of them (OEIS [A005384](https://oeis.org/A005384)):

```
2, 3, 5, 11, 23, 29, 41, 53, 83, 89, 113
```

#### Falsy

```
7, 13, 17, 31, 37, 43, 47
```

---

Please note that answers with explanations are encouraged!

It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), hence the shortest code in bytes in every language wins!

Comment: Can I flip the True/False (i.e. output "False" if the prime is a SG prime, "True" otherwise)?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Of course, any value can be used as long as you specify it.

Comment: Personally, I think ir would have been best to not gusrantee primality of the input.

Comment: Does "returning two distinct values for each case" imply the values must be consistent rather than the tag text "either `truthy` or `falsy`" or may we return inconsistent, but `if-testable`, values?

Comment: *You should have a set of values for truthy and their complement for falsy, if you choose to have them inconsistent.* Can I define SG primes as truthy values? :P

Comment: @Dennis Of course... not

Comment: **EDIT:** The values must be consistent

Comment: That is not a problem if we use the tag text of "either `truthy` or `falsey`" though (this means the results must be `if-testable`, which, unless there is some eso-lang out there that has that bizarre feature, S.G. primes wont be).

Comment: .. See [this meta-post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/53748) by Peter Taylor regarding that definition.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I will keep them consistent though

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close because I have a dupe hammer, but this seems like it's a dupe of [Is it a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/31716), since the only difference is that the input isn't the number you're testing. Adding the offset (**2n + 1**) is a pretty trivial modification.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I think it is different though... That one also asks for a full program.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem this one checks for two numbers?

Comment: @NickT No, the input is guaranteed to be prime

Answer (score 7):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 24 bytes

```
01 FF FF C7 6A 01 59 89 F8 FF C1 99 F7 F9 85 D2 75 F5 39 F9 0F 94 C0 C3
```

The above code defines a function that takes a single parameter (the input value, known to be a prime) in `EDI` (following the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) used on Gnu/Unix), and returns a Boolean result in `AL` (`1` if the input is a Sophie Germain prime, `0` otherwise).

The implementation is very similar [to the solution to this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131494/58518), since all we really have to do is determine whether a number is prime using as little code as possible, which means an inefficient iterative loop.

Basically, we take the input and immediately transform it into `2 × input + 1`. Then, starting with a counter set to 2, we loop through and check to see if the counter is a factor. The counter is incremented each time through the loop. As soon as a factor is found, the loop ends and that factor is compared against `2 × input + 1`. If the factor is equal to the test value, then that means we didn't find any smaller factors, and therefore the number must be prime. And since we have thus confirmed that `2 × input + 1` is prime, this means that `input` must be a Sophie Germain prime.

**Ungolfed assembly language mnemonics:**

```
IsSophieGermainPrime:
   add   edi, edi            ; input *= 2
   inc   edi                 ; input += 1
   push  1
   pop   rcx                 ; counter = 1
   
.CheckDivisibility:
   inc   ecx                 ; increment counter
   mov   eax, edi            ; EAX = input (needs to be in EAX for IDIV; will be clobbered)
   cdq                       ; sign-extend EAX into EDX:EAX
   idiv  ecx                 ; EDX:EAX / counter
   test  edx, edx            ; check the remainder to see if divided evenly
   jnz   .CheckDivisibility  ; keep looping if not divisible by this one
   
   cmp   ecx, edi            ; compare counter to input
   sete  al                  ; set true if first found factor is itself;
   ret                       ;          otherwise, set false
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/),  <s>46 43 41</s>  40 bytes

-1 byte using [code suggested elsewhere by Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) (`2*n+1` may be calculated as `n-~n` - that is, `2*n+1=n-(-1-n)`)

```python
f=lambda n,p=3:p>n or(n-~n)%p*f(n,p+2)>0
```

A recursive function.

Returns `True` if the prime number input, `n`, is a Sophie Germain prime and `False` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEETP@hVzkSa6BZuk1Baaf6losKCbUHPx4q/HjYflvZmBTZ/8iGxKCfNzeV1vC5jSbKfkGXFT3H5ZH9IxKKlPRvtzCXFDvr8zVoYyBEvoCV1HMKJmJDjxXvxSb6ybyCAUdEIruxU6yW7Q036XtpXz/yuhaX1DCKomXX4)**

Works by multiplying the remainders of the division of the candidate number `n-~n` (which is equal to `2*n+1`) after dividing by `p`, while `p` is less than `n`, starting at `p=3` and incrementing by `2` at each iteration. This is sufficient since `n` is greater that the square root of `2*n+1` (`n-~n`) for `n` greater than `2`. Also, since `2` is a Sophie Germain prime we can start testing with `p=3` and add `2` at each iteration rather than `1`. If the original `n` was greater than `2` the product of the resulting remainders is returned, so if the candidate has any factors the resulting `0` forces the result to be `0` too. The final `>0` forces all the positive products to return `True` and the `0`s to return `False` (to fulfil the "distinct and consistent" requirement).

Also beats:

...the 41 byte Python 3 (with sympy):

```python
import sympy
lambda n:sympy.isprime(n-~n)
```

...and the 42 byte Python 2 full program **[Try It](https://tio.run/##JY7BDoIwDIbP7Cl6MYDssg2CEPcwCDMswa7BGfXpZ4eH5vuav2lL37gG1GkOi7NlWSa0@uyRXrGqGyXIGvFe/eYATzRSY7Wg3WMEumLicXGM2m163JZpjO4ZxT3skAU8QqUlGAmdBKUkaFY9SGjZO/ZLriFnLD2ToZiGc8NsuW/7ehTF/@axvnAfN0N@N/0A)**:

```python
n=2*input()+1
p=3
while n%p:p+=2
print p<n
```

Comment: [You do not need the brackets](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEXXeorZSJv6BSehSAvNXSI1WNDpULPp6ePo7j/e4@tenqv4WvP0Su/7nEigkx81Cq0btb6TM7uTxmuSmXJr1rhmc@XxKbSINQjocQMzOIBtDPABfkBgNx4Pui1S/jmoucQG9vMjV78)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEXXeorZSBP9gjOhSAvNXSI1WNBJiNl4@hjdvcf7/Pypj6TSWlye4XVbAynyInP2SqkYOeqJ7SH7S9CVoumxe4upUL2/K21KRuAw4gpmsAN3mCAOMsGxnfe7XDat/zloOPsB/edntn0B), forgot to remove the space

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder was busy editing in for 43...I noticed :)

Comment: What is it with these weird looking recursive functions and out-golfing me...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I wrote about that in the answer - the OP requests "two distinct values for each case", I had meant to ask, and have now.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Actually seems to be allowed to remove `>0`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yeah I confirmed it, and have now updated the code, thanks!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry, I have updated the rules, I'm very sorry for the confusion I created. It was an issue spotted by Dennis, that one may choose the SG primes as the truthy values, and that would be trivial

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder righto, I rolled it back.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=3:n%k^k/2>0<f(n,k+2)or k>n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCoMwDEWft6/Ii9CygGtaccr0UwZ1oyjVWKQv@/ousodwTm7CTd8870ylhGH12/TxwBgH23MVX7Gm8f4MSpIb6f2AOHIJwsnn9wwLgyIEi9AgGINAotQhOPFG/HFOd96sRlCtmCRGaOXDCp3srtX99ZKOhTNsPqmA/35dfg)

#### Alternate versions

```python
f=lambda n,k=3:n%k^1>0<f(n-1,k+2)or k>n
```

```python
f=lambda n,k=3:~-n%k>0<f(n-1,k+2)or k>n
```

```python
f=lambda n,k=3:n%k!=1==f(n-1,k+2)or k>n
```

Comment: I usually don't ask for one on Python answers... But could we have an explanation as to what is going on?

Comment: I've recreated [the top solution](https://tio.run/##NY7hCoIwFIV/51OciGCjQboppqSPEsxsKMspYj96ejsWDe7ut3PvOWx6L90Y9Loe4KqnHZrWIihfmTIc/c2fdR1fnaBy0nKc4esQRe3DYdPANVlG4Jkfy2sOEIIu7CvQKGFDC/E3o0YsJZghPDnI6GvktTqKjV3uHXpGaAWjkCkkiYIm6kIhJWfky1bFNjNSQeQkKgm74YZhT/lOc35rN819WDDYSTj1y5frBw "Python 2 – Try It Online") in a more verbose way, altering some of the code but leaving the same logic. Though I'm still not quite sure why it works.

Comment: @totallyhuman If `(2*n+1)%k` gives **0**, `n%k` gives either **0** or **(k-1)/2**. Since **n** is prime, `n%k` cannot give **0**, so it suffices to check for the latter case. I'll add a more detailed explanation tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, 4 bytes

```
EQZp
```

Prints 1 for a Sophie Germain prime and 0 otherwise.

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=EQZp&inputs=53&version=20.1.1)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a number
E       % Multiply by 2 
Q       % Add one
Zp      % Check if this is a prime number
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica , 13 bytes

```
PrimeQ[2#+1]&
```

Comment: TIO link? (mathics)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

*Almost an anagram for Pyth.*

```
P_hy
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=P_hy&input=23&debug=0)

Other semi-anagrams: `Pt_y`, `P_tyh`.

**How?**

```
   y   # Double
  h    # Increment
 _     # Negate
P      # Prime?
```

P for positive argument factorizes; to test primality one should provide the negation of the number tested.

Comment: Why do you need to negate?

Comment: @totallyhuman P with negative argument check if -argument is prime, P with positive argument returns list of prime factors

Comment: It'd be great if you could find a way to make this an anagram of Pyth...

Comment: @daniero You're assumed prime input.

Comment: @BetaDecay I can do `P_tyh` (inc, double, dec)

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
{2*)mp}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/2khLM7eg9n/df0NDYwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
x>p
```

Prints `1` if the *prime number* input is a Sophie Germain prime, and `0` if it is not (prints `1` if double the input plus one is prime).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/wq7g/39TAA)**

#### How?

```
x>p - implicit input: number n
x   - pop n then push n, 2*n
 >  - pop 2*n then push 2*n+1
  p - pop 2*n+1 then push is prime? (2*n+1) {True:1; False:0}
    - implicit print of top of stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun. -1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.*

```
lambda n:all((n-~n)%i for i in range(2,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsIwEEX3@Yq7ERKIizxKbaFfoi4iNhqI05Jm48Zfj1MXDgznDBfmru/6XMi2OF1aDq/bPYDGkLOUdPyQOiTEpSAhEUqgxyytJqVanbe6YcLZajiNTsMYDctqBw3P3rGf9h32jKVnMgzTce6Ynm/fX4X4d/z@jgI8a0lUEWVS7Qs)

Comment: Do you need to check up to `2*n+1`?

Comment: `(2*n+1)` can be `(n-~n)`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, nice, thanks!

Comment: Basically `(2*n+1)` can also be `(n+n+1)` which can be `(n+(n+1))`, which in turn is the same as `(n+-~n)` or `(n-~n)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
×₂+₁ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r///D0R01N2o@aGh/unP7/v6GhMQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ḥ‘ÆP
```

A monadic link returning `1` if the *prime number* input is a Sophie Germain prime, and `0` if it is not (yields `1` if double the input plus one is prime, `0` otherwise).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiWPGmYcbgv4//@/KQA)**

#### How?

```
Ḥ‘ÆP - Link: number n
Ḥ    - double n
 ‘   - increment
  ÆP - is prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
ᚫ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@Gs1XYf5k7o@f/f0NAYAA)

-1 thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx).

Comment: Neim has a 1-byte 'check for primality' token.

Comment: @Okx Oh I searched for it.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 43 bytes

```
i;f(x){for(x=x*2+1,i=1;x%++i;);return x>i;}
```

Returns `0` if `x` is a Sophie Germain prime, `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BCoMwEEX3niIIQtLYRRKllcGexE2xTcmisQQLAfHsqVgoFPzOch7v/5n@@Oj7lBxZHsVkh8BjGw9aqtK1imIhpSNB4T6@g2fx4mhOzo/seXWei2zK2DKvsKwsz4tb5/OSWa6FoG1iIKkhUQoijfN0A1GFA2sceN5Bzc7xq/YHO//DJyziOoUtg18z2Ko2ur5gdeb0AQ)

## C (gcc), 38 bytes

```
i;f(x){for(x=x*2+1,i=1;x%++i;);x=x>i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BCoMwEEX3niIIQtLYRaLSymBP4qakpMyiaZEuAuLZ02ChUPA7y/94f2bc8e5cSkxeRjX75yTjEA9Wm5oHQ7HSmklRzi5MS@LwFo8rB6mKuRB5XlOOvCyr2xjKWnhplaJt0kDSQWIMRBb32R6iFhd2uPC8g/qd41ftD47hh09YxOsMthr8WoOtdmPXF6zOkj4)

Comment: Shave off 2 bytes by using `i=1;` at the start.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thanks, but then the function would not be reusable, and [therefore not a valid submission](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable).

Comment: Suggest `x-=~x` instead of `x=x*2+1`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

prints 1 for true and nothing for false

```php
for($d=$n=$argn*2+1;$n%--$d;);echo$d<2;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkrmT9Py2/SEMlxVYlzxYsqGWkbWitkqeqq6uSYq1pnZqcka@SYmNk/f8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia 0.6, 20 bytes

```julia
x->∉(0,(x-~x)%3:x)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 60 bytes

```clj
#((fn[n](some(fn[a](=(mod n a)0))(range 2 n)))(+(* 2 %)1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoAgEAXQqwxE8H9tyn0nCRdSFoWOYXV@s917S0jnm30puPKhT1A0wKazWtwp@p/OYkJMq6g4DiSy092LEWVNj66y5UgaspQP)

This is an anonymous function - to use the function, do this:

```clj
(#(...) {number}) ; This will output a value
```

Returns `False` if prime is a Sophie Germain prime, `True` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
*2Ä j
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KjLEIGo=&input=Nw==) Probably won't get shorter than this...

An alternative solution which might be shorter in other languages:

```
¤Ä n2 j
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=pMQgbjIgag==&input=Nw==) `¤` converts the input to binary, `Ä` appends a 1, and `n2` converts back from base 2 (Japt doesn't have a built-in for converting from binary).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 55 bytes:

```
lambda n:len(filter(lambda p:(2*n+1)%p,range(2,n)))>n-3
```

## Python 2, 48 bytes, different logic:

```
lambda n:all(map(lambda p:(2*n+1)%p,range(2,n)))
```

Comment: `(2*n+1)` can be replaced by `(n-~n)` in both versions.

Comment: Your first version can simply be `lambda n:len(filter((n~-n).__mod__,range(2,n)))>n-3`. Second version is essentially the same as totallyhuman's.

Answer (score 1):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
;*+q:
```

Works like this:

```
;          Input a number
 *+        Double and increase it
   q:      Print 1 or 0 depending on wether the current number is prime
```

edit: don't need prime check on input

Comment: you don't have to test input for primality

Comment: @Uriel Got it :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
p->isprime(2*p+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L9A1y6zuKAoMzdVw0irQNtQ839iQUFOpUaBgq6dAlA8rwTIVAJxlBTSNAo0NXUUwKqLNQwNDDQ1/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia 0.4, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Tanj*

```
x->isprime(x-~x)
```

`isprime` was deprecated in Julia 0.5.

Comment: Identical to the PariGP submission...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder polyglot then?

Comment: you can slightly reduce by computing 2*x+1 with x-~x ?

Comment: `2x+1` is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 7 bytes

```
?µ:*2+1
```

### Explanation

```
?        PRINT
 µ       the result of the prime-test (-1 for true. 0 for false)
  :*2+1  with the input times 2 plus 1 as argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 18 bytes

```
@(x)isprime(2*x+1)
```

Anonymous function.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mG/PfQaNCM7O4oCgzN1XDSKtC21Dzf5qGkSZXmoYxiDDV5AKS5iCmobHmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 2.3.1, 44 bytes

```
lambda{|p|(2...2*p+1).all?{|r|(2*p+1)%r!=0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzPycxNyklsbqmoEbDSE9Pz0irQNtQUy8xJ8e@uqYIKAbmqxYp2hrU1v4vKC0pVkjTSwZKKxhxIfOMUXimXChccxSeofF/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes

```c
f(x,i){for(i=2;i<x;)(x-~x)%i++?:(x=i=0);x=!x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDoIwEADAM31FxZDsBjCgN5fqW0xLdRNsTQWzCcGvV@c4tr1bm7MHaRhXHxOwORIPQgjSfgUrruvrGcSw6ZDE7IS2vOdgp8WNenjPjuPhcVGKw6yfNw7wiexwVcUr/ctDWbmy0R76/oRIqkjjvKSgO1Jb/gE)

Returns `0` if SG prime, `1` otherwise.

Comment: What does GCC do with the empty "true" portion of the conditional operator? How does that get interpreted?

Comment: @CodyGray If the "true" part is empty, [the value of the condition is returned instead of it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html).

Comment: @CodyGray Well, it's only *returned* to nowhere so don't worry.

Comment: Yes, I realize this is completely invalid and meaningless code that only just barely "works" if the stars are aligned just-so. I've been told that doesn't bother anyone on Code Golf, so I'm just trying my best to ignore it. I was intrigued, though, by the GCC extension with an empty "true" portion of a conditional operator, because I'd never seen that before and it wasn't immediately obvious to me how it worked. @Steadybox answered that with a reference, so much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 59 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` to and outputs to the vbe immediate window

Must be run in a clean module *or* the value of `j` must be reset to `0` before use

```vba
n=[2*A1-1]:For i=2To n-1:j=IIf(n/i=Int(n/i),i,j):Next:?j<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
2×1+p
```

Unlike other golflangs, ,,, doesn't have builtins for incrementing and doubling because I thought I'd rather use those bytes for other things. :P

### Explanation

Take input 23 for example.

```
2×1+p

       implicit input                      [23]
2      push 2                              [23, 2]
 ×     pop 23 and 2 and push 23 * 2        [46]
  1    push 1                              [46, 1]
   +   pop 46 and 1 and push 46 + 1        [47]
    p  pop 47 and push whether it is prime [1]
       implicit output                     []
```

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 9 bytes

```
#|2A+1?pz
```

Had to fix an interpreter bug to get this working, so no TIO link.

#### Explanation

```
#|2A+1      The last item in the input, which will become n, equals the first item 
            in the input times two, plus one.
      ?     Mode: query. Returns true if n is in the sequence, and false otherwise.
       pz   Sequence: each item is the next prime after the previous item.
```

Comment: Note current version uses `Z` instead of `z`