# Is it a semiprime?

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, decision-problem, primes

Surprisingly, I don't think we have a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question for determining if a number is [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime).

> A semiprime is a natural number that is the product of two (not necessarily distinct) prime numbers.

Simple enough, but a remarkably important concept.

Given a positive integer, determine if it is a semiprime. Your output can be in any form so long as it gives the same output for any truthy or falsey value. You may also assume your input is reasonably small enough that performance or overflow aren't an issue.

Test cases:

```
input -> output
1     -> false
2     -> false
3     -> false
4     -> true
6     -> true
8     -> false
30    -> false   (5 * 3 * 2), note it must be EXACTLY 2 (non-distinct) primes
49    -> true    (7 * 7)      still technically 2 primes
95    -> true
25195908475657893494027183240048398571429282126204032027777137836043662020707595556264018525880784406918290641249515082189298559149176184502808489120072844992687392807287776735971418347270261896375014971824691165077613379859095700097330459748808428401797429100642458691817195118746121515172654632282216869987549182422433637259085141865462043576798423387184774447920739934236584823824281198163815010674810451660377306056201619676256133844143603833904414952634432190114657544454178424020924616515723350778707749817125772467962926386356373289912154831438167899885040445364023527381951378636564391212010397122822120720357
      -> true, and go call someone, you just cracked RSA-2048
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so standard rules apply!

Comment: @WheatWizard There's a slightly difference in that that one asks for 3 primes (not a big difference for almost all languages) and it's for distinct primes only (fairly different for some languages). I can discuss it with you in chat if you'd like to continue a more detailed discussion.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I think the difference is negligible. How many product of **n** primes questions are we going to allow?  In my opinion we already have enough and this new one adds nothing interesting to the mix.

Comment: @WheatWizard You raise a good point, but similarly, we already have a bunch of many types of questions, and although, in contrast to what you express, most of them do add significant contribution to their area, this question has enough of a difference that I would believe that it warrants a separate question/post.

Comment: @hyperneutrino looking at the answers on both challenges, it looks like the difference is a single number in the source code, 2 vs 3. I would hardly call that a big difference.

Comment: @WheatWizard There is also "distinct" vs "not distinct"...

Comment: @WheatWizard For example, if you compare the Jelly answer on that one: `ÆEḟ0⁼7B¤` to the Jelly answer on this one: `ÆfL=2`, you'll notice that there is a significant difference; namely, that one has to check for distinctness.

Comment: You're my hero, @HyperNeutrino. In the future I'll look for further distinct questions.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino We disagree, I don't think this is worth arguing any further.

Comment: @LordFarquaad Just because its a duplicate doesn't mean it is bad.  In my mind being a duplicate is a good thing, it means that you are asking a thing that the community finds interesting enough to have already asked about.

Comment: @WheatWizard Agreed. (well, disagreed). I'd rather not argue further. It's borderline dupe but it's been antihammered so I won't bother arguing for either side for this question's sake :P

Comment: [OEIS A001358](https://oeis.org/A001358)

Comment: Subset of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131719/is-it-a-chen-prime) and (partially) [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/square-free-semiprime-counting)

Comment: If you can work out that some very large number is a semiprime that doesn't mean you've cracked RSA-2048, does it? Don't you need to know the two prime factors as well as that it's semiprime to crack it?

Comment: @CJDennis You're right, but is there a test for semi-primeness beyond calculating the factors and counting them? From what I've seen (which admittedly is not a lot), finding the factors is necessary to test semi-primeness, you just don't hold onto them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page)

Basically a port from [Fatalize's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135298/53748) to the Sphenic number challenge.

```
ḋĊ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7iNd//@bWP4HAA)**

#### How?

```
ḋĊ - implicitly takes input
ḋ  - prime factorisation (with duplicates included)
 Ċ - is a couple
```

Comment: Right language for the job indeed :P

Comment: @Uriel `Ċ` is actually a built-in list of two variables; being a declarative language the output is, by default, a test for satisfaction (e.g. `ḋ` on its own would output `true.` for non-negative integers).

Comment: How is this 2 bytes?

Comment: @harold I just updated to make "bytes" in the header link to Brachylog's code-page. A hex dump would be `c6 eb`.

Answer (score 16):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

<sub>Look ma no Unicode!</sub>

```
=2Lp
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39bIp@D///8mlgA)**

#### How?

```
=2Lp - a one input function
   p - prime factorisation (with duplicates included)
  L  - length
=2   - equals 2?
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 4 bytes

```
q2lP
```

**[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q2lP&input=36&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A6%0A30%0A49%0A95&debug=0).**

---

## How?

```
q2lPQ     - Q is implicit input.

q2        - Is equal to 2?
    lPQ   - The length of the prime factors of the input.
```

Comment: Darn it, shorter builtins! :(

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda n:0<sum((n%x<1)+(x**3==n)for x in range(2,n))<3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsIwEAXQq8xGmNS/aJJWbElOoi4iGi3YaYkV4ulj3D5463d7LmJL9OfyCvP1FkjG1r0/M7PsstNqz7lprPei4pIo0ySUgjzubCBKuVory59PGgYWHQ44wrboBgw9tOkv45om2YgFkWsqPw)

<sup>The [previous verson](https://tio.run/##FcvRCoIwFAbgV9mNcCY/5Nm0UmYvUl0saiXkUZaBPv1atx9887a8JrEp9Jf09uPt7pV0UpbEO6sLPlXu8x1JitVxmKJa1SAqenk@yEC0dnlmlj@fGQYWNfY4wlaoW7QN2DTXbo6DLIoEgXJKhx8) had some rounding issues on large cube numbers (`125`,`343`,etc)</sup>
This calculates the amount of divisors (not only primes), if it has `1` or `2` it returns `True`.
The only exception is when a number has more than two prime factors but only two divisors. In this case it is a perfect cube of a prime (its divisors are its cube root and its cube root squared). `x**3==n` will cover this case, adding one to the cube root entry pushes the sum up to a count of 3 and stops the false-positive.
<sup>thanks Jonathan Allan for writing with this beautiful explanation</sup>

Comment: This claims 8 is semiprime

Comment: `n**(1/3)%1>0<sum...` should work.

Comment: @xnor fixed it.

Comment: Made a tiny edit (e.g. 6 cubed has many more divisors)

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 16 bytes

```
PrimeOmega@#==2&
```

`PrimeOmega` counts the number of prime factors, counting multiplicity.

Comment: Dang, there's a builtin?

Comment: @JungHwanMin If only there was `SemiprimeQ`

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `PrimeOmega`

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```ruby
->x{r=c=2;0while x%r<1?(x/=r;c-=1):x>=r+=1;c==0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCkAwFAbgV9mNIoyp3Zh/HkQuWBZF6ZQcsWef76NrfqJHLC2/BIfG1Pe67YvghDrVp1yBjCuhspYtKIcyDqhDTJWUWmfymM734@8UAxfCDzyOIf4)

#### How it works:

```ruby
->x{                    # Lambda function
    r=c=2;              # Starting from r=2, c=2
    0 while             # Repeat (0 counts as a nop)
        x%r<1? (        # If x mod r == 0
            x/=r:       # Divide x by r
            c-=1        # decrease c
        ):              # else
            x>=r+=1     # increase r, terminate if r>x 
    );
    c==0                # True if we found 2 factors
}
```

Thanks Value Ink for the idea that saved 8 bytes.

Comment: Why not just have `c` start at 0 and count up, instead of making it an array that you add all the factors to? That way you take out the need to use `size` at the end

Comment: You are right, it's because I wrote the factorization function for another challenge and I reused it here.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
Tr[Last/@FactorInteger@#]==2&
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda k:f(k)==2
f=lambda n,k=2:n/k and(f(n,k+1),1+f(n/k,k))[n%k<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjLDoIwEEbhvU8xG5M2/Am24IXGeRJkUUOKZHQghAU@fWXh7nxn/q6vSX0e@JHf8fPsI0lIRiyzPyT@L4WwD1oKRe1NMrsLZ@GKPUuBWNvqUe6uy2laaKNRqXXwqFDjghuqE@oGzbkL8zLqSoPZbL7@AA)

***-10 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan!***

Credit for the Prime factorization algorithm goes to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104591) (in the initial version)

Comment: Did you use the code from [Dennis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104591)? If so, you should give credit.

Comment: @totallyhuman Oh yeah, sorry. I used it in [2 different answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138009/59487) today and I gave him credit in one of them, but I have forgotten to do that here once more. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##LchBDoIwEEbhvaeYjUkb/gRbUEPjnARZ1JAiGRwIYYGnryzcve8t3@09q88DP/MUP68@koRkxDL7U@L/Ugj7oKVQ1N4kc7hwFq44shSIta2e5eG6nOaVdhqVWgePCjVuqC6oGzTXLizrqBsNZrf5/gM)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcnRDoIgFAbgVzk3bbD@LUEzdfEk1QWtRIYcHdpmT0@z7/abv@swsc7O3PNo4/NlibvlE4XgUziEq5JH1U@JAnmmZNm9hQZL3xP/1xid99/2vylolKhQo0FZoGrRnh/dnDyv5MQm8@UH)

Comment: @HalvardHummel It is too similar to other answers. I will not update

Comment: Didn't realise there where other Python answers. My bad

Answer (score 4):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 4 bytes

```
δ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCf1AvPTclg9zp@z5/9/SFAA)

Comment: Can you explain how this is 4 bytes?... I am totally confused.

Comment: Lol I just had [this](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCf1AvNTow9wpe/7/NwMA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Neim has a [custom code-page](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Using the Neim codepage, this is ``, ``, `δ`, and `` as single-bytes.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I just obfuscated the 2 a little bit, and now this is the only answer without 2 :)

Comment: [heh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138022/68942)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino ono whatever should i do *adds builtin for checking for semiprimaity*

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 32 bytes

Thanks to ngenesis for 1 byte saved

```
Tr@FactorInteger[#][[;;,2]]==2&
```

Comment: Save one byte by using `;;` instead of `All`.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```js
n=>(k=1)==(d=n=>++k<n?n%k?d(n):d(n/k--)+1:0)(n)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>(k=1)==(d=n=>++k<n?n%k?d(n):d(n/k--)+1:0)(n)

console.log(
  [...Array(200).keys()].filter(f).join`, `
)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
(?=((x(x*))\2+)\1+$)\3^
```

*-1 byte [thanks to Grimmy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50001768#50001768)*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89b8IwFIXhv0KjCu4lTUgo6oBrmDqwMLRjaSUrXJzbGseyDaR8/PYUhkqdnyMdvV9qr0Ll2cUsOF6T3zb2m346Ly0deq@kX1oHcJSz0bCDuQRooR0irsYprsr0HlePn91wdMQ8Nm/Rs9WAeTBcETw9ZBNEEWQhDjUbAjDSk1obtgSId9LujMGTliYPznCEQTZAwRsAK3VuyOpY42x8PnNYqiWwdMoHWtgI@r34QPwD@g92Vs7L6Y0x1r45JAu7V4bXPa@spmkvSY3YNB4EP0sSnKZ4PUzaJPfkSEVgzLcqVjV4xFPo9901KcKtohRuF0P014m4XLoimxTFLw) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEAbvfopF5LAb/yAlOdkRfRDbhdAqjYq6MiuVOk/vRim9Ld8wwy73fIt83PzXEiVDuqdGXPOZIg8gVpRSG75YxBXXPdF0qGky9Y6m4@v2YKPpWzMP4K2urlEggOfS6FJ@99xXEGzo0hJ8RtUqqsBfITjGQOdDD2E0sw2jnisoMhdZLvzh0HPGAqj5u8xMtaFHrwTEdcld5O2G0oBa1Z6fpCDfwyJFoedgzfD/TfzO3Y/47DBlQSbadHvS@hc) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bb8IwDIXv@xVeNYkEVivtdiJEqIIK7cIktlvLok2EEikKVRpEd9lf7xLYONiSn9/3bHf6@h4cCNioRvUtWnWGZfFeoFOfu8erOJ2@rNavm3JRvJUctGAczgdtFBjRKN/dAeg9mCrNtkIktU14WJiKIab5loOyu@AICnat0Z6M0hH9Q9Ao2/gDobM8MFXgA3ZD9kcHFrSFKKI/Sk0yRhGj8TYG3yWLJH0ythTEDzgeBX0f/2xPvrvkxb@zMDttPdj/E7HHkrJcL6UcyFwQ0pN@TGmdT2idTR5o/fQxDCx9ZuwX) - Ruby

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

This regex is based on the 18 byte "Is it prime?" regex `(?=(x(x*))\1+$)\2^`, which unlike its semiprime version above, is longer than the shortest known, the 16 byte `^(?!(xx+)\1+$)xx`. But like `^(?=(xx+?)\1*$)\1$` (also 18 bytes), it has the interesting attribute of implicitly rejecting 0 and 1 as prime numbers, whereas the 16 byte regex must explicitly reject them (the `xx` at the end).

```
                  # tail = N = input number; there's no need to anchor here,
                  # because a start anchor is used at the end of this regex
(?=
    (             # \1 = largest proper divisor of N that is >=2
        (x(x*))   # \2 = largest proper divisor of \1; \3 = \2 - 1
        \2+       # Assert that \2 is a proper divisor of \1
    )
    \1+$          # Assert that \1 is a proper divisor of N
)
\3^               # Assert that \3==0, and thus \2==1, meaning the largest proper
                  # divisor of the largest proper divisor of N is 1, meaning N is
                  # semiprime
```

## Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / .NET), 23 bytes

```
^(?>((x(x*))\2+)\1+$)\3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzV1bmjh8MU2t4F592tvqghMLgUy7pEIlZF@9xk7Yy@Wec/@cX3eyZjl@34BYAd5cjgcDpBBRynK7ed9UAdqLpcRJJspKoAfdRoW@s/rcw6w5z0SA2kjXGd3TJE8yd/1yfTxRWc4zjqefx9L632XRxxVRKB6/XEw82NqUC/S1@eB7GSvbi2eufkqiSzmNY5em6HULlCZDAgPEJUSQv1AQW6Anbj6f4Ca2CM7FHyvRIoSg1Ntuq9T4SdcVpQMdXhCbRYoNTwk2r@PI8iVjdw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLvb9MwEP2@v@KIQLXbzkuH@IIXJkAgITFA28e2SG7itO6cS7CdNdu0v72c0/BjUvPlcnfP7/yeb6vu1Om2uN2bqqldgC3lwtRiLOH/ShuMPVpzeq076pw07cqaHHKrvIcrZRAeYaj5oAKFu9oUUFGH3QRncA3Krf18ySFsXL3z8KnLdRNMTSdPAD4bq6HMUO/6X5aIvC60oH7C5Ye2LLXTxbVWhXaw6mHPi@zPySEtOZfDXD8NcreJ/Iz5bEUaVPHVoGacv8iwtZabknmhf7XKepacjcfjhPPH59ADA2PhKMEjMYS/DERwRgwrwt1KP8lGCxzFGOTTofb0Q4WgHYLLhj9SWzVxgOeS3FjVtdUK4SEriVFLuMkVIkk32LQBMohqhxq7ufdBV8IglzDo7GFio/w33QW6Zm8xwGCIpbsTxwGEhBgkDv35Eiy1I0r4xprAklN6BMIHwJQ6XzDQGjjRKOc1JczO0yWfAs6ONoXVuA6bi3O4hIiEtxRmS2LMN8rNl92gp89wtpTw3jl170VprGXddNSNelMAytpFbXSNDFMJeJHhjMJkQgKvVMg35FBFbE5Uh4z1m4u04B@J/LAxYudUw4YRed3cfy@vFa41TUqnyHlUWgKraDwW5F182wc@mFyTYztngmbxUbl8yIJr4/v8azfkYShZ8sonZAmXT/E7iVu1/8ku3zHWsW7M@eJ8whezyUu@eL2PC7NPT9@k6W8) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda4MwFH3vrwghYG7VVl27UVLXl21QGHvY9la7YF2sMhtDTEEo/e3uWva0h1zu1znn5pjKDOuNqQxhlqSEzimZEWPVUVplmrxQ3JvPphspq7xxsmhPpm6UzXgGInufd15APHwlNuVRjQvaKe06LuXL9vVZSghIDEiJxGJS61p2ynFqCqtmh7z4cRaDbOpT7WhA6CJZLVb3D8lqSUFMytZyVqeRYE1aInvHPz6ftm8g4ELqkrNm1znbKI0ZhPE@TWmmKeBydz7gBNtBFIQxjHjVm6b9VpyGNMB1gfiiPWs3YtcJgnZIgDHaiwkhN2X9VzO9Tm9zzHwfUJrwm0On3BUVZzZAsdEulTvu9V7ANACQy3hiDaqo2vEuQfArsSBjTZgWV5S5/rOVgxi@@OaR8573U4As8SGLfQbZ3TBE4TKKfgE) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEAbvfopF5LAb/yAl5GLH7YPYLoRWSVTUlVmp1Hl6N3Lpbdlhhm9@pHvg4@q@5iAJ4iNWYm92qT5j4A6kF6XU@oavL4gLLnui8VDSaModjcf1yQbT1mbqwPW6uAYBD45zponpw3FbgO99E2fvEqpaUQHuCt4yejofWvCDmXo/6KmALHOW5cI3i44TZkDV32UmKg09ezmwTWyivcj7HaUCtag9bzBT18Is2aLt0Zvuf1D4Ts2PuGQxJkEmWnV90voX) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwFER/ReSCyaZZ4pa@bEi70Od@gVoQe7cG0huJWZSVfLvVltLHMwyHmcFPGMYenVshmCrgJ87N@Uw4sUuxvrOXZ8ZmNh84r0@C16UAXj@uxeUhf/Vfg3X4kXMNd6P01Qdsu56ByyxlYGm4Rb5Aa8DJcXA25jLX9sqgPXb@RlG6mJ32gjDQVqpJm4ABmcpSbH4SDSQd/nG5sxB82R3h@NbGrseRFXNxAOK/8Z0vU7ARZe/HmLZZpf7nTJLffjlLmAGllFYln5T6Bg) - .NET

This is a direct port of the "ECMAScript or better" regex above, using an atomic group instead of an atomic lookahead. It is much faster on most regex engines, as the `^` start-anchor test is done first instead of last.

## Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>), 23 bytes

```
^((x+)\2*(?=\2$)){2}+x$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEIRfZQlLrK1tLBtyqazEgfTaU291ItISg0BJHMkFF6G@uqu4gV6Wndmf@fqTNavp/A1oBXhz/TwawEJEKevd9m27DtBdLUMnuajXgjzoLiryvdWXARbtZSECNEa63uiBJXmSua8PN8QTleVlVtLpdl/a/Ls8@vSMisT9l4uJR9uYuiLfmPdyL2Ple/HI1Q@JupbzOHZpSl53wFgyJjBCXCIC@QMF2oI8uuVyhpvZIngp/lhRixCCUi@vO6WmA2NjSm31xDayrZDIVyEdcZp4vuL8Fw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr@CMDpGSVHUC7GWqUWzDBgxYu6F9TDNAseVErUx7kty4KfLbM8rxPgrULzTJ01F34r16VGf3xcPBVE3tAtxTLkwtxhL@r7TB2FdrTq91R52Tpl1Zk0NulfdwpQzCMww1H1Sg8FibAirqsNvgDK5BubVfLDmEjau3Hj53uW6CqenkCcAXYzWUGept/8sSkdeFFtRPuPzYlqV2urjRqtAOVj3sZZH9OTmkJedymOunQW43kZ8xn61Igyq@GdSM8zcZttZyUzIv9K9WWc@S8/F4nHD@/BJ6ZGAsvErwTAzhLwMRnBPDinAP0k@y0R2OYgxyf6ztf6gQtENw2fBHaqsmDvBckhururZaIeyykhi1hNtcIZJ0g00bIIOodqix2ycfdCUMcgmDzh4mNspf6y7QNXuLAQZDLN2dOI4gJMQgcegvlmCpHVHCN9YElpzRIxA@AKbU@YqB1sCJRjmvKWF2kS75FHD2alNYjeuwuZjDJUQkvKcwWxJjvlFusewGPX2Gs6WED86pJy9KYy3rpqNu1JsCUNYuaqNrZJhKwIsMZxQmExJ4pUK@IYcqYnOiOmas31ykBf9E5MeNEVunGjaMyOvm6Xt5o3CtaVI6Rc6j0hJYReOxIO/i2@74YHJNjm2dCZrFR@VylwXXxvf5127Iw1Cy5K1PyBIu9/E7iVt1@MlYN@F38zG7zO7mp8Q930@600NcmEN69i5NfwM) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaK5NtRbdkFh82QbC2MO2N@tC7VJbVtOQRiiIv727lT3tIZf7dc65Obayw2ZrK0uYIymhc0pmxDp9Uk7bJi80D@az6VapKm@8KtqzrRvtMp6BzN7nXSBIgK/EpjrpccF4bXzHlXrZvT4rBYIsACmRWE5qU6tOe05t4fTsmBc/3mFQTX2uPRWELpP1cv3wmKxXFOSkbB1ndRpL1qQlsnf84/Np9wYSrqQuOWv2nXeNNphBtDikKc0MBVzuLkecYFvEIlrAiNe9bdpvzWlEBa5LxBftxfgRu0kQtEcCjPFBTgi5K5u/mplNep9jFoaA0oTfHTrnvqg4cwLFRrt07nnQB4IZACDX8cQadFG1412S4FcWkow1YUbeUOb2z1YOcvjivA8hS6Z8m2YJA7gmt7BnwxBHqzj@BQ) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEAbvfopF5LAb/2C59GJX5EEcF0KrJCrqyqwU6lD67G7k0tuywwzffE/XwE@r@5yDJIj3WIm92KX6iIEHECNKqfUVcSnp2O3xYI7djui7@ymX3fpgo@5rPQ3gTFucg4AHxznTxPTuuC/AG9/E2buEqlZUgDuDt4yeXroe/Kgn48d2KiDLnGU58cWi44QZUPV36YlKTY9eDmwTm2hP8nZFqUAtas8bzNT1MEu2aHsYPfwPCrfUfIlLFmMSZKK1rZ/b9hc) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

This is a port of the now-obsoleted 24 byte "ECMAScript or better" regex, using a possessive quantifier instead of an atomic lookahead to disable backtracking.

```
^                   # tail = input number
(
    (x+)            # \2 = largest strict divisor of tail
                    #    = tail / {smallest prime factor of tail}
    \2*(?=\2$)      # Assert that \2 is a strict divisor of tail; tail = \2
){2}+               # Execute the loop exactly 2 times, with backtracking disabled
x$                  # assert tail == 1
```

#### \$\large\textit{Expressions with interactive input}\$

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
grepl('^((.+)\\2*(?=\\2$)){2}+.$',strrep(1,scan()),,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczLCoMwEIXhfZ5D8EwNYtILdSF9ERFEQhEkDTNSCuKzR9ed1YGPw89ZuvBLHETmT8SW3xzSgnIA6or63l/w6s4piDa/V3VRWln5/MBZmcYIImsd5Z1M4jmuCN9xgRAZZ/7FK7kquSl5KHnqTqNDraL2ng8) - test cases only

#### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> <s>62</s> <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```
\(n)grepl('^((.+)\\2*(?=\\2$)){2}+.$',strrep(1,n),,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BasMwEEX3PcVgAp5p5GAZAqVC9ALdd2G7YBrJFQjVaJRNgk_STVrIEXqY3qYS6Wrm8ef_P59f8fJt9fWYbPPwux8w0BzN4rF-RdxtaRi6e3zSeWyIzt263W1qwSnmG5QikBCS_s0_rFsFJ22dN1hxOrhQkQL7EdGDC8DHZYmG-WWKwYWZMZrp8OyCYTxRDr8D8KAhh_PiXUIvoGoq6ns5jgqcBfQmzOkdPWktCXzfjdpnNRtLiSslhR-LQtmBFh0RnPPG9DYlrIdQk2ItFRR0tK635y_Xttm37Q3-AA)

*-1 byte [thanks to Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248690/is-it-a-valid-list/248747#comment555846_248747)*
*-4 bytes by using `grepl()` instead of `sum(grep())` or `any(grep())`*
*-5 bytes by using a new anonymous function syntax introduced in R v4.1.0*

The old **58 byte** R v3.5.2 function: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU3LasMwELz3KxYT8G4jB8vQixXRH@i9B9sF00iuQKhCqxya4G93pdPMMK902Gt3xPSXxtHilkz02H4hXs40z8MrvusCJ6LnsJ8vp1ZwTiWDUgQSQhIdrHsFD22dN9hwvrnQkAL7m9CDC8D3GJNh/lxTcGFjTGa9fbhgGB9UZl8APGgosxy9y@gFNF1D0ySXRYGzgN6ELf@gJ60lgZ@GRfvilmI9cfWk6rE6VBpo0RHBszCm7zVjO4eWFGupoEpH@3703Vvf/wM)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
->n{?x*n=~/(?=((x(x*))\2+)\1+$)\3^/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RDoIwDEXf/YpKTNgkGwN9w8mHAJoYAZcshcCIGKO/joWoD23a23tu2g2Xx1TpSRzxmY5b1O@QpZqxkY1bzvM44HkUbHi@O4WvyWiVwP1mbAlW16XrVwCmApuJqNDay9FL6GAzJaWIiwRKvJKDFNm31jjmC59/EWlLrN2N8UNMTEY8YX@kajpAMAizKF1zNixSXMrZ@F/Jt2RVGRJIg1nP/7WD65cc0nREe2fQAf6i5041KbFX6gM)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLDoIwFADA/TtFARctRJCPRjSVg4gSP0VJyNPYEitNvXrF1cxrOH9cy918h6bSIfJvQitOqaY6ZKzOIlan0YzV@TGx7n3vekGQ34SSMImxejTdloy83eMByHNQkviBQbshgfG80RI@ZYwv/UlK@6/1QeDVpZBBDgWsYA35AooSyuUP) - test cases only

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 62 bytes

```
fn($n)=>preg_match('/^((.+)\2*(?=\2$)){2}+.$/',str_pad('',$n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY89b4MwEIb3/AoLWeKumMQgdTJOlixdurRbSKOU2AHJNRYQqRLit9Nz1OV0X8@974U2rNUhtIFxq1frgXvU@zCY@@XnOjUtpLsvgG2GdfkCB12XHHEul2zLd6kYp@ESrjdIU0EYrmpj@wF4p6XiTtu7mUb4@Dy@vaPCmXUWuDsR4wzJOMyLs9ZJ7ROk5fHxTRNqCynyAiNvfoPrbwaSPBG0rohv@oefIluVBJ3oAEV5VhvGnsr@v@a@0s85ZVmGJM2A2/gbsjn66NA0bR/FFSO/hWKxZtyrZVll/irlHw)

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
n=>/(?=((.(.*))\2+)\1+$)\3^/.test(Array(n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BTsJAEIDhV0FiYMZNS4ueWKfEIxdewGqysdt2dJ1udhcIAZ691oOJ5y/5/09zNPEjsE9Z9NzY8D3Ilz2PLY1C1Qq2BJBD/oBYrxXWpbrH@vF9lScbE7yEYM4gqkQcIxX61LOzAI6CNY1jsYB4R3JwDi8duTx6xwmW2RI1twBCXe6sdKnHan29ctybPTB5E6LdSYLutXhD/AP7H6Qqt@XmlzH1YTjNd3I0jptZMNLZzWyunG6HAJqfyWpWCqdhC4x4iYuFDzxVUEcqtT@kmMIk@nYbi@ypKH4A)

## Java 8, 61 bytes

```
n->new String(new char[n]).matches("((.+)\\2*(?=\\2$)){2}+.")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLbtswELznKxZCCi/9IGQDuYRWguRQoEDbi4@2DoxCWXTplUBS8SPIt7sryW0OLS/L5cwOd2an3/Rs9/rrYvdN7SPsuJdttE6WLRXR1iTHCv4Bx@qmcDoE@KEtwfsNQNO@OFtAiDpyeavtK@wZw1X0lrbrHLTfBtFTAb5etZffKJqt8dPnunZG0wOUkF1o9kDmAMMkdtei0n5NuZB7HYvKBEwQ5URsNosxPmZcboV4X3xMZCIuin94GeTgnJXaBaNgVWgi48FS00bIoNcf3nB1CtHspSWh4FBZZwB7mqx0@GmOEcWftYeNwFkyrDGQiBnf@QF5@q9Xx3DHkqFxNmIySxi1FIFSRq6mZaN9MNygW6e5mALN/wtKZ2gbq@UCHqFjwj2Xec6KfSz58epnCGmeK3jyXp@CLK1zeJyOjiOh@v3L2nfeeI2MUgW0zGjOZTJhg7YELKVuGndC4jRtiWdxjaZmnwdvo8HRhljsnEXfdql@wg07jyUmX0LCRoT66M4lnd2l6W8)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHPagIxEMbvfYpBPMxUDHarUhHbJ9CLR/Uwxliju5NlEy0i@@xr7HqVQIb58xu@@SBHvnDflUaOu1Ojc/Ye5mzl9gZgJZhqz9rA4tECbJ3LDQtojAiEpnFax4jPBw5WwwIEZtBI/1vMHyxDZeUXH6U@cLWSDamCgz4Yjx1E1aP1OnvHn1lMXaJbVvdUh5ppK1met3mUfCpfnN1BEZ1hq7raAFNra3n1wRTKnYMqIwq5oCiNH/Rv8CXPEvwzwYcJPk7wr9T9QcrAJLEwGdHzj@rmDg) - test cases only

## Java 11, 51 bytes

```
n->"x".repeat(n).matches("((x+)\\2*(?=\\2$)){2}+x")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPb9swDMXv/RSEsSFS/ghOgF2muMV2GDBg2yXHxAfVlWNlCi1IdOOk6GfP6CTtDpsuBPmeHvjjzjyb2e7p99ntQxsJdtyrjpxXdYcVuRbVWMM/4ljfVd6kBD@NQ3i5Awjdo3cVJDLE5bl1T7BnTawoOtyuSzBxm@TFCvDtlr38jmS3Nk6/tq23Bu@hhuKMs/usz1S0wRoSKNXeUNXYJDIh@oncbBZj8VBw@SDly@J10mfyrDn38RoCp6I2PlkNq8og2ggOQ0dQANrD20ysjonsXjmUGg6N8xbExaYak37ZnoR8W/ZKAN6h5YyrCdnxgweCf78TepYHl0rBOxLZLGPVIQHmrNxQVTAxWW6EX@elnALO/ysqb3FLzXIBDzA44TOXecmJVWPiuuxvPJcO56WGLzGaY1K1817001E/kvqyf93GgY3XKDDXgMsC51wmEwZ0NYhamRD8kQ8tuRcneTtNy5yH6MiK0QY57FRQ7Iar/pUDk1Mtso8pYxCpX4d3zmef8vwP)

#### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
.+
$*
^(?>((1(1*))\2+)\1+$)\3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLK07D3k5Dw1DDUEtTM8ZIWzPGUFtFM8b4/39DLiMuYy4TLjMuCy5jAy4TSy5LUwA) - test cases only

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

```
<?=preg_match('/^((.+)\2*(?=\2$)){2}+.$/',str_pad('',$argv[1]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1PT43sSQ5Q0NdP05DQ09bM8ZIS8PeNsZIRVOz2qhWW09FX12nuKQoviAxRUNdXUclsSi9LNowVlPT@v///yaWAA) - tests one number at a time

## [PHP](https://php.net/) `-F`, 61 bytes

```
<?=preg_match('/^((.+)\2*(?=\2$)){2}+.$/',str_pad('',$argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY89b8IwFEXn8ituXRcnBEMK6uQENqRODB2hRW7skKjBiUykVhB@e@rwIVQPlt590n3nfMl91lotFbhVYAw2itjm@lgbzePK6u1mJ@sk89j40/NGgb@eDLx5vJ5Q3z9OTsGIjtlwX9tNJZXH2JBKuzW@L9pbT08nWQluQKglrBvI2hDBMENSKi2gf3WC6az/IrD7TvO0xFLgJ8sLjbfFe4wrIIqmWV16CoIPoUqkpYXnwcSEHotnwsngRARMdJ6fBi44EbggCOCIVNl7OLNQI/43S0RYomkcSl4L5ClWoNLd0gjdpTrT5hI@gh9AD7esa5v1pyLNBQ6x47@rGtItkOY9VRon2f1oUGUV@OIs7vyXd3nehvw1DP8A) - tests ranges of numbers
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62oCg1PT43sSQ5Q0NdP05DQ09bM8ZIS8PeNsZIRVOz2qhWW09FX12nuKQoviAxRUNdXUclsSg9T1PT@v9/E8t/@QUlmfl5xf913QA) - tests one number at a time

Comment: I'll forgive you for missing [this conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50001768#50001768). 23 bytes

Comment: @H.PWiz Oh! Thanks. I came up with `(?=(x(x*))\1+$)\2^` independently on 2021-03-06 (basing it on my earlier finding of `^(?>(x(x*))\1+$)\2` on 2018-12-07), and didn't realize Grimmy had already come up with it on 2019-04-21. Cool that a method that's longer for primes can be shorter for semiprimes.

Answer (score 4):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby) + `prime`, 34 bytes

```
:prime_division|:*&:pop|:sum|:==&2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbRCoMgFADQ9/sVUlAw7qLSIoW@JCK2ZcxB6jIHI/t2BztP53X192/c5NurTZLcbmqVOcDSR/H/NKuPcsroIC6ZsMYG4fwaRN9ndRwqrJEiwxY7pCUyjrwZC3l7PMlsSNABCLF@dyRJD30Kkh7LoIvdTGo8E5B6jhXUQIFBCx3QEhgH3vwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ÆfL=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5qPrdH/w@2Pmtb8/x9tqKNgpKNgrKNgoqNgqqNgBmQbxAIA)

## Explanation

```
ÆfL=2  Main link
Æf     Prime factors
  L    Length
   =   Equals
    2  2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

```
ol2=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z8/x8j2/38TSwA)

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, 4 bytes

```
Òg2Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8KR0o8D//00sAQ)

**How?**

```
Ò       prime factors list (with duplicates)
 g      length
   Q    equal to
  2     2
```

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 18 bytes

```
⎕CY'dfns'
2=≢3pco⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdOSM1Ofv/o76pzpHqKWl5xepcRraPOhcZFyTnAwVBKv6DlXAZcnFBGEYwhjGMYQJjmMGlDOByljCWpSkA)

**How?**

`⎕CY'dfns'` - import `pco`

`3pco⎕` - run `pco` on input with left argument 3 (prime factors)

`2=≢` - length = 2?

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
Yfn2=
```

**[Try it online!](https://matl.suever.net/?code=Yfn2%3D&inputs=49&version=20.2.2)**

## Explanation

- `Yf` - Prime factors.
- `n` - Length.
- `2=` - Is equal to 2?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/) with [SymPy 1.1.1](http://www.sympy.org),  <s>57</s>  44 bytes

-13 bytes thanks to alephalpha (use 1.1.1's `primeomega`)

```python
from sympy import*
lambda n:primeomega(n)==2
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDsIgFAXX9hRvVzBfo60a2wRP4gYjaBM/EMqGND07oqt5s3gTcnp71xer7uWj@fHUcGOIExvP5qWFk0p1jY2eMWcOGRMHH9O2WB@RzJwwOYgjoSP0hBPhQrjWfagyEIazHJtNDbok2mXF7oZlbff1zTqJX4Bg/5RSli8)**

Comment: `lambda n:primeomega(n)==2`

Comment: Ah that reminds me to upgrade from 1.0, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
ḍl2=
```

4 bytes seems to be a common length, I wonder why... :P

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3hwj2///LU0B)

#### Explanation

```
ḍ     Prime factors
 l    Length
  2=  Equals 2?
```

Comment: *4 bytes seems to be a common length, I wonder why...* - Probably because all answers are prime factors, length, is equal to 2?

Comment: @MrXcoder Yep, exactly

Comment: 4 of which are mine BTW >_>

Comment: 4 is also the first semiprime. Spooky!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 67 bytes

```r
c=0;n=scan();for(p in(1:n)[-1:-2]-1)while(n%%p<1){c=c+1;n=n/p};c==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNCsIwEEDhfU7hpjCDFDvxB9s4JxEXJUQMlGlIRIXSs0fXzvaD93ItHD4ph1LiLLBUz50TLn4UQHefM6RNFKBB8NrS0NpbS/h@xCmANE26EC6e/ZZ@jezS6jyzrSualKM8IbzGCQqiIfMvVsleyUHJSclZfzo96hX1x/oF)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>69</s> 61 bytes

```
n->{int r=1,c=2;for(;r++<n;)for(;n%r<1;n/=r)c--;return c==0;}
```

-8 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZFNC8IwDIbv/opchBbddH7hqPUf6MWjeKi1SnVLR9YJIvvts35cpZBAkie8eSFXdVeJqwxeT7dOF6quYaMsPnsAFr2hs9IGtu8W4OhcYRSCZgEBchGmbcgQtVfeatgCgoQOk/XzvUIyG2o5EWdHTNBgsELBPzX2aZUJHEniOkkEGd9Q0JVyLNpOfCWr5lgEyZ/y3dkTlMEZ23myeNkfQPGvrd2j9qZMXePTKiBfIMNUs4x/DP7lkwifRvgswhcRvozdH8cM5JGFfM5/P2q7Fw)

Comment: You can remove the else statement (which could be `else++r;`) to save 8 bytes `n->{int r=1,c=2;for(;r++<n;)for(;n%r<1;n/=r)c--;return c==0;}`.

Comment: This ties with [my regex solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243144/17216) at 61 bytes.

Comment: @Deadcode Actually, yours can be 10 bytes shorter by changing `new String(new char[n])` to `"x".repeat(n)` (Java 11+). :)

Comment: Ah, nice! It even works in TIO. Hmm... I know I saw this method [before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220997/17216), as I had already upvoted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string#comment99922617_49065337). Can't think of any reason I wouldn't have just included both, unless it didn't work on TIO back then... but TIO already stopped being updated by then, so I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35+8 = 43 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag to unlock the `prime_division` function.

```ruby
->n{n.prime_division.sum(&:pop)==2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1NCsIwEEDh/ZxiaEV00aBtFVuIF1EJSFM7YJOQH0VCrm6Urh98z4b7J4/8mquziooZS7MUA73IkVbMhXmz7o02W87rlN8TPSUq5PiQ3jGvBQGgCd5hUUaVeizjeFmJpdxSAVINeQ81NNDCEU7Q7KDtoDt8tfF/3@XKLscf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ǐḢ₃
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLGmyIsIseQ4bii4oKDIiwiO1rGm2AgPT4gYGo74oGLIiwiWzEsMiwzLDQsNiw4LDMwLDQ5LDk1XSJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 22 bytes

```factor
[ factors length 2 = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcyxCsIwFEDRPV9xvyCorWIVZ3FxESdxCOXVik2MyXMQ8dtjEZzv4Xau1Xsqx8Nuv13hnfY2pquXbLtfyWR5PCW0krlJCjIQk6i@RhWUtTFvpsyoqFmwpJpQNzRzPqac@D8GCRftR7bhXLyL2PIF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>75</s> 65 bytes

```python
lambda n:g(n)==2
g=lambda n,i=2:n/i and[g(n,i+1),1+g(n/i)][n%i<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvLCsIwEIXhfZ/ibISGDtTEC7Q4TxKziNTWATsGm41PH4Pg7uM/nPTJj5e6MvO1PON6myJ0XFo1zK5Z@J9I2I3aC6JOvs4knTVku8peTPC6k4sNJd@3vIHhLcERDoQj4VyxrxoIwyk0TXqLZqwxtTPh9zDlCw)

All credit to [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104632) for the original prime factorization code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
k Ê¥2
```

[Test it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ayDKpTI=&input=OA==)

---

### Explanation

Does pretty much the same as most of the other answers: `k` gets the array of prime factors, `Ê` gets its length and `¥` checks for equality with `2`.

Comment: [`÷k o)j`](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=92sgbylq&input=Ng==) also works, unfortunately it's the same length :-(

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 112 Bytes

```cs
n=>{var r=Enumerable.Range(2,n);var l=r.Where(i=>r.All(x=>r.All(y=>y*x!=i)));return l.Any(x=>l.Any(y=>y*x==n));}
```

With formatting applied:

```cs
n =>
{
    var r = Enumerable.Range (2, n);
    var l = r.Where (i => r.All (x => r.All (y => y * x != i)));
    return l.Any (x => l.Any (y => y * x == n));
}
```

And as test program:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace S
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            var f = new Func<int, bool> (
                n =>
                {
                    var r = Enumerable.Range (2, n);
                    var l = r.Where (i => r.All (x => r.All (y => y * x != i)));
                    return l.Any (x => l.Any (y => y * x == n));
                }
            );

            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                Console.WriteLine ($"{i} -> {f (i)}");
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    }
}
```

Which has the output:

```
0 -> False
1 -> False
2 -> False
3 -> False
4 -> True
5 -> False
6 -> True
7 -> False
8 -> False
9 -> True
10 -> True
11 -> False
12 -> False
13 -> False
14 -> True
15 -> True
16 -> False
17 -> False
18 -> False
19 -> False
20 -> False
21 -> True
22 -> True
23 -> False
24 -> False
25 -> True
26 -> True
27 -> False
28 -> False
29 -> False
30 -> False
31 -> False
32 -> False
33 -> True
34 -> True
35 -> True
36 -> False
37 -> False
38 -> True
39 -> True
40 -> False
41 -> False
42 -> False
43 -> False
44 -> False
45 -> False
46 -> True
47 -> False
48 -> False
49 -> True
50 -> False
51 -> True
52 -> False
53 -> False
54 -> False
55 -> True
56 -> False
57 -> True
58 -> True
59 -> False
60 -> False
61 -> False
62 -> True
63 -> False
64 -> False
65 -> True
66 -> False
67 -> False
68 -> False
69 -> True
70 -> False
71 -> False
72 -> False
73 -> False
74 -> True
75 -> False
76 -> False
77 -> True
78 -> False
79 -> False
80 -> False
81 -> False
82 -> True
83 -> False
84 -> False
85 -> True
86 -> True
87 -> True
88 -> False
89 -> False
90 -> False
91 -> True
92 -> False
93 -> True
94 -> True
95 -> True
96 -> False
97 -> False
98 -> False
99 -> False
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 17 bytes

```
n->bigomega(n)==2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLikzPT83NT1RI0/T1tbof1p@kUaegq2CoY6CoYGBjkJBUWZeCVBESUHXDkikAZVpav4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 90 bytes

```python
def g(x,i=2):
 while x%i:i+=1
 return i
def f(n,l=0):
 while 1%n:l+=1;n/=g(n)
 return l==2
```

`f` takes an integer `n` greater than or equal to `1`, returns boolean.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc1NCsIwEAXgfU/xNgWDAzbxBxvJScSdiR0IaYkR4@njdKOzmoHvvVk@ZZqTae3uAx6bSuyMsh3eE0eP2rPlrdMdsi@vnMDd6oK46Ia/0321Udyl7pyUqJ@PzpkW5ozinwWccNUEQ9gTDoQT4Sz7IMdIGI83KZRZMqciT9aMal8)

Test cases:

```python
>>> f(1)
False
>>> f(2)
False
>>> f(3)
False
>>> f(4)
True
>>> f(6)
True
>>> f(8)
False
>>> f(30)
False
>>> f(49)
True
>>> f(95)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 45 bytes

```
.+
$*
^(11+)(\1)+$
$1;1$#2$*
A`\b(11+)\1+\b
;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLK07D0FBbUyPGUFNbhUvF0NpQRdkIKOyYEJMElokx1I5J4rL@/9@Qy4jLmMuEy4zLgsvYgMvEksvSFAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(11+)(\1)+$
$1;1$#2$*
```

Try to find two factors.

```
A`\b(11+)\1+\b
```

Ensure both factors are prime.

```
;
```

Ensure two factors were found.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com), 6 bytes

5 bytes will work as a one-off:

```
   2=#q: 8
0
   2=#q: 9
1
```

I believe I need six when I define the function:

```
   semiprime =. 2=#@q:
   (,. semiprime) 1 + i. 20
 1 0
 2 0
 3 0
 4 1
 5 0
 6 1
 7 0
 8 0
 9 1
10 1
11 0
12 0
13 0
14 1
15 1
16 0
17 0
18 0
19 0
20 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 5 bytes

```
Pl02q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Pl02q&input=95&warnings=0&hex=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 bytes

```
fl2=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UplS7IKlpSVpuhZ7Cooyc1Pj0xKTS_KLihVyUvPSSzIUjBRSC0sTc5YUJyUXQxUuWGgCYQAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
f      # prime factors
 l     # length
  2=   # equal to 2?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 43 bytes

```
{my \f=first $_%%*,2..$_;?f&&is-prime $_/f}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRCoIwGEDhVznI3EWklZoka/YiwejCHwZJsnkj4rOv3R2@s0zh26d5Qws27TneYsWHuKJcWZ7OTV0rZ16itY/VEvw85XGRIxniZ6NQDjuyS9ajQH6B542Glo6eB@2VbmC4jyb9AQ)

`f` is the smallest factor greater than 1 of the input argument `$_`, or `Nil` if `$_` is 1.  The return value of the function is true if `f` is true (ie, not `Nil`) AND the input argument divided by the factor is prime.

If `$_` itself is prime, then `f` will be equal to `$_`, and `$_ / f` is 1, which is not prime, so the formula works in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

```php
<?php for($c=$t=2;$n=&$argv[1]>1;$t++)while($n%$t<1){$c--;$n/=$t;}echo+!$c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0AhLb9IQyXZVqXE1shaJc9WTSWxKL0s2jDWztBapURbW7M8IzMnVUMlT1WlxMZQs1olWVcXqE4fqMG6NjU5I19bUSXZ@v///yaWAA)

This script is called from the command line with the number being tested as its parameter. It prints out a 1 if the number was a semi-prime, else a 0.

**Explanation**

```php
<?php
```

Work through each integer, `$t`, from 2 up, to see if it's a factor. We need to keep 
going, dividing by the factors until `$n` (an alias for 
`$argv[1]`, the first CLI parameter) reaches 1. (And as there is a 2 to hand, we take the 
chance to initialize the counter, `$c`, to 2.)

```php
for ($c = $t = 2; $n = &$argv[1] > 1; $t++)
```

When we find a factor, we keep using it for as long as we can…

```php
    while ($n % $t < 1) {
```

…each time deccrementing the factor counter…

```php
        $c--;
```

…and recalculating our number.

```php
        $n /= $t;
    }
```

When we reach the end, the counter can only be 0 if there were 2 factors. We ‘not’ 
the number, but this converts it to a boolean, so we use `+` to make it into 1 
(the number was a semi-prime) or 0 (it wasn’t).

```php
echo +!$c;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 8 bytes

```
pl2e1:0|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/@/IMco1dDKoOb///@GBgA)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 7 chars, 14 bytes

```
{2=≢π⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{2=≢π⍵}
  f¨1 2 3 4 6 8 30 49 95
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/O\cdtv
@I/ nt<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fPyY5paSMy8FTXyGvxOb/f0tTAA)

### Flattened

```
IcdttnO   Full program
I         Read the input
 c        Get the prime factors in the stack
  dtt     Depth of the stack - 2
     n    Negate, becomes 1 if there was only 2 prime factors, 0 otherwise
      O   Print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 5 bytes

```
2=Lq$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/38jWp1Dl/39LUwA)

1 for truthy, 0 for falsey.

### Explanation

```
       each term in the sequence is 
2                                   2
 =                                    == 
  L                                      length (
   q                                              prime factors (
    $                                                             current index
```