# Find the sum of the divisors of N

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, division, factoring

Write a program that displays on the screen the sum of the divisors of a number (1 ≤ N ≤ 100) entered by the user in the range of 1 to N.

This is [OEIS A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203).

---

Examples:

**Input**: 7

```
7 / 1 = 7
7 / 7 = 1

7 + 1 = 8
```

**Output:** 8

---

**Input:** 15

```
15 / 1 = 15
15 / 3 = 5
15 / 5 = 3
15 / 15 = 1

15 + 5 + 3 + 1 = 24
```

**Output:** 24

---

**Input:** 20

```
20 / 1 = 20
20 / 2 = 10
20 / 4 = 5
20 / 5 = 4
20 / 10 = 2
20 / 20 = 1

20 + 10 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 42
```

**Output:** 42

---

**Input:** 1

```
1 / 1 = 1
```

**Output:** 1

---

**Input:** 5

```
5 / 1 = 5
5 / 5 = 1

5 + 1 = 6
```

**Output:** 6

Comment: @H.PWiz I think he means "the divisors of a number N"

Comment: I think you mean sum of divisors, aka, the [sigma function](https://oeis.org/A000203)?

Comment: Sorry, i mean "The sum of the multiple of N".

Comment: @H.PWiz this is the sum of those, so I dunno

Comment: @Stephen That seems like a trivial change to me

Comment: Oh, and that question is restricted by time complexity, so maybe not.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53550/194)

Answer (score 22):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÑO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8ET///@NDAA)

#### How?

```
Ñ    Divisors
 O   Sum
```

Comment: [Polyglot with 2sable](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f//8ET///@NDAA)

Comment: `ÑO` - Rejecting the challenge and winning at the same time. That's pretty badass.

Answer (score 7):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 23 bytes

```
89 F9 89 FE EB 0D 89 F8 99 F7 F1 85 D2 99 0F 44 D1 01 D6 E2 F1 96 C3
```

The above bytes of code define a function that accepts a single integer, N, and returns the sum of its multiples as a result.

The single parameter is passed in the `EDI` register, consistent with the System V AMD64 ABI (as used on *nix-style systems). The result is returned in the `EAX` register, as with all x86 calling conventions.

The algorithm is a very straightforward one, similar to many of the other submissions in other languages. We loop N times, each time computing the modulo and adding that to our running total.

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
; unsigned SumOfMultiples(unsigned N  /* (EDI) */)
    mov     ecx, edi      ; make copy of input N, to be used as our loop counter
    mov     esi, edi      ; make copy of input N, to be used as our accumulator
    jmp     CheckEnd      ; jump directly to 'CheckEnd'
AddModulo:
    mov     eax, edi      ; make copy of input N, to be used as input to DIV instruction
    cdq                   ; short way of setting EDX to 0, based on EAX
    div     ecx           ; divide EDX:EAX by ECX, placing remainder in EDX
    test    edx, edx      ; test remainder, and set ZF if it is zero
    cdq                   ; again, set EDX to 0, without clobbering flags
    cmovz   edx, ecx      ; set EDX to ECX only if remainder was zero (EDX = ZF ? 0 : ECX)
    add     esi, edx      ; add EDX to accumulator
CheckEnd:
    loop    AddModulo     ; decrement loop counter (ECX), and keep looping if it != 0
    xchg    eax, esi      ; move result from accumulator (ESI) into EAX
    ret                   ; return, with result in EAX
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NasMwEIXX1ikGl4Jd6kZS/YvbLBrHl4i6MLLjCBK5WDIISq9eV8UKycKLYeY9vpk3POo5n2c@SKWBn5oRTJ7uhrY7fMI7@MzkBTN14fqemf0HM7hyOmem@O@ZLWK9hJmKLh6umYljq62PbVWp3aULV9h59@qXSOlGCw6TVKKXXQvBk02vjQyDqxXaL9xH5fwgJD9PbQdvSrdieDltERJSw6URMgjRN/K@RquPgQ8Z09GW6ceWSf8ZlqsBZGFYepsN5DeSJGskSRxJ4xtK8RpKsUNjepdPVvOJQ8kduZoP1/wUecgbOz2NEnCJfuZffjw3vZqjSxr/AQ)**

It sure seems like there should be a way to make this shorter, but I can't see it. Computing modulo on x86 takes quite a bit of code, since you do it using the `DIV` (or `IDIV`) instruction, and both of those use fixed input registers (`EDX` and `EAX`), the values of which get clobbered (because they receive the results, the remainder and quotient, respectively).

The only real tricks here are pretty standard golfing ones:

- I've structured the code in a somewhat unusual way so that I can use the CISC-style `LOOP` instruction, which is basically just a combination of `DEC`+`JNZ` with the `ECX` register as the implicit operand.
- I'm using `XCHG` at the end instead of `MOV` because the former has a special 1-byte encoding when `EAX` is one of the operands.
- I use `CDQ` to zero out `EDX` in preparation for the division, even though for unsigned division you would ordinarily just zero it using a `XOR`. However, `XOR` is always 2 bytes, while `CDQ` is only 1 byte. I use `CDQ` again a second time inside of the loop to zero `EDX`, before the `CMOVZ` instruction. This works because I can be guaranteed that the quotient of the division (in `EAX`) is always unsigned, so a sign-extension into `EDX` will set `EDX` equal to 0.

Answer (score 5):

## C (gcc), 45 bytes

```
i,s;f(n){for(s=i=n;--i;)s+=n%i?0:i;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/RCoIwGIbh4@0qhiFs5HITzWhpN@JJTFc/1IxtHonXbh0YiYcfPPDyaX7Xep4h8cpQy0bTO@orqKziHBTz@8rGcBVnUK4Lg7PEq2negdXPoe3IxYcW@sOjxhhsIK8bWMrwiNHbfbehESmbwOsmxG1jo4QYSkrGFEpTcvojWWyQLBaU5X@ViY3KxKLybBWU26BclFyhbZD8gkeMMFqeCoWn@QM)

Answer (score 4):

### C, C++, C#, D, Java, <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```cpp
int d(int n){int s=0,i=1;for(;i<=n;++i)s+=n%i>0?0:i;return s;}
```

This works in all theses 5 programming languages because of similarities.

#### C, C++ and D optimization : <s>62</s> 60 bytes

In C++ and D, integers convert implicitly to booleans ( Zero => false, Not Zero => true ), so you don't need to have the `!=0`

```cpp
int d(int n){int s=0,i=1;for(;i<=n;++i)s+=n%i?0:i;return s;}
```

#### D optimization : golfy template system, 55 bytes

```d
T d(T)(T n){T s,i=1;for(;i<=n;++i)s+=n%i?0:i;return s;}
```

#### C++ optimization by c and c-- : <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```cpp
int f(int n,int i=0){return++i<n?f(n,i)+i*!(n%i):n;}
```

**Code to test** :

C :

```c
printf("%d %d %d %d %d", d(7), d(15), d(20), d(1), d(5));
```

C++ :

```cpp
std::cout << d(7) << ' ' << d(15) << ' ' << d(20) << ' ' << d(1) << ' ' << d(5);
```

C# :

```cs
class FindSum
{
    int d(int n) { int s = 0, i = 1; for (; i <= n; ++i) s += n % i > 0 ? 0 : i; return s; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var f = new FindSum();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", f.d(7), f.d(15), f.d(20), f.d(1), f.d(5)));
    }
}
```

D :

```d
writeln(d(7));
writeln(d(15));
writeln(d(20));
writeln(d(1));
writeln(d(5));
```

Java :

```java
public class FindSum {
    int d(int n){int s=0,i=1;for(;i<=n;++i)s+=n%i>0?0:i;return s;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FindSum f = new FindSum();
        System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", f.d(7), f.d(15), f.d(20), f.d(1), f.d(5)));
    }
}
```

Comment: A few things: First, I don't think you need parentheses around the `n%i`/`n%i!=0` in any of the languages. Second, your first solution should be able to have `n%i>0` instead of `n%i!=0`. Third, D's solution can be `T d(T)(T n){T s,i=1;for(;i<=n;++i)s+=n%i?0:i;return s;}` by abusing the template system and default values.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY7RCoJAFESf937FjQh3s8CMCnSzH@lF1tUu6FV0rQfx2zetlzMwwwxjuu5o6pwr74kdlnIlH1bSPVJTb93YcxiS5kcpl0CFtN9I3pFKOJ39ltjUY2FRUzu43uZNBrC0ocmJ5bulQsEE4reagvi8qLYoB1ckiSHGLENWIMTfaEeHWi8nWK0aPDlIYfYnvOAN4wjPMV6/), C++

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
Tr@Divisors@#&
```

or an answer by @Loki

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
DivisorSum[#,#&]&
```

Comment: @Jennymathy Very nice, thanks! An equivalent and funny way to write it is also: DivisorSum[#, # &] &

Comment: @Jennymathy Hmm, this is even better: Total@Divisors@ is only 15 characters long! And it works: eg Total@Divisors@15 gives 24 as expected. Mathematica  FTW :)

Comment: @Loki and `Tr@Divisors@#&` even better  ;-)

Comment: @Jennymathy Wow, awesome!

Comment: @Jennymathy, actually you don't even need the #&, Tr@Divisors@ also just works, ie Tr@Divisors@15 gives 24

Comment: @Loki the program must be a function `f=` that takes an input f[x] that's why I present it in this way.Welcome to PPCG

Comment: You can use `Tr@*Divisors` to shave off a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
â)x
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4il4&input=MjA=)

Comment: Alternative: `â x`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: not really an alternative; it's doing the exact same thing - only difference is the choice of parenthesising.

Comment: Or with the flag `-x`, it could be one byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Shnap](https://github.com/ShnapLang/Shnap), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

-1 bye thanks to Mr. Xcoder (lol I was outgolfed in my own language)

```
 $n return:{s=0for d:range(n+1)if n%d<1s+=d}
```

This is a function (`$` starts a function in Shnap).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ISyz4n2b7XyVPoSi1pLQoz6q62NYgLb9IIcWqKDEvPVUjT9tQMzNNIU81xcawWNs2pfY/SDbaXMfQVMfIQMdQxzRWoaAoM68kJ08jTSOzRFPzPwA)

Explanation:

```
$ n                        //Start function with parameter n
    return: {              //Technically, we are returning a scope-block, which evaluates to the last statement run
        s = 0              //Our result
        for d : range(n+1) //For each value in the iterator range(n+1)
            if n % d < 1  // If n is divisible by d
                s += d     // Add d to the sum
                           // Since (s += d) returns (s + d), and a scope-block returns the last run statement, this will be the last statement and equal to our result
    }
```

---

## Noncompeting, 19 bytes

After many language updates, this can now be reduced to a measly 19 bytes:

```
$n=>sum(factors(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ISyz4n2b7XyXP1q64NFcjLTG5JL@oWCNPU/N/Wn6RQrS5jqGpjpGBjqGOaaxCQVFmXklOnkaaRmYJUAEA)

Comment: `==0` is `<1` ([43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K87ISyz4n2b7XyVPoSi1pLQoz6q62NYgLb9IIcWqKDEvPVUjT9tQMzNNIU81xcawWNs2pfY/SDbaXMfQVMfIQMdQxzRWoaAoM68kJ08jTSOzRFPzPwA))

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder thanks... I was outgolfed... In my own language... Which isn't even esoteric xD

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
f+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P037/38jg/9RAA)

#### Explanation

```
f       Factors
 +      Sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 3 bytes

```
+/?+??
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIrLz8rPz8iLCJbN10iLDBd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW/H////NAQ)

Built-in that does exactly as wanted.

Comment: Jelly seems so beautiful! Where can i find some stuff to study about it?

Comment: @KevinHalley You can check out the [Tutorial page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Tutorial) on Github, or you can visit the [official Jelly chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32533/jelly) once you have 20 reputation, or the [Jelly training chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining), also at 20 reputation, which you'll need to request permission to train in

Comment: I desperately want to upvote this *because* you suggested not upvoting trivial solutions.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, maybe there's no point putting that there :P

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>31</s> 26 bytes

```r
function(N)(x=1:N)%*%!N%%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0/DT1OjwtbQyk9TVUtV0U9VteJ/moahgeZ/AA)

Returns a `1x1` matrix.

Computes `!N%%x` maps elements `d` of `1:N` by: `d->(1 if d divides N, 0 otherwise)`

Then `x%*%x!N%%x` is the matrix product of `1:N` which results in the sum of `x` where `!N%%x` is `1`. Neat! Technically a port of Luis Mendo's [Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142151/67312) but I only saw that after I thought of this.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/)+ numbers, 14 bytes

```r
numbers::Sigma
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P680Nym1qNjKKjgzPTfx/38A)

Comment: For the first one you can save 2 bytes with `N=scan();`

Comment: @gstats yes, but then I should get +4 bytes per [meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13743/67312). If you have a strong opinion you can weigh in on Jarko's answer but as nobody has suggested an alternative, that stands in my mind.

Comment: Shouldn't the second be `numbers::Sigma(N)`? Like this it outputs the source code of function `Sigma`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas a function is a perfectly good submission. to test it, you obviously have to call it as I do in the first submission.

Comment: Note: that anonymous functions in the later versions of R now can now use the syntax `\(x)` instead of `function(x)`. So you can save quite a few characters there.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>54</s> 44 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(x=n)].reduce(y=>y+!(n%x)*x--,0)
```

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

#### Try it online!

```js
const f = n=>[...Array(x=n)].reduce(y=>y+!(n%x)*x--,0)

console.log(f(7))
console.log(f(15))
console.log(f(20))
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 44 bytes

```
lambda k:sum(i*(k%i<1)for i in range(1,1+k))
```

- Thanks to Stephen, save 1 byte by removing whitespace.
- Thanks to Jonathan Frech, save another 1 byte by changing if to multiply.

Comment: You could also write it as `lambda k:sum(-~i*(k%-~i<1)for i in range(k))`

Comment: [41 bytes.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVsn09bQKtMmW9swMS9FI1s108ZQUytTO00DKKNtqPm/oCgzr0QjTcPQVFPHyESTC8Y319SxQPCMDDR1TIwQfKBiM83/AA)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Maybe that is different enough to post as another answer.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 And looks like it is similar to this answer. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142108/44718 so you can go up vote that one.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 5 bytes

```
sigma
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L84Mz038X9afpFGHpBrqKNgaGCgo1BQlJlXAhRRUtC1AxJpGnmampr/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 23 bytes

```
[:+/](([:=&0]|[)#])1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WTyHaSls/VkMj2spWzSC2JlpTOVbTUDtTjys1OSNfIU3B0BTGMjKAi/3/DwA)

For J fans, there is a [clever 13 byte solution](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Divisors#Sum_of_Divisors): `>:@#.~/.~&.q:` but since it wasn't my invention I'm not posting it as my official answer.

My own solution simply filters 1..n, finding divisors, then sums them.  The crux of it is the dyadic fork

```
](([:=&0]|[)#])
```

Note that in this context `]` is 1..n, and `[` is n itself.  Hence `]|[` are the remainders when dividing each element of 1..n into n, and `=&0` tells you if they're equal to 0.

Comment: This for 13 bytes should be equivalent: ``+1#.i.*0=i.|]``

Comment: @miles, that is *really* nice.  This part is `i.|]` is a great improvement on my approach.  I don't fully understand this part though: `+1#.i.` -- could you explain it?

Comment: ``1#.`` is base 1 conversion, which is equivalent to ``+/"1``. First ``i.|]`` to get the remainders, then ``0=`` to find the ones equal to 0 (the divisors), then ``i.*`` to zero out the non-divisors in the range, then sum using ``1#.``, then add ``+`` itself since ``i.`` is an exclusive range.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 6 bytes

```
s*M{yP
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2aM%7ByP&input=20&debug=0)**

Pyth doesn't have a built-in for divisors, so I think this is reasonable.

## Explanation

```
s*M{yP    - Full program with implicit input.

     P    - The prime factors of the input.
    y     - The powerset of its prime factors.
   {      - Deduplicate.
 *M       - Map with multiplication.
s         - Sum.
          - Implicitly display the result.
```

Given `20`, for instance, this is what our program does after each instruction:

- `P`: `[2, 2, 5]`.
- `y`: `[[], [2], [2], [5], [2, 2], [2, 5], [2, 5], [2, 2, 5]]`.
- `{`: `[[], [2], [5], [2, 2], [2, 5], [2, 2, 5]]`.
- `*M`: `[1, 2, 5, 4, 10, 20]`.
- `s`: `42`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```java
n->{int s=0,i=0;for(;i++<n;)s+=n%i<1?i:0;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY5BS8NAEIXv@RVzERJil1QQwW0Ujx6sh@JJPIxpUibdzi67s4VQ8tvjVoJn847D9@Z9PZ5xZV3L/f44ufhtqIHGYAjwhsRwySAlCEq6d8RooE8NFYWM6iI3QpbVK8sHox/eXetRrIct1BOvni7EAqGubqmudGd9rqksN6yLUNZ8Q5v1Mz1W2rcSPUPQ43Qd09nv5uwyT58t7eGUjPKdeOLD5xegP4RiFrxmNwRpT8pGUS4hYjjfKnTODC8hCeYPRaH/Da/vl9B31aLfS@A/jzEbpx8)

Comment: @corsiKa Only class fields. In a local scope they're unitialized.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
t:\~fs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Qqpi6t@P9/IwMA)

-4 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo

## 10 bytes

My previous solution using a loop

```
:"G@\~@*vs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30rJ3SGmzkGrrPj/fyMDAA)

## 3 bytes

Using built-in

```
Z\s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pyqm@P9/I4P/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[i|i<-[1..n],n`mod`i<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7a4NDc6sybTRjfaUE8vL1YnLyE3PyUh08Yw9n9uYmaegq1CQWlJcEmRT56CikJxRn45kMpNLFDQiMlT0LVT0AAL5WkqaGsrKIEElEAsiKgG0HxNTU2FaHMdBUNTHQUjAyCto2Aa@x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 96 bytes

```
((({})<>){<(([()]{})){<>(({})(<()>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]({})){((<{}{}>))}}{}>{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxCoBADAS/sylsrCxCPnJYnIUgioXtkrfHPRFCyM5Otqcf97Rf/awCwDQPowMNtirpjg/DYWFq@UWj9nBEkqmR15gifw2nqF5GGVKsal5e)

### Explanation:

<sub>Now outdated by improvements.</sub>

The heart of the algorithm is this:

```
({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]({})) turns |N, M...| into |N mod M, M...|
{((<{}{}>))} if the top of stack is not zero, replace it and the second with zero
```

That is a modification on mod that will give us `M` if it is a factor of `N` and `0` otherwise. Full code is below.

```
((({})<>) place input, N on both stacks
{ Loop to find factors
 <
  (([()]{})) Decrement and Duplicate; get next factor to check
  { if not zero
   (<>({})<>) Copy N from other stack
   ({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]({})){((<{}{}>))} Code explained above
  }
  {} drop the zero
 >
 {} add the factor
}) push the sum
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @FunkyComputerMan I got one now!

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 41 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:s=s-i*([A1]mod i=0):Next:?s
```

## Excel, 41 Bytes

Worksheet formula that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the caller

Requires MS Excel Version 16.0 or later for access to `Let(...)` function

```vb
=LET(a,SEQUENCE(A1),SUM((MOD(A1,a)=0)*a))
```

Comment: `For i=1To[A1]:s=s-([A1]mod i=0)*i:Next:?s` is 41 bytes.  The minus is because VBA seems to convert True to -1.

Comment: @Axuary - thanks for having me take a look at this one again - It was fun to make the worksheet formula solution for this

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 16 bytes

```
sum(seq(Inot(fPart(Ans/I)),I,1,Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 1 byte

```
K
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiSyIsIiIsIjciXQ==)

`K∑` flagless. `K` just gets the divisors of a number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
ΣḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zihzu6/v//b2QAAA)

Comment: wow that's pretty good

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://www.raku.org/), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

thanks ovs for 2 byte improvement
also JoKing for 1 byte improvement

```raku
{sum grep $_%%*,1..$_}
```

```
declare anonymous block ($_ implicitly declared)
filter (grep) numbers from 1 to $_ inclusive using the whatever variable (*) that are divisible by $_
get the sum of that list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3NCoJAGEX331NcRMMJHRpRC8SeoqUggUMM@YejRojPPn0u2p5zOXfUU5u77otTY9bYLh1Kt4VKSr8W8jXpMfTrIDgLyWp3i9V4aDsXRK3ptZXvVXbPMYzvqEzfRKgOjI0ATobMGA3LLFDiMPIzTI0tWBsL08v/aQQeRfBmbmPj0u7RLtwVN1IZkpSSC9KEFBRlyH8)

Comment: `{grep($_%%*,1..$_).sum}` works for 23

Comment: that that is very smart

Comment: you can move `sum` to the start to save one on the brackets, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCoMwFET39ysG0aIlhkbUFsR@RZeCFAwl1BdGLUX89vS66GrgzHBm1FObu@6LU2PW2C4dSrcd8Zr0CL8OgrNQUvr17har8dB2Loha02sr36vsnmMY31GZvhGoDoyNAPaFzBgNyxyhxNHIzzA1tuDaWJhe/h8FeCTgzezGxqbdoz1yV9xIZUhSSi5IE1JQlCH/AQ "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
(load library
(d D(q((K N)(i K(a(i(mod N K)0 K)(D(s K 1)N))0
(q((N)(D N N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcohEoAgEAXQ7il@/NsgeAMaMxROgEPZGRQFC6dHDK@9V69RtN9zstSUUfRoqY2NGY4P6RGECs9E5VkzAryYhY4dHlaCiPl7/PvKbpUwGWH3@QE)

-1 byte thanks to DLosc.

And without `library` just for fun:

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>97</s> 90 bytes

```
(d D(q((N K)(i(l N K)N(D(s N K)K
(d F(q((K N)(i K(a(i(D N K)0 K)(F(s K 1)N))0
(q((N)(F N N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw9DoUwDAPgnVN4dDY6cIOKJVIWTlDEUqnv8btw@pJ2s@IvfvL/Lfk@auWGyJM0qDCzoAVj5N2TDg7mBhTmAMrkLPZybD@zS0UQExkbXvqa351YZdnThpLXK12vDPylAwsYnh1hEqkf)

-7 bytes thanks to DLosc.

Comment: @DLosc thanks! I should probably rename `D` to `M` since now it's just a `mod` function.

Comment: Huh--I didn't notice that, lol.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 31 bytes

```
f=(n,i=n)=>i&&!(n%i)*i+f(n,i-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 73 bytes

```
a=Cells(1,1)
x=1
While x<=a
If a Mod x = 0 Then b=b+x
x=x+1
Wend
MsgBox b
```

Comment: This answer is invalid as it is a collection of snippets that cannot be run as a single unit as stands. To make this valid you will need to convert this to a subroutine or an anonymous VBE immediate window function.

Comment: I am not very familiar in what you had said. Can you help me a bit more?

Comment: To make this post valid you would have to convert it into one of the following formats, 1 - Subroutine, 2 - Function, 3 - Anonymous VBE immediate window function (a single line that can be executed in the Immediate window);  For your implementation, the simplest implementation of this would be to convert to a subroutine by wrapping with `Sub Y`...`End Sub` to get the 85 Byte solution `Sub y`
`A=Cells(1,1)`
`x=1`
`While x<=A`
`If A Mod x=0 Then b=b+x`
`x=x+1`
`Wend`
`MsgBox b`
`End Sub`

Comment: That however can be optimized quite heavily down to the 72 byte solution `Sub y`
`While x<=[A1]`
`x=x+1`
`If [A1]Mod x=0Then b=b+x`
`Wend`
`Debug.?b`
`End Sub`
which assumes that it is run in a clean module (x = default int value, `0`) and outputs to the VBE immediate window (`?` autoformats to `Print ` )

Comment: Beyond this, and recognizing that your solution does not take input via the subroutine call, this can then be converted to a VBE immediate window function for 50 Bytes `While x<=[A1]:x=x+1:b=IIf([A1]Mod x,b,b+x):Wend:?b` which assumes that `x`,`b` are the default value of 0 and outputs to the VBE immediate window (from the VBE immediate window `?` is equivalent to `Debug.Print `)

Comment: Note that in the above, the `If ... Then` clause was converted to an `IIf` call - if this is not possible and the `If` statement lies in a loop, then your subroutine / function cannot be made into an anonymous VBE immediate window function, as anything that follows the `Then` regardless of next lines (`:`) shall be regarded as part of that `If` statement and thus, the compiler sees an un-terminated loop structure

Comment: That's about all of the basics - see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba) for more.

Comment: Thank You Sir @TaylorScott . I guess I really don't know a lot about the definitions in VBA. Yes I read about your post and it actually helped me a lot and understand more. Thank you again Sir.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 36

```bash
bc<<<`seq -f"n=%g;a+=n*!$1%%n;" $1`a
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PynZxsYmoTi1UEE3TSnPVjXdOlHbNk9LUcVQVTXPWklBxTAh8f///4amAA).

---

## Pure Bash, 41

```bash
for((;++i<=$1;a+=$1%i?0:i))
{
:
}
echo $a
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPDWls708ZWxdA6URtIqmbaG1hlampyVXNZcdVypSZn5CuoJP7//9/QFAA).

I first tried a fancy bash expansion answer, but it ended up being longer than the simple loop above:

```bash
echo $[$(eval echo +\\\(n={1..$1},$1%n?0:n\\\))]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=1:i<=n and(n%i<1)*i+f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n09bQKtPGNk8hMS9FI08108ZQUytTO00DKKNtqPk/JTVNwU0jT9OKi7OgKDOvBKgDKKfJxeWmYa4JJAxNQaSRAYgEM4F6AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), 9 bytes

```
D,f,@,dFs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQSfFrfi/SpqdPZf///9GBgA)

I clearly got here too late. This defines a function that gets the factors, then sums them.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
VΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/P@zc4v//jQwA)

This is pretty straight-forwad:

```
V   - Divisors.
 Σ  - Sum.
```

Comment: Damnit, you beat me too it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
ṁΠuṖp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxnMLSh/unFbw//9/IwMA)

## How?

```
ṁΠuṖp  - Full program, implicit input.

     p  - Prime factors.
    Ṗ   - Powerset.
   u    - Remove duplicates.
ṁΠ     - Get the product of each list, sum and implicitly output.
```

Thanks to Zgarb for the suggestions in chat!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
dΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P@Xc4v//jQwA)

Pretty straight-forward:

```
dΣ   - Full program.

d    - Divisors.
 Σ   - Sum.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCa1AvOb/f3MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 20 bytes

```matlab
@(n)~mod(n,t=1:n)*t'
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@zLjc/RSNPp8TW0CpPU6tE/X@ahrmmjkKahqEpmDIygPDApKnmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
param($a)1..$a|%{$j+=$_*!($a%$_)};$j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVR01BPTyWxRrVaJUvbViVeSxEopqoSr1lrrZL1//9/IwMA)

#### Explanation

```powershell
param($a)1..$a|%{$j+=$_*!($a%$_)};$j
param($a)                            # Takes input $a
         1..$a|%{               };   # For-loop from 1 up to $a
                          $a%$_      # Modulo, if this is zero we've hit a divisor
                        !(     )     # Take the Boolean-not of that. If a divisor, it's 1
                     $_*             # Multiply the current number by that Boolean
                                     # Only if it's a divisor will this be non-zero
                 $j+=                # Add it into our accumulator
                                  $j # Output our accumulator
```

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 42 bytes

```
f(x:PI):PI==(x=1=>1;reduce(+,divisors(x)))
```

results

```
(19) -> [[i,f(i)] for i in [7,15,20,42,1,5] ]
   (19)  [[7,8],[15,24],[20,42],[42,96],[1,1],[5,6]]
                                          Type: List List PositiveInteger
```

Comment: Why is not possible upvote the answer of who write it? I have the suspect here people upvote their answer logging with some other login... I say that because in some question there are more star than the people answer... (so why give one star if you not participate to competition?)

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 9 bytes

```
+/⍳×0=⍳|⊢
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28+/%u2373%D70%3D%u2373%7C%u22A2%2942&run)

### How? (input **n**)

- `⍳|⊢`, `[n mod 1, ..., n mod n]`
- `0=`, `[0 == n mod 1, ... 0 == n mod n]`
- `⍳×`, `[1*(0 == n mod 1), ..., n*(0 == n mod n)]`
- `+/`, `sum([1*(0 == n mod 1), ..., n*(0 == n mod n)])`

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 96 bytes

```
listen to N
X's0
T's0
while N-X
let X be+1
let D be N/X
turn up D
let T be+D is N/X and X

say T
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~.,{.3$\%!*+}*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Pp1rPWCVGVVFLu1ZL@/9/E0szAA)

```
~                # Parses the input to integer
 .,              # Makes an array with numbers from 0 to (N-1)
   {.3$\%!*+}    # This block goes to the top of the stack without being executed
             *   # Folds
              +  # Adds the input and the result
```

What the block does:

```
    .            # Duplicates the number of the array
     3$          # Makes a copy of N
       \%!       # Tests if the number of the array is a divisor of N
          *      # Multiplies, resulting in the divisor if it was divisible or 0 if it wasn't
           +     # Adds to the acumulator
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 18 bytes

```
00000000: 89c1 9988 0e09 0150 d40a 7502 02d4 58e2  .......P..u...X.
00000010: f2c3                                     ..
```

Listing:

```
89 C1           MOV  CX, AX                 ; input number as loop counter 
99              CWD                         ; zero DX as running sum 
            DIVLOOP:
88 0E 0109      MOV  BYTE PTR[AAM1+1], CL   ; move loop counter to divisor 
50              PUSH AX                     ; save input number 
            AAM1:
D4 0A           AAM                         ; ZF if (AL % CL == 0), AH = quotient
75 02           JNZ  END_LOOP               ; if not ZF, continue loop 
02 D4           ADD  DL, AH                 ; otherwise add to running sum 
            END_LOOP:
58              POP  AX                     ; restore input number 
E2 F2           LOOP DIVLOOP                ; loop until CL == 0 
C3              RET                         ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input `N` in `AX`, result in `DX`.

Inspired by [@CodyGray's excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142105/84624), and the comment `"It sure seems like there should be a way to make this shorter"` I just had to try!

As Cody mentioned, Using `DIV`/`IDIV` is inconvenient because it clobbers two registers including the dividend. Another is that the `ZF` flag is set when the quotient is `0`, however in this case we're only interested in when the remainder is `0`.  Enter `AAM`, a trusty and underrated byte-sized division/modulo instruction that can be golfy.  Even though it does clobber the dividend just like `DIV`, it will set `ZF` when the remainder is `0` which is what we want here.  It's downside is that the divisor is encoded in the instruction opcode, which can be modified at runtime at a cost of 4 bytes (in real mode at least).

Comment: this is for MS-DOS ? what assembler and debugger you using ? TASM ?

Comment: @NotStar I use MASM 1.1 for DOS asm and then just DOS DEBUG.EXE for the x86-16 stuff. Quick and dirty!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(i for i in range(1,n+1)if n%i<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyNTIS2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1AnT9tQMzNNIU8108ZQ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

```
{var s=0;for(i in 1..it)if(it%i==0)s+=i;s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7NCoJAFAXgfU9xEIIZInEmrUimfeueQFDhko7ijG7Et2jZ0/Ui5s8iksC7OJt7v8t5FDYj3TdRhZgaMkV1r3NcwG7a8v11SNW349YoL0yLihFIQ7guWU4pI7slpTxudopC0/VprZFHpBlvMcxmjOHs@5rhxKEUcOYoK9I208yxibECZWRMEuP9ejr8DxTBBKW/gHINSm@CvlzAwxqEmKuKBfRX4VwVxwUMfmHXfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{+/&~1!x%!1+x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFj8FuwjAMhu9+iqBtaFNV0oSEokZo5532AAhpXUmhApqOpKgIwbMvSVN6sPzZ+f07LrNbhKcPMuneJiTq7gAmu72ur49zViKEOvGjDuL9p8yro+jEVZw/Nncw61QsNzYRLihzQBPBqO8I4hIXiw0Ahr0xjc4wLtRW7tSxnGmTFwfZFfu83slZoU74r5XaVKrWmDCapASXVb2NzV7Guj3FqvS4rS6VVmft6vqzyXdyRacm/13lhaku8sVibFQD8FU3rclQCpAijAhaWXSUWiKuGfnmEuC7NV66fA4RDkB4GLOF57nlgNziPCh472dzhFzMgzFlo7PjYE0TAJoEa1t4ps4jMPNrPDprFtSJkwd10q+0OXIP/V5mg4bdjI67HQ9n2W8OR40C8ny3Vw9HcxjuJK7Z2y7GocU/V46GYw==)

- `!1+x` generate sequence from `1..x`
- `x%` divide the input by each term in this range
- `&~1!` identify values in the range that evenly divide the input
- `+/` take (and implicitly return) their sum

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors math.unicode`, 15 bytes

```
[ divisors Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeal5mcn5IK4RQUZeamFuulgZUVKxSnFpam5iWnFisUFKWWlFQCpfNKFKy5uKoVzBUMTRWMDBQMFUwVav9HK6RklmUWg/ScW6wQ@z83sUBB7z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
+Sk
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIrU2siLCI1Il0=)

```
+Sk
 S  # Sum
  k # The divisors
+   # And add the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>60</s> 56 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @Steffan*

```
N+X:-bagof(M,(between(1,N,M),N mod M<1),L),sumlist(L,X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCoMwFAXQXwlO7@FNaQpSkCLorJkFcVCqIhgTTIqbv56Wjmc47rCbXaQ/1xh12uZyHBY7UwMap3BO004KGg1DC2PfonkpRs3wH7OtPlCNlm8xl2Zwf3dlXxRUphVme5ghUHI5IQtxuWtP0JWoemZ0T6gMjzsUsv73vw)

Comment: `=:=0` can be `<1`

Comment: also you can use `bagof` instead of `findall`

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 62 bytes

```go
func p(n int)(p int){i:=1
for;i<=n;i++{if n%i<1{p+=i}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEXXzSmGgpCQKhY30jauPIBXKKUpg3YSQroKOYmbIngIj-JtTGtXb_H57z1fg5k_tu3u7dDD2CIxHK1xHnI9-vw9eb0_fy96og4sJ0DygtsVAStVMm1cjY2iGqUMqIF22JTBSoUxMtf7yVHcLNfVsjS4gMCydAWESkFZJzZwOiZKuUxZih9uLmUexLFIaRSCZZFtrnn-8wc)

-2 bytes compared to my answer to [Product of Divisors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252256/77309) via use of Go's 0-initialization for variables.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
$=>[∑factors&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?sMst0t)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 20 bytes

```
{+/t(*=(t:1+!x)!'x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW1i/R0LLVKLEy1Fas0FRUr9Cs5eJKizY0jQWS5iDCyCAWANRVClQ=)

I honestly didn't know how I manage to make a for-each that find the divisors, lol.

Explanations:

```
{+/t(*=(t:1+!x)!'x)}  Main function. x is input
    (           'x)   For x amount of times
               !      Modulo it with
       (    !x)       Range, create a list of [0..x-1]
          1+          + 1 to each number in list to turn it into [1..x]
        t:            Assign it to variable t
                      Now, we got the modulo results of each number from [1..x],
                      we now need to
      =               Group them into a dictionary
     *                And get the value of the first key
                      i.e. the occurence positions of the 0s
                      (Implicit at)
   t                  The variable t
 +/                   Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
fS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaL0oIhDCh_wSJDUwgLAA)

```python
f   # Factors
 S  # Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 1 byte

```
F
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhYL3ZYUJyUXQ3kLFhmaQlgA)

Or, `FS` flagless.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
ƒ+
```

### Explained

```
ƒ+
ƒ   # Factorize
 +  # Sum
```

Trivial, but felt it needed to be posted.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///YJO3///8bmgIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 35 + 1 (-p) = 36 bytes

```perl
$\+=($n%$_==0)&&$_ for 1..($n=$_)}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWQyVPVSXe1tZAU01NJV4hLb9IwVBPDyhqqxKvWVv9/7@Rwb/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgb/dQsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
smBa++'%'Va'a:0!a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P@/ONcpUVtbXVU9LFE90cpAMVH9/38jAwA)

## Explanation:

```
smBa++'%'Va'a:0!a' - Input to a; 20
s                    - sum up; 42
 m                   - map with; [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15]
  Ba                 - Range; [1,2..20]
    ++'%'Va'a:0!a'   - function, evaluates to 0 if param cannot divide a i.e. 20
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
[:|~b%a|\p=p+a}?p
```

### Explanation

```
[:|      FOR a = 1; a <= b (read from cmd line); a++
~b%a|    IF b modulo a has a remainder THEN - empty block - 
\p=p+a   ELSE add divisor 'a' to running total 'p'
}        END IF, NEXT
?p       PRINT p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 16 bytes

```
ri:X{)_X\%!*}%:+
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyjTKqJaMz4iRlVRq1bVSvv/fyMDAA)

#### Explanation

```
ri                 e# Read integer, n
  :X               e# Write to variable X
    {       }%     e# Map this block over the array [0 1 ... n-1]
     )             e# Increment current value. Will give 1, 2, ..., n
      _            e# Duplicate
       X           e# Push input
        \          e# Swap
         %         e# Modulus
          !        e# Negate
           *       e# Multiply
              :+   e# Sum of array. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/6a95f4fae0f4d97a109336c5890b5ade), 56 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `Int32` `i` A number
- **Output** `Int32` The sum of the divisors of the number

---

#### Golfed

```cs
i=>{int s=0,d=1;for(;d<=i;d++)s+=i%d<1?i/d:0;return s;};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
i => {
    int
        s = 0,
        d = 1;
        
    for( ; d <= i; d++ )
        s += i % d < 1 ? i / d : 0;
    
    return s;
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Takes an int
i => {
    // Initializes the sum 's' and divider 'd' vars
    int
        s = 0,
        d = 1;
        
    // Cycles each number lower than the the number 'i'
    for( ; d <= i; d++ )
    
        // Sums the result of the division between 'i' and 'd' if the modulus is 0
        s += i % d < 1 ? i / d : 0;
    
    // Returns the sum
    return s;
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestBench {
    public class Program {
        // Methods
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Func<Int32, Int32> f = i => {
                int s = 0, d = 1;

                for( ; d <= i; d++ )
                    s += i % d < 1 ? i / d : 0;

                return s;
            };

            List<Int32>
                testCases = new List<Int32>() {
                    7,
                    15,
                    20,
                    42,
                    1,
                    5,
                };

            foreach( Int32 testCase in testCases ) {
                Console.WriteLine( $" INPUT: {testCase}\nOUTPUT: {f( testCase )}" );
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `56 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: In this statement `s+=i%d<1?i/d:0;`, you can save 2 bytes by replacing `i/d` by `d`, the results will be the same ( mostly because it will add the same numbers by in the reverse order : For example, in the second test case, all the division result are added : `15+5+3+1=24`. If you add all the denominators ( i believe it's the word to describe the number used to divide the input, sorry if it's the wrong word, i'm not a native english speaker ), we get : `1+3+5+15=24`, which is the same )

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 70 bytes

```
@set/ai=%2+1,s=%3+i*!(%1%%i)
@if not %i%==%1 %0 %1 %i% %s%
@echo %s%
```

Alternative solution, also 70 bytes:

```
@set s=0
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/as+=%%i*!(%1%%%%i)
@echo %s%
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 4 bytes

```
ωḊΣ↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9858MdXecWP2rb@v//fxMjAA)

### How?

It's really simple: `ω` is the argument, `Ḋ` is divisors, `Σ` is sum, `↵` is output. I thought I already answered this challenge, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->x{(1..x).sum{|r|x%r>0?0:r}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iWsNQT69CU6@4NLe6pqimQrXIzsDewKqotvZ/QWlJsUJatHksF5RlaApnGhnAmQhBw9j/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 53 bytes

```
#(apply +(for[i(range 1(inc %)):when(=(mod % i)0)]i))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Casio-Basic, 42 bytes

```
sum(seq(piecewise(n/x=int(n/x),x,0),x,1,n
```

The `piecewise` acts as a shorter `If` statement. `seq` loops values of x from 1 to n, and the `piecewise` returns x if the number is a factor, otherwise it returns 0. `sum` adds the whole list together to output the total.

41 bytes for the function, +1 to add `n` in the parameters box.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

```ruby
->x{(1..x).sum{1[x%_1]*_1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuha7de0qqjUM9fQqNPWKS3OrDaMrVOMNY7XiDWtrISpuGheUlhQrpEWbx3JBWYamcKaRAZyJEDSMhWhdsABCAwA)

Abuses Ruby's nth bit operator.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
─Σ
```

One of many 2-bytes answers in a code-golf language.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlIZzi///N@cyNOUyMuAy5DIFAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
─   # Get a list of divisors of the (implicit) input-integer
 Σ  # Sum them together
    # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 3 bytes

```
Uz$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/P7RK5f9/Q1MA)

### Explanation

```
     implicit mode sequence - print nth term in sequence given input n
U    sum (                           )
 z         divisors (              )
  $                   current term
```