# Is it a Cyclops number? "Nobody" knows!

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, binary

**Task:**

Given an integer input, figure out whether or not it is a Cyclops Number.

What is a Cyclops number, you may ask?  Well, it's a number whose binary representation only has one `0` in the center!

**Test Cases:**

```
Input | Output | Binary  | Explanation
--------------------------------------
0     | truthy | 0       | only one zero at "center"
1     | falsy  | 1       | contains no zeroes
5     | truthy | 101     | only one zero at center
9     | falsy  | 1001    | contains two zeroes (even though both are at the center)
10    | falsy  | 1010    | contains two zeroes
27    | truthy | 11011   | only one zero at center
85    | falsy  | 1010101 | contains three zeroes
101   | falsy  | 1100101 | contains three zeroes
111   | falsy  | 1101111 | only one zero, not at center
119   | truthy | 1110111 | only one zero at center
```

**Input:**

- An integer or equivalent types. (`int`, `long`, `decimal`, etc.)
- Assume that if evaluating the input results in an integer overflow or other undesirable problems, then that input doesn't have to be evaluated.

**Output:**

- Truthy or falsy.
- Truthy/falsy output must meet the used language's specifications for truthy/falsy.  (e.g. C has `0` as false, non-zero as true)

**Challenge Rules:**

- Input that is less than 0 is assumed to be falsy and thus does not have to be evaluated.
- If the length of the binary representation of the number is even, then the number cannot be a Cyclops number.

**General Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answers in bytes wins!.
- [Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) apply for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/).

---

This is my first **Programming Puzzles & Code Golf** challenge, so any feedback on how I should improve would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note: This is [A129868](https://oeis.org/A129868)

Comment: +1 for the 2800 year late pop culture reference in the title

Comment: what is the maximum number that is be tested?

Comment: @Serverfrog since I did not specify a limit, assume that any positive integer can be tested.

Comment: Is binary input allowed?

Comment: Suggest case `11(1011)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
1¥¢q0 äè
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MaWicTAg5Og=&input=MTE5)

### Explanation:

```
1¥¢q0 äè   
                                                              119
  ¢          // Convert the input into a binary string        "1110111"
   q0        // Split the string on "0"                       ["111","111"]
      ä      // Reduce each item by:                            a     b
       è     //   Seeing how many times a is found in b       [1]
 1¥          // == 1; See if the result equals 1              True
```

The idea is to split the binary string at `0`, which would yield two items if there is only one `0`. Then we see if the first item matches the second to ensure it is palindromic. If the binary string contains multiple `0`s, then the reduce would return a multi-item array and that would fail the `==1` condition. If the binary string does contain one `0`, but is not palindromic, `äè` will return `0` because `b` contains `0` matches of `a`.

Comment: Took my pre-caffeinated brain a couple of seconds to see what was happening here! Nicely done. `r¶` should also work.

Comment: I don't know Japt, but if I understand correctly it does the following: `¤` = convert to binary; `q0` = split on 0s; `äè` I'm not entirely sure..; and the flag `-N` converts lists to `NaN`, but leaves `0` and `1` the same. For the `äè` part I can see that `119` is `[111,111]` after the split, which `äè` changes to `1`; and `85` is `[1,1,1,1]` after the split, which `äè` changes to `[1,1,1]`. Could you explain how `.ä("è")` works?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I added an explanation. I hope that helps.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, [no better time to learn Japt](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17410/58974) ;) As well as that, I'm also working on a new interpreter for Japt, with a load of new features.

Comment: Is `NaN` falsey in Japt? (i.e. if you perform an if-else with that as the condition does the if get executed? "Truthy/falsy output must meet the used language's specifications for truthy/falsy") Also `2` yields `2` which I doubt is falsey (but might be if Japt is like 05AB1E).

Comment: @JonathanAllan assuming that Japt is like JavaScript (which i'm assuming is true since it's just [transpired from JS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121286/85765)), `NaN` would be considered [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: @Tau ...but not `2` (which is yielded by inputting `2`) I believe; which would mean this is not currently conforming to spec.

Comment: JS assumes that any integer other than `0` is considered truthy...  however, if `2` is returning `2` as truthy, then this submission may need to be reworked.

Comment: I think replacing `äè` with `r¥`, as I mentioned above, should solve the issue @JonthanAllan raised.

Comment: Your code was almost a cyclops program.

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda n:(2*n^2*n+3)**2==8*n+9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoAgEADQ/ZzCpVqLZiL64U0iMEoSapIwotObiwcvfHG/mJIzUzrsuaxW8CBJ85wVtdKajOly@/Tu/tgEDmw8hydKNYbbcxRcOskqVYBA0AASUAtdToWA2P8)

Note that `2*n^2*n+3` is the bitwise xor of `2*n` and `2*n+3`, because that's Python's operator precedence.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to return `lambda n:(2*n^2*n+3)**2-8*n-9`, with a return value of `0` for cyclops numbers?

Comment: This yields `TRUE` for `n = -1`

Comment: @user2390246 this problem is clearly not intended for negatives- if it was, all accepting solutions would need to be negatives (and the way that python implements integers would mean that no solutions should accept in python)

Comment: @DreamConspiracy Can you explain more?

Comment: @SolomonUcko The rules specifically say that negative input is falsy and does not have to be evaluated.

Comment: @SolomonUcko negative numbers are typically stored in twos complement representation. Consider first fixed size integers (32 bit for example). Among other properties, TCR requires that the MSB is 1 in negative numbers, and 0 in positive. This would immediately require that all positive outputs are false. In python we have even more of a problem though. Negative numbers implicitly have an infinite sequence of 1s in the most significant direction. Good luck trying to find the middle of that

Comment: @user2390246 The problem was since edited to clarify that our code doesn't need to work for negatives. It could be handled for 2 bytes by appending `>1`.

Answer (score 19):

## x86 Machine Code, 17 bytes

```
8D 47 01 31 F8 89 C2 F7 D2 0F AF C2 8D 44 78 02 C3
```

The above bytes define a function that accepts a 32-bit integer input value (in the `EDI` register for this example, following a common System V calling convention, but you could actually pick pretty much any input register you wanted without affecting the size of the resulting code), and returns a result (in the `EAX` register) indicating whether the input value is a Cyclops number.

The input is assumed to be an unsigned integer, since the challenge rules state that we can ignore negative values.

The decision logic is borrowed from [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181156): since a Cyclops number has the form \$ n = (2 ^ k + 1) (2 ^ { k - 1 } - 1) \$, we can use a series of bit-twiddling operations to check the input.

*Note:* The return value is truthy/falsy, but the semantics are reversed, such that the function will return falsy for a Cyclops number. I claim this is legal because machine code doesn't have "specifications for truthy/falsy", which is the requirement in the question. (See below for an alternative version if you think this is cheating.)

In assembly language mnemonics, this is:

```
; EDI = input value
; EAX = output value (0 == Cyclops number)
8D 47 01           lea    eax, [edi + 1]          ; \ EAX = ((EDI + 1) ^ EDI)
31 F8              xor    eax, edi                ; /
89 C2              mov    edx, eax                ; \ EDX = ~EAX
F7 D2              not    edx                     ; /
0F AF C2           imul   eax, edx                ; EAX *= EDX
8D 44 78 02        lea    eax, [eax + edi*2 + 2]  ; EAX  = (EAX + (EDI * 2) + 2)
C3                 ret                            ; return, with EAX == 0 for Cyclops number
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLfa8IwEMff@1ccGUIqOmvH2M86RPfgyxh72oMgsY0alibSJOIY/uvr0tYWdZaal9K7zzf3vbuE3WUYpldMhNxEFJ6VjuZS8uvVwDkKMmlDqRGKLQWNYKJG3yGXa/Vm4jlNcJXYEG6o6/w4YE8VTagyXD/lwdmMqHg2w2iqOSXcRvq41aIRcztgv2Q7FSgHy2PBrUwyMMfqqVhuoKDINqeic5SQurzrXJrFhvN9ur7U3rmPD4pZZ35ND4@AAoIAF3NwAXptkEavjbajWTKlaQJMwevwE9q9E@EYAeBirJALmch0x8Lx5L8w6wBVASusFHZzc7s14PYXToRusaWEapOIanG7dCNZBKMVDb@KlQ9F9J4woT9youYBrDNigVGLTXUwgJayc@kcVsvpowjGp29r33sQgOfCC6CwyKKsR7tMKP9da33nOLYixIQJXJqoN@3tm60n@o3EbfMdzZf0/UbEv2tE7i/w4l1g5hLD/QfLHL4ULxt@@hsuOFmqtBvf@H8)**

---

As promised, if you think it's cheating to invert the semantics of truthy/falsy even in machine code where there are no real standards or conventions, then add three more bytes, for a total of **21 bytes**:

```
; EDI = input value
; AL  = output value (1 == Cyclops number)
8D 47 01           lea    eax, [edi + 1]          ; \ EAX = ((EDI + 1) ^ EDI)
31 F8              xor    eax, edi                ; /
89 C2              mov    edx, eax                ; \ EDX = ~EAX
F7 D2              not    edx                     ; /
0F AF C2           imul   eax, edx                ; EAX *= EDX
8D 44 78 01        lea    eax, [eax + edi*2 + 1]  ; EAX  = (EAX + (EDI * 2) + 1)
40                 inc    eax                     ; EAX += 1
0F 94 C0           setz   al                      ; AL = ((EAX == 0) ? 1 : 0)
C3                 ret                            ; return, with AL == 1 for Cyclops number
```

The first half of this code is the same as the original (down through the `imul` instruction). The `lea` is almost the same, but instead of adding a constant 2, it only adds a constant 1. That's because the following `inc` instruction increments the value in the `EAX` register by 1 in order to set the flags. If the "zero" flag is set, the `setz` instruction will set `AL` to 1; otherwise, `AL` will be set to 0. This is the standard way that a C compiler will generate machine code to return a `bool`.

Changing the constant added in the `lea` instruction obviously doesn't change the code size, and the `inc` instruction is very small (only 1 byte), but the `setz` instruction is a rather whopping 3 bytes. Unfortunately, I can't think of any shorter way of writing it.

Comment: This is so fast, I think it deserves to be shown off by testing all numbers up to a large value: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLbsIwELznK7apkBwehVKphwKVqtIDl557QIpM4qQrOTbyA1FV/fWmmwcRUNiL5dmZ3fWOk1GeJOUtqkT6VMDcunSjtbz7fA5OQNQElV5ZzJVIYWVfvxKpt/bdFxthWJfYcelFFHwHQNGhRlgv3awG45jbIo5ZuHZScEnIPev1RIrREOjk@7UKa@IhiLjXpiLWtOusQu@gYfF9zUovsZR2h1qX0lh4Kdv09Vbt5FN21Iwmm155wxOECx4Ca/YQAYz7oL3bekerydE6YQAtvL18QH98JlyGAKxZK9RCVJXuVLhc/RdWLwg7gISdgpzbkGsg6QpnwqhxyQjnjeqM@ylROSg4Ktaam2kDrAJxMZkBzh8nbdBlMIgOJTEDdnP@WzCKjltuDdXJWNhLaW1DwGaEdoIJNQ/K3ySTPLflqHiY/gE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: It should actually be even faster, @Deadcode. :-) Demonstrating it with inline assembly adds some overhead, but my old trick of jumping to a string of bytes (see e.g., [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142105)) has stopped working with TIO's compiler, and writing code to print the results directly in assembly is too much work to bother with. This is one of those unusual cases, though, where optimizing for size is not at odds with optimizing for speed. This is pretty much the way you'd write the code in asm if you were going for speed over size.

Comment: By consensus, it not unacceptable to return a status flag in an asm submission https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020/84624 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381234/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-the-flags-register-as-a-boolean-return-valu. If so, you could - 3 from your second answer.

Comment: Here's a clean way to [return boolean results efficiently from inline asm](https://tio.run/##dVLbTgIxEH3nK8Yaki4XQUh8EDAmookv@m5MSOl2lybdlvRCUOOvu87eCK7Ql03PnDNzemb5MOU8v5SaqxALmDsfr41RV5u7zh9QGoRyvmEWnt3DB1dm615CthaWBu1kqkUMO6aCiDpfHcBTUq1wQflZCaxWzGWrFSWgBFMIXNNuV8QyGgB@2f5dk5LXHAJ7YwteyTpLyswOKhLbl6T4BEkb33Q6UZVZUKqunp1zbLqZhK4m5@1jfAdnreotkMU95/qTAK0yimDUAxP8Nvg6NdTD2xPQRLE0gt6opV8SAFolXmGol7qQoz6VzgsL0sHj8vm/tngoOTaL2oMIV7vGtYLCK7S0UbVKK3yw@rDd71xqDxmTmtbbT4wFWoByMZ6BnN@M64OXfj9qWsoE6EX7d5JRdDxya7FPQkk3xgwHICsLtYNxMfyHFxG5fJhNJ/nwdfoL) - [and the result](https://godbolt.org/z/e44ex7)

Comment: `mul edx` or `imul edx` saves 1 byte over `imul eax, edx`, and produces the same result in EAX.  (It clobbers EDX but we're done with it at that point.)  This is a size vs. speed tradeoff: one-operand `mul`/`imul` is 3 uops for 32-bit operand-size on Intel.

Comment: Also BTW, only the x86-64 SysV calling convention passes an arg in EDI, not i386 SysV.  Your first version doesn't depend on one-byte `inc`/`dec` and is actually valid 64-bit machine code as well, which would decode as `lea eax, [rdi + 1]` and so on since there aren't address-size prefixes.  Re: truthy/falsy: yes, comments on the meta Q&A [Interpretation of Truthy/Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9441) point out that in languages like x86 asm where jump-if-zero and jump-if-nonzero are on equal footing, you can choose which you want.

Comment: Besides, `0` is highly appropriate to indicate that it *is* a cyclops.

Answer (score 12):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>60</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

The input \$n\$ is in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s.

**SPOILER WARNING**: For the square root, this regex uses a variant of the generalized multiplication algorithm, which is non-obvious and could be a rewarding puzzle to work out on your own. For more information, see an explanation for this form of the algorithm in [Find a Rocco number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179239/find-a-rocco-number/179420#179420).

*-2 bytes by allowing backtracking in the search for \$z\$*
*-1 byte [thanks to Grimmy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49371136#49371136), by searching for \$z\$ from smallest to largest instead of vice versa*
*+3 bytes to handle zero*
*-2 bytes by moving the square root capture outside the lookahead*

This works by finding \$z\$, a perfect square power of 2 for which \$n=2(n-z)+\sqrt{z}+1\$. Only the largest perfect square power of 2 not exceeding \$n\$ can satisfy this, but due to a golf optimization, the regex tries all of them starting with the smallest. Since each one corresponds to a cyclops number, only the largest one can result in a match.

```
^(x*)(?!(x(xx)+)\2*$)(x(x*))(?=(?=(\4*)\5+$)\4*$\6)x\1$|^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89b8IwEIb/CkQR3CVNSBBlwDVMHVgY2rEpkgVH4tY4lm0g5eO3p8lQqdIN773PSafnS5yF21lpfOKM3JM91vqbflrLNV0Gb1S@NgbgypeTqN1CEyGshtBA02CMxTQKsV8i7GreTzGLsHiOQ@xCWMyxKfLwvg3baHLF1Nfv3kpdAqZOyR3B/CmZITLHM3appCIAxS2JvZKaAHHI9UkpvJVcpc4o6WGcjJHJA4DmZapIl77C5fR@l24jNiC5EdbRWnsoP7JPxD9A/4Fe5qt80WP0la0vwVqfhZL7gRW6pMUgiBU71BaYfOHEZBxj9zBogtSSIeFBYnoUfleBRby50ch0Sh56i5yZk3fedifs8WizJM@y7Bc)

```
^                 # N = tail
(x*)              # tail = Z, with the smallest value that satisfies the following
                  # assertions (which is no different from the largest value that
                  # would satisfy them, since no more than one value can do so);
                  # \1 = N - Z
                   
(?!(x(xx)+)\2*$)  # Assert Z is a power of 2

# Assert Z is a perfect square, and take its square root
(x(x*))           # \4 = square root of Z; \5 = \4 - 1; tail = N - \1 - \4
(?=(\4*)\5+$)     # iff \4*\4 == Z, then the first match here must result in \6==0
(?=\4*$\6)        # test for divisibility by \4 and for \6==0 simultaneously

# Assert that N == \1*2 + \4 + 1. If this fails, then due to a golf optimization,
# the regex engine will backtrack into the capturing of \4, and try all smaller
# values to see if they are the square root of Z; all of these smaller values will
# fail, because the \4*\4==Z multiplication test only matches for one unique value
# of \4.
x\1$

|^$               # Match N==0, because the above algorithm does not
```

Comment: OP clarified that 0 should be truthy, so this currently doesn't solve the challenge.

Comment: Isn't a simple `^(1*)0\1$` enough?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Only if the input were in binary. That would trivialize a lot of challenges; consistently using unary input where applicable is much more interesting.

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 20 bytes

```javascript
p=>~p==(p^=p+1)*~p/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoAgEADA72hSaVfbnhKIaWyIu2h09OtWc5vLPa76gnyPmY7QI3SGrTGA4B1YGTk0npceqQgEbXE1@mdRKYlRRIFSesqVUpgSnV/7Cw)

Maybe this is correct, maybe.

Thanks Grimy, 1 byte saved.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
f=(p,q)=>p&1?f(p/2,q+q|2):!(p^q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYm9CoMwGEX3PMXXpSaosRHsH8RODp36AqUY1GiLTaLGguC7Wwsd9Cz3Hs5LfESXtU9jfaXzYpokx8ZrCI/Nll0kNkHoNW4zhuS8webRkMkChxRdlektjHDr7XyQvwIx@DGCFHU3oOhvtu1tNSAWLmN4WMVjtIxsx5bGTgtL6VvYrMLBPXeDklCp20TMroDHkGnV6bqgtS6xokbkicrxnoALzgjOPBK7ihAyfQE)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

```javascript
p=>/^(1*)0\1$/.test(p.toString(2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY89C4MwFEX3/Io3FEwqRiPYj0E3h04dukoxqFGLTYI@C4L/3VrooHe593Cm@5IfORR9a9HTpqwWFS82TvwnFUcWZOLgc6wGpJajeWDf6pqGjC0IMeTkpu2IMMN9xHUQbxci4JcZlOyGiUR/wn7EZiIi3MrwvJOXaCtFILYkrhvK@Vti0VA/K12/ZlyZPpUra4gTKIweTFfxztRUcyvLVJf0xMAFZwZnLUVdzdY3Xw)

Comment: [20](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoAgEADA72hSaVfbnhKIaWyIu2h09OtWc5vLPa76gnyPmY7QI3SGrTGA4B1YGTk0npceqQgEbXE1@mdRKYlRRIFSesqVUpgSnV/7Cw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Test, not match

Comment: @edc65 Did you find out any failed testcase?

Comment: @tsh `.test` not `.match`

Comment: @ASCII-only Wow, sound reasonable... How can you read this?

Comment: @tsh read what lol

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt),  <s>25</s> <s>19</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
¢êÅ©1¶¢èT
```

*Thanks to @Shaggy for -1 byte*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Ciw6sOtx5aaXhoG5C5IuT/fyNzAA)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9Ciw6sOtx5aaXhoG5C5IuT/fyNzAA)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ourFqTG2ouhU&input=ODU)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 23 bytes

```perl6
{.base(2)~~/^(1*)0$0$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ovKbE4VcNIs65OP07DUEvTQMVARb/2vzVXWn6RgkZOZl5qsaZCNRdncWKlgn2ahnaufkyKtr4mV@1/QwUQqFFIS8wpruQyhfJKikpLMiq5DI2QJY3MUSQtTJElDQ0MkXmGlkhKAQ)

Regex based solution

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica (Wolfram language), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to J42161217!*

```
OddQ@Log2[#+Floor@Sqrt[#/2]+2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98/JSXQwSc/3ShaWdstJz@/yCG4sKgkWlnfKFbbKFbtv0t@dEBRZl5JdJ6Crp1CWnRebKyOQnWejoKBjoKxQW3sfwA)

Pure function taking an integer as input and returning `True` or `False`. Based on the fact (fun to prove!) that a number `n` is Cyclops if and only if `n` plus the square root of `n/2` plus `2` rounds down to an odd power of 2. (One can replace `Floor` by either `Ceiling` or `Round` as long as one also replaces `+2` by `+1`.) Returns `True` on input `0`.

Comment: you can save 1 byte by using `Log2[#+Floor@Sqrt...`

Comment: and 1 more using [`√()`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98/JSXQwSc/PdpIR1nbLSc/v8jhUccsDWV9I01to1i1/y750QFFmXkl0XkKunYKadF5sbE6CtV5OgoGOgrGBrWx/wE) instead of `Sqrt[]`

Comment: Is the byte count correct? TIO gives 32 bytes for the current program.

Comment: @mbomb007 aha, the TIO didn't incorporate J42161217's 1-byte savings. Fixed.

Comment: Was there a reason you didn't use what attinat suggested?

Comment: no, just laziness

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->x{x+x+2==(1+x^=x+1)*x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukK7QtvI1lbDULsizrZC21BTq6L2f7ShjoKRjoKpjoIhkDIy11GwALENgMKGhpaxeqmJyRnVNXk1CgWlJcUK0Xk6CoqKadF5sbF6WfmZeRrqCuqatf8B)

Comment: Nice. There might be a shorter version with different assignments and precedence, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
¢ðT ¥¢Êz
```

Thanks to Luis felipe de Jesus Munoz for fixing my submission!

[Try it Online!](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308155149/https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ovBUIKWiyno=&input=MjE=)

## Old regex-based solution, 15 bytes

```
¤f/^(1*)0\1$/ l
```

Returns 1 for true, 0 for false.

[Try it Online!](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308025259/https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=pGYvXigxKikwXDEkLyBs&input=Mw==)

Comment: Well played, I should really learn regular expressions sometime. :) +1

Comment: @Quintec Regex is awesome :)

Comment: Update: found shorter way :)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ovBUIKWiyno=&input=NSAtUQ==)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Thanks, that's a really nice use of the `==` operator!

Comment: I'll get your bounty setup for this on Monday; I'm not online over the weekend and, if I do it now, I'll only forget about it.

Comment: The 8 byte version [fails for `1`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=ovBUIKWiyno&input=MQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (use isPalindrome built-in, `ŒḂ`, instead of `⁼Ṛ$`)

```
B¬ŒḂ⁼SƊ
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer which yields `1` (truthy) or `0` (falsey).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p0JpHjXse7pylAqSCj3X9///f0NASAA)**

#### How?

```
B¬ŒḂ⁼SƊ - Link: integer             e.g. 1    9          13         119
B       - to base 2                      [1]  [1,0,0,1]  [1,1,0,1]  [1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
 ¬      - logical NOT (vectorises)       [0]  [0,1,1,0]  [0,0,1,0]  [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
      Ɗ - last three links as a monad:
  ŒḂ    -   is a palindrome?             1    1          0          1
     S  -   sum                          0    2          1          1
    ⁼   -   equal?                       0    0          0          1
```

Comment: Looks like you actually had the clever idea before me, but its cleverness isn't obvious (`Bċ0⁼1ȧŒḂ` is also 8 bytes), `⁼Ṛ$` is the same as `ŒḂ` for -1. Also, you don't need to handle negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks Erik, the is palindrome built-in slipped my mind for some reason!

Comment: Actually, you can also use `ṚƑ` in its place nowadays, so you might want to remember it like that (the most important `Ƒ`s).

Answer (score 5):

## C (gcc), 26 bytes

```
f(n){n=~n==(n^=-~n)*~n/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsJADETv@xVDQUispUU8CGv@RISyJSUHo5TeSvfX1y3Oad68Sd2cUilKzptLdhHyl3TZ@Zy9v8a9mK94j@bEYQuAfhbQsZkMEfa434YjtbYtVw@YgpSM/wR8l3pXak7T05sLjGPYyw8)

Port of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181156/6484). Relies on implementation-defined ordering of operations.

## C++ (clang), 38 bytes

```
int f(int n){return~n==(n^=-~n)*~n/2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1BCsIwELznFUtFSKzVIh6ENL5EhJI0utBuQ0xPpfl6THQOwwyzO6Oda/TY0yslpACWFyax@iEsniIpxempmkjiEOl8kVvaIelxMQN0n2BwPr3vrPxMPRIXbGUAdvbw60HVSsDudm0LsqxrkXMAtMDzlPg7AOfzueXV3jyoOgIKybb0BQ)

Can't omit the types in C++, can’t omit the return in clang, otherwise identical.

Comment: I would prefer that C++ answers be differentiated from C answers by using `return` instead of the fragile and platform-dependent implicit accumulator return value exploit.

Comment: I would also like the rules to require standard-compliance, but they don’t, so not making use of this would just be bad golf. C++ (clang) requires the return, making this 38 bytes.

Comment: Then you can get around this by having C (gcc) and C++ (clang) in your answer instead of C (gcc) and C++ (gcc). I've now done that.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ḃD↔Dḍ×ᵐ≠
```

This is a predicate that succeeds if its input is a Cyclops number and fails if its input is not a Cyclops number. Success/failure is the most fundamental truthy/falsey concept in Brachylog.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9icmFjaHlsb2cy///huINE4oaUROG4jcOX4bWQ4omg//8yNw) Or, [find all truthy outputs up to 10000](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/zEwMDAw4p@me@KGsOKCguKIpz99y6L/4biDROKGlEThuI3Dl@G1kOKJoP///1g).

#### Explanation

```
          Input is an integer
ḃ         Get its binary representation, a list of 1's and 0's
 D        Call that list D
  ↔       When reversed...
   D      It's the same value D
    ḍ     Dichotomize: break the list into two halves
          One of these halves should be all 1's; the other should contain the 0
     ×ᵐ   Get the product of each half
       ≠  Verify that the two products are not equal
```

This succeeds only when given a Cyclops number, because:

- If the binary representation isn't a palindrome, `D↔D` will fail; in what follows, we can assume it's a palindrome.
- If there is more than one zero, both halves will contain at least one zero. So the products will both be zero, and `×ᵐ≠` will fail.
- If there is no zero, both halves will contain only ones. So the products will both be one, and `×ᵐ≠` will fail.
- That leaves the case where there is exactly one zero; since we already know we have a palindrome, this must be the central bit. It will appear in one half, causing that half's product to be zero; the other half will contain all ones, so its product will be one. Then we have 1 ≠ 0, `×ᵐ≠` succeeds, and the whole predicate succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 (or 9) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
bD0¢sÂQ*
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ycXg0KLiw02BWv//W5gCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/JINDC10Odxen22j91/kfbapjZK5jaGipY6hjaKRjYapjaGAYCwA).

Returns `1` if truthy; `0` or any positive integer other than `1` as falsey. In 05AB1E only `1` is truthy and everything else is falsey, but I'm not sure if this is an allowed output, or if the output should be two consistent and unique values. If the second, a trailing `Θ` can be added so all outputs other than `1` become `0`:

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ycXg0KLiw02BWudm/P9vYQoA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/JBeDQ4uKDzcFap2b8V/nf7SpjpG5jqGhpY6hjqGRjoWpjqGBYSwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
b     # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
 D    # Duplicate it
  0¢  # Count the amount of 0s
 s    # Swap to get the binary again
  ÂQ  # Check if it's a palindrome
 *    # Multiply both (and output implicitly)

  Θ   # Optionally: check if this is truthy (==1),
      # resulting in truthy (1) or falsey (0)
```

---

An arithmetic approach would be **10 bytes:**

```
LoD<s·>*Iå
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ9/FpvjQdjstz8NL//@3MAUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/n3wXm@JD2@20Kg8v/a/zP9pUx8hcx9DQUsdQx9BIx8JUx9DAMBYA).

**Explanation:**

Creates a sequences using the algorithm \$a(n) = (2^n-1)*(2*2^n+1)\$, and then checks if the input-integer is in this sequence.

```python
L        # Create a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 o       # For each integer in the list, take 2 to the power this integer
  D<     # Create a copy, and decrease each value by 1
  s·     # Get the copied list again, and double each value
    >    # Then increase each value by 1
  *      # Multiply the numbers at the same indices in both lists
     Iå  # Check if the input-integer is in this list
         # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: Having `1` as truthy and all other numbers as falsy is acceptable for this challenge, since other languages (e.g. C and TI-BASIC) have similar truthy/falsy definitions (0/non-zero for both).  As long as what's considered truthy or falsy matches with the language's specifcations, then it's fair game.

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>53</s> 47 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to both Deadcode and Grimy

```
^((?=(x*?)(\2((x+)x(?=\5$))+x$))(?!\2{6})\3x)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc09T8MwFIXhv9JGlXpvQty00A4NbiaGLh1gJCBZya1jcO3INm3ox28PYUBiOcP7DOdDHIWvnGpD6ltVkztY80nfveOGTqNnkk9dC3Dmm1ncvwMUHLq4QCgXAF2C3RDK5QQx6YaBYlwuLqsblvcdxpM@np2RBfsSnDISkHmtKoLVXfqAmJ8apQlAc0ei1soQII65@dIaL5Jr5lutAkzTKeZqD2C4ZJqMDA1uFter8juxA8Vb4TxtTQD5mr0h/gH9B7OZF/P1L2NonD1FW3MUWtUjJ4yk9ShKdL63DnL1yClXSYLDYdRFzFFLIoBCdhChasAhVtZ4q4lpK4ee3/osXWbZDw)

<sub><sup>*explanation by [Deadcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17216/deadcode)*</sup></sub>

This regex takes its input in unary, as a sequence of `x` characters in which the length represents the number. Properties of its binary representation are handled indirectly, by doing math on its unary representation.

It works by looping the following operation, which is a subtraction at every step:

- Trim the leftmost and rightmost `1` from the number's binary representation, if the `1` being trimmed from the left is immediately followed by another `1` or the full number is `101`

If and only if the initial input was a cyclops number, it will be the next smallest cyclops number at every step of the loop, e.g. `1110111` → `11011` → `101` → `0`. The regex matches if and only if the value is `0` at the end.

```
^                              # tail = N, the input number
(                              # While tail is odd and is >= 3, and has a leftmost "11"
                               # in its binary representation, trim off the leftmost and
                               # rightmost 1 from its binary representation. If it is a
                               # cyclops number, it will be the next smaller cyclops
                               # number on the next iteration.
    (?=
        (x*?)                  # Find the smallest \2 such that tail - 2*\2 satisfies the
                               # following assertion, i.e. that tail - 2*\2 = 2^k-1
                               # where k >= 2. In other words, assert tail is odd, and
                               # let \2 = (tail - 2^k + 1) / 2, where 2^k-1 has the
                               # largest value of k such that 2^k-1 <= tail. If tail is
                               # a cyclops number, then \2-1 will be the next smallest
                               # cyclops number;
                               # tail -= \2
        (                      # \3 = tool to make tail-1 = \2-1 (will be used later)
            \2                 # tail -= \2
            ((x+)x(?=\5$))+x$  # Assert tail = 2^k-1 where k >= 2
        )
    )
    (?!\2{6})                  # Assert that tail < 6*\2, which is a way of asserting
                               # that in tail's binary representation, the next 1 to the
                               # right of the one we'll be trimming is also 1. This
                               # prevents for example, trimming 10110111 -> 11011, which
                               # would give us a false positive. As a worst case example,
                               # let's say tail = 0b101111111111111111111111111111111111
                               # this would give us:
                               #             \2 = 0b001000000000000000000000000000000000
                               #           6*\2 = 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000
                               # So it's not quite exactly asserting that tail begins
                               # with "11" in its binary representation, and would
                               # continue looping in that case, but that doesn't matter
                               # because that number could never be trimmed into a
                               # cyclops number anyway. With any smaller value of tail
                               # that passes the other tests, we'd have:
                               #           tail = 0b101111111111111111111111111111111101
                               #             \2 = 0b000111111111111111111111111111111111
                               #           6*\2 = 0b101111111111111111111111111111111010
                               # and in this case tail >= 6*\2, so it stops the loop.
                               # On the other end of the scale is 0b101, which needs to
                               # be trimmed even though it doesn't have two leftmost 1
                               # bits in a row. And indeed, that works:
                               #           tail = 0b101
                               #             \2 = 0b001
                               #           6*\2 = 0b110
                               # In this case, it is just barely true that tail < 6*\2
                               # and the loop is allowed to continue one more step.
    \3x                        # tail = \2-1
)*
$                              # Assert that tail = 0 after the loop finished. This will
                               # be true iff N is a cyclops number. If it fails to match,
                               # backtracking cannot make it match, because everything in
                               # the loop is atomic.
```

Comment: In the course of fully commenting and proving your regex (not quite finished yet), I got it down to 50 bytes: `^((?=(x(x*?))(\3((x+)(?=\6$))+xx$))(?!\2{6})x\4)*$` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc09T8MwFIXhv9JGlXpvQty0lA4NbiaGLh1gJCBZya1jcO3IMa3px28PYUBiOcP7DOdDHEVXOdX6tGtVTe5gzSd9944bOo2eST6FFuDMN7O4fwcoOAQIcYEI5T1ASHBI5WqCmIQwLBTjcnFZ3TCUS4wnfTw7I/P2xTtlJCDrtKoIVnfpEjE/NUoTgOaORK2VIUAcc/OlNV4k16xrtfIwTaeYqz2A4ZJpMtI3uFlcr6rbiR0o3grX0dZ4kK/ZG@If0H8wm3kxX/8y@sbZU7Q1R6FVPXLCSFqPokTne@sgV4@ccpUkOBxGIWKOWhIeFLKD8FUDDrGyprOamLZy6Pmtz9KHLPsB "JavaScript (SpiderMonkey) – Try It Online"))

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f n=or[2*4^k-2^k-1==n|k<-[0..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAr@yhU2zhLkUF@RIx6KAk2hbmsb9bh4E59ie6lGr1IPrKhtthix3/SGt549oZ1fdibT33IKDhzkEKNOBDKi6DB6OQkHFEYuQJ5z@KkGix9QM)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>22</s> <s>19</s>  <s>17</s>  <s>15</s> 14   bytes

-3 bytes thanks to BolceBussiere !

-4 bytes thanks to ngn!

-1 byte thanks to Traws!

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
1=1#.(*:|.)@#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DW0NlfU0tKxq9DQdlK3@a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCkYwhimcBEjGMvIHMayQMgawHUYGlr@BwA)

Comment: -3 Bytes by using `+/=<:@#` instead of `,@0-:1-.~]`

Comment: @BolceBussiere Of course, that's much better! Thanks!

Comment: `#=1++/`­­­­­­­

Comment: `(#=1++/)@(*|.)@#:`

Comment: @ngn Thank you! Nice and simple code!

Comment: `1=1#.1-(*|.)@#:`

Comment: @ngn Addicted to J?

Comment: i don't know enough j to use it but it's fun to learn from other people's code by trying to shorten it

Comment: -1 byte `1=1#.(*:|.)@#:`

Comment: @Traws Nice, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

Convert to binary and check with a regex. Returns `0` if true, `nil` if false.

-3 bytes thanks to [GB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b).

```ruby
->n{"%b"%n=~/^(1*)0\1$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur1pJNUlJNc@2Tj9Ow1BL0yDGUEW/9n@0oY6CkY6CqY6CIZAyMtdRsACxDYDChoaWsXqpickZ1TV5NQoFpSXFCtF5OgqKimnRebGxeln5mXka6grqmrX/AQ)

For two bytes more, there's a direct port of the Python solution:

```ruby
->n{(2*n^2*n+3)**2==8*n+9}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a"m=%1^-~%1,!(m/2*(m+2)-%1)
```

Explanation: A Cyclops number has the form \$ n = (2 ^ k + 1) (2 ^ { k - 1 } - 1) \$. The bitwise XOR then results in \$ m = 2 ^ k - 1 \$ from which we can recalculate \$ n = \lfloor \frac m 2 \rfloor ( m + 2 ) \$. This can then be used to test whether \$ n \$ was a Cyclops number.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```r
(x=scan())%in%(2*4^(n=0:x)-2^n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DU1M1M09Vw0jLJE4jz9bAqkJT1yguT9dQ87@hoeV/AA)

R doesn't have a built-in for converting to binary, so I simply used one of the formulae from OEIS to calculate a list of terms from the sequence.

`n<-0:x` generates a generous list of starting values. `2*4^(n<-0:x^2)-2^n-1)` is the formula from OEIS, and then it checks whether the input appears in that sequence using `%in%`.

-2 bytes by not having to handle negative inputs. -2 bytes by remembering I can change `<-` to `=`.

Answer (score 3):

### Excel, <s>97</s> 63 Bytes

```
=A1=2*4^(ROUND(LOG(A1,4),0))-2^(ROUND(LOG(A1,4),0))-1
```

Calculates 2 numbers:

> Twice the nearest Power of 4
>   `>Num|Binary|2*Power4|Binary`
>   `>  1|     1| 2* 1= 2|    10`
>   `>  2|    10| 2* 4= 8|  1000`
>   `>  4|   100| 2* 4= 8|  1000`
>   `> 20| 10100| 2*16=32|100000`

> 1 Plus the square root of the nearest Power of 4
>   `>Num|Binary|1+√Power4|Binary`
>   `>  1|     1|1+  √1= 2|    10`
>   `>  2|    10|1+  √4= 3|    11`
>   `>  4|   100|1+  √4= 3|    11`
>   `> 20| 10100|1+ √16= 5|   101`

Then subtract the second number from the first:

> `>Num|Binary|2*Power4|Binary|1+√Power4|Binary|a-b|Binary`
>   `>  1|     1| 2* 1= 2|    10|1+  √1= 2|    10|  0|     0`
>   `>  2|    10| 2* 4= 8|  1000|1+  √4= 3|    11|  5|   101`
>   `>  4|   100| 2* 4= 8|  1000|1+  √4= 3|    11|  5|   101`
>   `> 20| 10100| 2*16=32|100000|1+ √16= 5|   101| 27| 11011`

And compare this result with the original number

**Old Method**

```
=DEC2BIN(A1)=REPLACE(REPT("1",1+2*INT(IFERROR(LOG(A1,2),0)/2)),1+IFERROR(LOG(A1,2),0)/2,1,"0")
```

Start with the Log-base-2 of A1 and round it down the nearest even number, then add 1.

Next create a string of that many `"1"`s, and replace the middle character with a `"0"` to create a Cyclops number with a binary length that is always odd, and the same as or 1 less than the binary length of A1

Then, compare it with the Binary representation of A1

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>29 28</s>  27 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat*

A port of the [21-byte JS answer by @tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181134/58563).

```c
f(p){p=2*~p==~(p=-~p^p)*p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCsIwEEbhfU/xUxBmWgMiiIuYm4hQolMCOg5VcFGSoxsD7h58L7o5xlqFjFcL@6FYCIUsuGIX48F8ro8pKTHWDpDnQknf0LDzUJxwuB1bjOOfgSQkpMywpX1C/eZ61n4LZd88d7l@o9yn@VXd5wc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
BŒḂaB¬S=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p6KSHO5oSnQ6tCbY1/P@ocYfCo4Y5unaPGuYqADmH24HkdpAQUIDrcPujpjX//0cb6pjqGBrpGJnrWAAZBoY6hoaWsQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`^(1+)\1
$+0
10
1
^((1+)0\2)?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSzshTsNQWzPGkEtF24DLEIi44jRAIgYxRpr2Kv//g0RMuQwNuQyNuIzMuSyAbAMgByRgaAkA) Link includes test cases. Edit: After clarification, previous solution didn't handle zero correctly. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert from decimal to unary.

```
+`^(1+)\1
$+0
10
1
```

Convert from unary to binary, using the method from the Retina wiki.

```
^((1+)0\2)?$
```

Check for the same number of `1`s before and after the `0`, or an empty string (which is how the above conversion handles zero).

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 22 bytes

```
{Flip@_=_∧1=0~_}@Bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBlq/C/2i0ns8Ah3jb@UcdyQ1uDuvhaB6fMvP9@qakpxdEqBQXJ6bFcAUWZeSUhqcUlzonFqcXRaToK0QY6CoY6CqZAEkgZGukoGJnrKFiA@AYgAUPL2Nj/AA)

### Alternatives

**27 bytes:** `{BitXor[2*_,2*_+3]^2=8*_+9}`

**27 bytes:** `{BitXor@@(2*_+0'3)^2=8*_+9}`

**27 bytes:** `{Palindromic@_∧1=0~_}@Bin`

**28 bytes:** `{BitXor[...2*_+0'3]^2=8*_+9}`

**28 bytes:** `{BitXor[…2*_+0'3]^2=8*_+9}`

**28 bytes:** `{Same@@Bisect@_∧1=0~_}@Bin`

**29 bytes:** `{_[#_/2|Floor]=0∧1=0~_}@Bin`

**30 bytes:** `Same@Bin@{_+2^Floor[Log2@_/2]}`

**30 bytes:** `{_[#_/2|Floor]=0and 1=0~_}@Bin`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

```php
function($x){return($c=strlen($a=decbin($x)))&1&&trim($a,1)===$a[$c/2|0];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda4MwFH02v@JSgjYgzEid7VzWp409DOZ7V0qaRRRclSTCoOtvd0lrO12ezj1fl5u2bPvHdVu2gAUw6IvuIEzVHOb4mxyVNJ2yUDBtVC0t4uxTin11lgnxqe8bVX1ZPqSEMYb5Bou7@CfaZqc@QwgbqY22vRvkRcCewKhOhsijDhe81m5IxsJEofFoguHR1dgSp6P0Mpmko2nZv@5Lz3VvtLqnl65b8x81mGK6SBdJtExvSbS1RxaNklyUcxiu5doi58AKCByRJ0XZWCqE2YeZhZZ2P42FCwA5s9Z8FZiLrSHIudYBPEDwwqs6CCF/zXfP728ZOvW/)

Or **61 bytes** using Arrow syntax:

```php
fn($x)=>($c=strlen($a=decbin($x)))&1&trim($a,1)===$a[$c/2|0];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBPS8MwFD83n@IxwtpAwKSsdrNmOykeBHufQ2JMaKG60kQQ1M9ek63bWnN6v7@Pl7Zq@9tNW7WAjejNR4K/iFgnWAnrukZ7LMWbVq/1QSFkzueuq989TTkRQmC5xeoq/WG7oi8Qwk5bZ0HAFkUMxBpc96kpiniYjWxsANlYmCg8HSEYHl@NLWk@Si@zSZpNy/51H3tOe9nqmh@7zs0XajClfJEvMrbMz0m080eafaelqhIYrpXWT8GBOyDwjSKtqr2nKMye3Yx6WvkfwSYEgBxYbz4JIsQ2EJfS2hhuIL6XdRNTKB/Kl7unxwL99n8)

Totally naïve non-mathematical approach, just strings.

```php
function cyclops( $x ) {
    $b = decbin( $x );     // convert to binary string (non-zero left padded)
    $l = strlen( $b );     // length of binary string
    $t = trim( $b, 1 );    // remove all 1's on either side
    $m = $b[ $l / 2 |0 ];  // get the middle "bit" of the binary string
    return 
        $l & 1 &&          // is binary string an odd length?
        $t === $m;         // is the middle char of the binary string the same as
                           // string with left and right 1's removed? (can only be '0')
}
```

Or **60 bytes** based on @Chronocidal's algorithm [above](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181128/is-it-a-cyclops-number-nobody-knows/181173#181173).

```php
function($x){return decbin($x)==str_pad(0,log($x,2)|1,1,2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBRa4MwFIWfza@4lIAKeTBSZzvr@rSxh8F8X0fJ0lgF0ZBEGHT97S5pbafLS@4995wv3MhKDputrCRgDjkMZd9yU3dtgL/DkxKmVy0cBP@qL0qea6P2kh2CiDTd0UokDn8oofbKzkOGEDZCG21JH8iLIH8Co3pBkEddXbJGuyaZDmYTGk86GA9dTy1xOkmvklk6msP@sa@c27vR@oFeWXfynzSaYrpMl0m0Su9J9GmXLDslGK8CGLdl2lbOgRWEcEKe4FVnJQKLnVkQK7u/xdwFILyo1nwb5C62Bb9gWvvwCP4LqxufQPFa7J/f3zJ0Hn4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 17 bytes

```
ĐļƖĐ⁺2⇹^⇹ᵮ₂2⇹^-⁻=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQje45NOzLhUeMuo0ftO@OA@OHWdY@amsA83UeNu23//zcyBwA)

No string manipulation required

```
ĐļƖĐ⁺2⇹^⇹₂2⇹^-⁻=
```

| Instruction | Stack | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Đ` | n,n | implicit input (n); duplicate onto stack |
| `ļƖ` | n,k | take base-2 log of n and cast to integer (k) |
| `Đ` | n,k,k | duplicate k on stack |
| `⁺` | n,k,k+1 | increment top of stack |
| `2⇹^` | n,k,2^(k+1) | raise 2 to the k+1 power |
| `⇹` | n,2^(k+1),k | swap the top two items on the stack |
| `ᵮ₂` | n,2^(k+1),k/2 | cast top of stack to float, then divide by 2 |
| `2⇹^` | n,2^(k+1),2^(k/2) | raise 2 to the k/2 power |
| `-⁻` | n,2^(k+1)-2^(k/2)-1 | subtract and decrement |
| `=` | True/False | check for equality; implicit print |

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
bDZqs0c=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrklyiCosNkm0hXKjogsWGhpYQJgA)

Port of emirps's Vyxal answer.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `P`, \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
bD0c1=sZq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSgFLsgqWlJWm6FiuTXAySDW2LowohfKjwgsWGhpYQJgA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
bDZqs0c=  # Implicit input
bD        # Convert to binary and duplicate
  Zqs     # Check if it's a palindrome and swap
     0c=  # Is this equal to the count of 0s?
          # Implicit output
```

```python
bD0c1=sZq  # Implicit input
bD         # Convert to binary and duplicate
  0c       # Count the number of "0"s in the string
    1=     # Is it equal to 1?
      sZq  # Swap and check if it's a palindrome
           # P flag multiplies them together
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>31</s> <s>35</s> 26 bytes

*-5 thanks to @DLosc*

```
.!5*+2base..-1%=\{0=},,1=&
```

Link includes test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbaBgqGCqYKlgaKBgZK5gYQpkGCoYGoKwZWz1fz1FUy1to6TE4lQ9PV1DVduYagPbWh0dQ1u1/7WqeVr/AQ)

## Explanation

```
.!5*+2base..-1%=\{0=},,1=& | whole program
.!5*+                      | if the input is 0, make it 5 (smallest non-zero cyclops number)
     2base..               | push the binary version of the input
            -1%            | push the reversed version of the binary
               =           | is it equal to the non-reversed version?
                \{0=},,    | count the number of zeros 
                       1=  | is it equal to 1?
                         & | are both of the above checks true?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
Π:Ḃ=$0O=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwizqA64biCPSQwTz0iLCIiLCIwXG4xXG41XG45XG4xMFxuMjdcbjg1XG4xMDFcbjExMVxuMTE5Il0=)

Different approach from the other Vyxal answer.

```
Π        # binary of input
  Ḃ=     # the equality of the reversed version of it to itself (0 for non palindrome, 1 for palindrome)
       = # is equal to
 :  $0O  # the count of 0s in itself
```

Could potentially be golfed

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>65</s> <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 58 bytes

*+1 byte to handle 0 correctly*

```
^((((x*)xx)\3)x)?(?=(\1*)\2*(?=\4$)((x*)(?=\7$)x)*$)\1*$\5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BT8JAEAXgv4JNE2aKXQqCJtSFkwcuHPRoNdmUYTu67DbbFSrib6/FxMR3ennf4b2pg2pKz3VIm5q35PfOvtNn56Wl4@CR9ENbA5zkcpx0r9CnTbBtsbjBFmEloZgkWEyTvhazGH/50u/i3pMYe46LeZeMTyiCewqerQYUjeGS4PY6nSHmx4oNARjpSW0NWwLEK2k/jMEvLY1oasMBhukQc94BWKmFIatDhcvp@czNRm2AZa18Q2sbQD9nL4h/QP/BLieryeLCGCrvjtHaHpTh7cArq2kxiEYm3zkPOd9Lynk0wv4waiPhqSYVgFHsVSgr8Iils40zJIzT/Z5/d1k6z7If)

Works by asserting the input is of the form \$ (2^k - 1) (2^{k+1} + 1) \$. Ties [Deadcode's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181158/6484) but with a completely different algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 57 char, 114 bytes

```
{⍵≤0:1⋄k=m←⌈k←2÷⍨≢v←{(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟⍵)⊤⍵}⍵:0⋄((,1)≡∪v∼⍦0)∧∼m⊃v}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵≤0:1⋄k=m←⌈k←2÷⍨≢v←{(2⍴⍨⌊1+2⍟⍵)⊤⍵}⍵:0⋄((,1)≡∪v∼⍦0)∧∼m⊃v}
  ⎕fmt f¨0 1 5 12 27 85 101 119
┌8───────────────┐
│ 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1│
└~───────────────┘
```

This below would be (modulus bugs) the function that would convert a positive integer number omega in one array of digits in base alpha:

```
{(⍺⍴⍨⌊1+⍺⍟⍵)⊤⍵}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 101 <s>107</s> bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @Chronocidal.

```
=AND(ISEVEN(LOG(A1,2)),MID(DEC2BIN(A1),LEN(DEC2BIN(A1))/2+1,1)="0",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(A1),1,))=1)
```

Performs 3 checks:

- Odd length

```
ISEVEN(LOG(A1,2))
```

- Middle character is `0`

```
MID(DEC2BIN(A1),LEN(DEC2BIN(A1))/2+1,1)="0"
```

- There is a single `0`

```
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(A1),1,))=1
```

Comment: Save 6 bytes by changing `ISODD(LEN(DEC2BIN(A1)))` to `ISEVEN(LOG(A1,2))`

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>142</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>59</s></sup> 55 bytes

Saved <s>10</s> a whopping <s>21</s> 23 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```cpp
int f(int n){int c=__builtin_ctz(~n);n=(n>>c)+2==2<<c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BCoMwEETvfoXQgwml0ASkrdn4JYVgVy0BXaUml4r99RRPhcJeZuANzAzO8@mJmJKnkPdiV5Lrbmide0Q/BE8Ow1t8SBqyguoa5VFbqwHQbOngCYfYduCnJby6ZqyzsfEk5JrlS2irCqcYAHpxlgDFnQrzxxXDS4bfuB5uQF@Y4FqyVdwppfjkd2xLXw)

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
bool is_cyclops(int n)
{
    int ones = 1;
    while ((n & 1) == 1)
    {
        ++ones;
        n /= 2;
    }
    while (--ones, n /= 2, (n & 1) == 1)
    {
        // nothing to do
    }
    return n == 0 && ones == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (clang), <s>72</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 60 bytes

As with [Neil's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181156/17216) and [Grimmy's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181153/17216) solutions, this works by asserting that the input is of the form \$(2^k-1)(2^{k+1}+1)\$.

5 bytes were dropped thanks to Arnauld, by changing `((x)+1)` to `-~(x)` and `((x)-1)` to `~-(x)`, and then changing `n-a*-b` to `n+a*b`. An additional 7 bytes were dropped thanks to ceilingcat.

```
int f(int n){int z,k=1;while((z=n+~-k*~(k*=2))>0);return!z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7RDoMgDHznK7rsBeZM2LKHRcB/MYhbI6JBzBKN/roD7cO1d71cq4ch17Zyn31HF6ChCR1bUpvvrXqI3xetoXRWLtvy9rbR9qaejJWcCW/C5N1lFut@RaftVBuQ2I/Bm6orScroKnSUkYUANL2HIx4VF4Dy/eKp4phlLO4BsAEaP2AnAxhDXRS6nwJICZjgUIyrrYiW8zxwQdb9Dw)

Alternative 60 byter:

```
int f(int n){for(int o=n,k=1;n>0;)n=o+~-k*~(k*=2);return!n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU7RDoMgDHznK7rsBeZM2LKHRcB/MYhLoxaD@GT01xlqHy7Xa3s9O02lHRr6pYQUoeMHklg7H07qDT1781JUSyXI@GIv@8fO@4d5CxVcXALdSG3pjmSHpXWg0c8xuGas2XE/NkhcsJUBZEs4PdFIBai/H3lUpkUh8hwAO@A5gbg6gDm2VWX9EkFrwANOxVE7qLxyvQep2Jb@)

Ungolfed:

```
bool is_cyclops_number(int n)
{
    for (int k=1;; k*=2)
    {
        int z = n - (k - 1) * (k*2 + 1);
        if (z == 0)
            return true;
        if (z < 0)
            return false;
    }
}
```

## C (gcc) - x86 & most others, <s>41</s> 34 bytes

Returns zero for true and nonzero for false.

```
k;f(n){for(k=1;n+~-k*~(k*=2)>0;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsIwEETv@Yq1IOw2BqJ4ENb4JV5KNGWJRokVD6X9dGOKc5qZ97zpvS8lcsBEY3hkjG7LSc8mtjPG1u3oZJl4KpIGuHeSkNSoAKoKuHziLIMcD3u7pFatqXIACYCrgEL/CfDM1Q/YrC/n1GxAiCvI1@GdE1hWU/n6cOv6VzGfHw)

This demonstrates why I hate the implicit accumulator return value exploit that is commonly used in C submissions and less often in C++ submissions. It's fragile and very much architecture dependent. Here, it depends upon the comparison operator `>` not changing the value of the accumulator.

I did notice something quite curious regarding the [ARM gcc assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/o7W86q). It appears that the return value hack is being explicitly supported, by copying the intermediate result `r3`, which wasn't stored into any variable, into the accumulator `r0` once the loop is done:

```
        cmp     r3, #0
        bgt     .L2
        nop
        mov     r0, r3
```

Similarly on [PowerPC gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/9d64oc), where register `3` carries the return value:

```
        cmpwi 7,9,0
        bgt 7,.L2
        mr 3,9
```

Similarly on [RISC-V gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/44xqqv), where `a0` carries the return value:

```
       add   a5,a5,a4
       bgtz  a5,10144 <f+0x12>
       nop
       mv    a0,a5
```

In fact, it appears the trick works on all but one of the architectures on godbolt. On [MSP430 gcc 6.2.1](https://godbolt.org/z/sG3M6z), it yields the code with the equivalent of `return 0` (as the return value is passed through `R12`):

```
        MOV.B   #0, R12
        CMP.W   R13, R12 { JL .L2
        NOP
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, <s>41</s> 36 Bytes

```
x=2^Int([Log(A1,4)]):?[A1]=2*x^2-x-1
```

Run in the Immediate window, with Explicit Declaration turned off.  Input is cell `A1` of the active sheet.  Outputs True/False to the immediate window.

Uses the same logic as my [Excel Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181173/78385) to find the Cyclops number of the same number of bits (or 1 bit shorter if there are an even number!) and then compares that with the input.

Saves some bytes when calculating Cyclops numbers by reducing them to the form `y = 2x^2 - x - 1` (where `x = n-1` for the *nth* Cyclops number, or `x = 2^Int(Log([A1])/Log(4))` to find the largest Cyclops number with a lesser-or-equal number of bits) and storing x in a variable

(-5 Bytes thanks to [Taylor Scott](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61846/taylor-scott)!)

Comment: Instead of converting the log's base using log division, you can change it directly using `[...]` notation as `[(Log(A1,4)]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ç8┤-½Θ■
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8738b42dabe9fe&i=0%0A1%0A5%0A11%0A12%0A27%0A85%0A101%0A111%0A119&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 82 bytes

```
import Text.Printf
(`all`[(==)<*>reverse,("0"==).filter(<'1')]).flip($).printf"%b"
```

And a port of xnor's Python solution:

## Haskell, 47 bytes

```
import Data.Bits
\n->(2*n`xor`(2*n+3))^2==8*n+9
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 19 bytes

```
{1=(~x)+/~a&|a:2\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtrQVqOuQlNbvy5RrSbRyiimovZ/iVW1SnRlXZFVmkKFdUJ@trVGQlpiZo51hXWldZFmbC1XSbSBgoK1YSyQYQhkGIAYpjARS5iIoQGUYWQOlbIwhUsZQhmGcIYlUM1/AA)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`2\x` the bits of `x`

`a:` assign to `a`

`a&|a` *and* between `a` and its reverse (`|a`)

`~` *not*

`+/` sum

`(~x)` use "not `x`" as the initial value for the sum. this is to correct for `2\x` returning an empty list of bits when `x` is 0

`1=` compare with 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
b:ṭ¤0C1=∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P8nq4c61h5YYOBvaPupY/v@/oaElAA)

[Verify All Test Cases](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P8nq4c61h5YYOBvaPupY/j/aQMFUwchcwdDQUsFQAYgNFCxMgaQhUMQw9lHbxEPL/gMA)

```
b:		% convert to binary and dup
  ṭ		% is it a palindrome?
        ∧	% and
   ¤0C		% is the count of zeros
      1=	% equal to 1?
		% implicit print top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```
[2~rd0<B]dsBx1kz2/szsi[1r-si]sC[zlz=Cli*siz0<M]sMz1=Cz1<Mlip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxC4MwFIT3/ArnQmleQGwlLjoHHNxCJuPw8FGKLwV5Q/96SmwHl@@44@7inE2TvflsUds@RO53WMXcWBg9bFfGwIMXkm4gvDCKti6wE@gGAesIX9mraeFU8RvT0qower1ymik9fVuFkRKdLk@7wJPSNO0VFNQFj8MeoWkK7/UvOSoAfym1/AU)

`dc` has no native truthy/falsy values (conditionals either execute a macro or they don't); using 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy, I hope that's ok.

```
[2~rd0<B]dsBx          # Basic breakdown into binary. Every digit is a stack entry. Luckily this
                       # also leaves an extra 0 on the stack.
1k                     # Set precision to one - needed it at 0 for the binary-ifier.
z2/sz                  # Divide the stack depth by 2 and store it in 'z'. This is why we're lucky
                       # that the binary-ifier leaves an extra bit on the stack! Numbers with even 
                       # numbers of binary digits will now have an odd number & this value will be
                       # (whatever).5 which... isn't a valid stack depth.
si                     # Seed 'i' which is our truthiness register w/ that extra 0
[1r-si]sC              # Macro 'C' toggles the top of stack between 0 and 1 by subtracting it from 1.
                       # It stores this in 'i'. This is the only way 'i' ever becomes 1.
[zlz=Cli*siz0<M]sM     # First we test if we're at the position of the stack that matches up with 
                       # 'z', and run 'C' if so. Thus, if we're in the 'Cyclops' position (the
                       # middle), we'll flip that from a 0 to a 1 or vice versa. Next we load 'i'
                       # and multiply it by top of stack, putting that back in 'i'. For the first half
                       # this whole thing does nothing but multiply stuff by zero. In the middle
                       # position (if there is one) it sets 'i' to 1 if it's a zero. For the rest of
                       # the digits, it multiplies by '1' if things are ok, and '0' if there's another
                       # (Cyclops-invalidating) zero.
z1=Cz1<M               # 1 and 0 don't work w/o special treatment. Run 'C' if it's one of these, 
                       # otherwise start 'M'
lip                    # Print 'i'
```

Golfed off two bytes because my brain was fried and I was using a wasteful, convoluted method of toggling between 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `--extendedglob`, 30 bytes

```
>$[[##2]$1]
<`ls|rev`~*0*0*~1#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwU214tQSBd18hdSKktS8lNSU9Jz8JK60_CIFQwWNagM9PVMDg1pNDY2lpSVpuhb77FSio5WVjWJVDGO5bBJyimuKUssS6rQMgLDOUBmiaLummp2-ln5eaU6OmpqNjY2KIVdRroKWJkR2wQIIDQA)

Outputs via exit code (`0` = is a cyclops number, `1` = not a cyclops number).

- `>` - create the file

  - `$[[##2]$1]` - the input in base 2
- `` <`ls|rev`~00*~1# `` - try to find a file that matches this pattern:

  - `` `ls|rev` `` - the file in reverse (i.e. palindromic)
  - `~` - but not this pattern

    - `*0*0*` - more than one 0
  - `~` - and not this pattern either

    - `1#` - one or more 1s

The exit code depends on whether or not the pattern matched and the file could be found.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 21 bytes

```
b2JXXRA'0==j'0CN1==&&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZC7DsIwDEX3fIXFwENiiJEQMHRAbAwMLLC2yBBQlaiJCyqPby8NpahqgQyRZfnec@0otTG5JKX8lkh3scc8Gi232/W8J4Pg1JOLFQZBt5s/NnEuwb87sE1ZZUVRNnzL6DgrPoIrWQMhQ2dHmsl2BL4n9mHsMl/gR7QzmsOjdqDNS0dOjJsIlPgLURLErAWQpaYG4EtFgD6dSQMrkx4URIYVhJa8HSt6Ww4EypZn1friKUaTZupiHv@mno6/EPyydYKyRBWjPERd4Pf8J8C2AH2zEWpYnJ9ryRBnzWVewt/LPAE)

```
b2   # As binary
J    # Duplicate
XX   # Split into chars (RA is supposed to work with strings but doesn't)
RA   # Get middle
'0== # Is 0
j    # Reorder stack
'0CN # Count of 0s
1==  # ==1
&&   # And
```

Shorter, but sadly doesn't work for zero case because `2dg` returns empty list

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 16 bytes

```
2dgJRAj0CN-.||n!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBPDwExEMXv/RTDiQTpSARHcXNwcHFeDCWbNtpZsqzPvrZqZa0/PTSTybz5vTerxMbkjgnl16N0Z7vP@5vdbDE5yOm828sy3chvyzhHCf5lwDZhlRZFaPiW0XFafAQXsgYihuaaNJNtCnxObKPYpb7Al2htNEd77UCbh46cGNQRKPEXIhDE@AMgg6YC4HNJgBadSAMrk@wUrAwriCz5dazoubItQtS3nWXry07RH9ZdF/P41/Vo8IXgw1YJyhKVjHCIqsDn/CfATwH6Zs1Upzg/V5whjuthHsLfYe4)

```
2dg # Base 2 as list of digits
J   # Duplicate
RA  # Get middle
j   # Reorder stack
0CN # Count 0s
-.  # Decrement (i.e 1 -> truthy, else falsy)
||n!# not or (Check both zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
b0₌O€vL≈=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJiMOKCjE/igqx2TOKJiD0iLCIiLCIxMTkiXQ==)

Output 0 → False, 1 → True

```
b         # To binary array
 0        # Push 0
  ₌       # Parallel apply next two operators:
   O      #   Count how many "0" and
    €     #   Split at "0"
     vL   # Lengths of parts
       ≈  # If its equal return 1
        = # If its equal number of zeroes, return 1, else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.7, 60 bytes

```swift
{nil != (try?#/(1+)0\1/#.wholeMatch(in:String($0,radix:2)))}
```

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/g6auok4z5zg53nltya7vrlv3hi)

Swift 5.7 introduced Regex literals, delimited by `#/`...`/#`. This code attempts to match the regex `(1+)0\1` against the string, and returns whether or not it succeeded. Input may be any `BinaryInteger`.

I'm not certain that this is shorter than bit manipulation, but this is shorter than the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang 37 bytes

```
f(x)->Y=2*X bxor (2*X+3),Y*Y==8*X+9.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 55 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.875 bytes

```
b†Ḃ₍⁼∑≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsImLigKDhuILigo3igbziiJHiiYgiLCIiLCIwXG4xXG41XG45XG4xMFxuMjdcbjg1XG4xMDFcbjExMVxuMTE5Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
0111000000100000010011101011101001010010110100100111000
```

```
b†Ḃ₍⁼∑≈­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌­
b†       # ‎⁡Convert to binary, then invert each bit
  Ḃ      # ‎⁢Push the list of inverted bits and its reverse
   ₍  ≈  # ‎⁣is each item in the list equal?
    ⁼    # ‎⁤does the reverse of the inverted bits equal the inverted bits
     ∑   # ‎⁢⁡sum of the bits
‎
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

7 byter (before encoding) with a completely different method.

Edit: Apparently this is a port of Jelly but I didn't realize

‎⁢⁣Since the equality check can only be 0 or 1, and the sum of the inverted bits is always at least 1 for any nonzero number, the values can only be equal if there is exactly one "1" in the inverted binary representation and that "1" is directly in the middle

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 69 bytes

```
: f ( n -- ? ) >bin [ dup reverse = ] [ [ 48 = ] count 1 = ] bi and ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoIwGIR3nuJGHSCWaESIOhoWFuNEHEr5iUQo9W8x4ekRq8t9ly@Xa6RyA8@3a15cUkhmOVk8iTV16KV7REayJYZhcm4y3GoHS6@RtCKLLMiLFGpS3WBCPfYVsZ1TNFhBIwxxxhqnqtUoUY8GTO9lQDjivpgS28RXNYzLq/C9aiF1jWwWy0sU7HyK2CPeeyR/uflNhDh8OX8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <strike>135</strike> 130 bytes

Uses the Formula described here: [A129868](https://oeis.org/A129868)

```java
(n)->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,16).map(r->((Double)(Math.pow(2,2*r+1)-(Math.pow(2,r)-1)-2)).intValue()).anyMatch(c->c==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI7T8MwGJybX2F1smlj5VE3QaUZEEJi6BSJBTEY16QpiW05TlFV9bcH0wfFCBS8@NPp7rs7y2u6ob5UXKyXb11ZK6kNWFsMt6as8GsrmCmlwPenYeaxijYNyJmmhq3AzgP2qPalKhloDDX22shyCWpaCpgbXYri6RlQXTTIkgeGN@a8C3qDDgrkZxe/xmhOa/wgTH6cNBUFh8E4nCJcUwW1n0F4J60fR3BBzQor@Q6jcXSlRyHyv0Ma@RaJEMKlMI@0ajm0MxXbxWdyyPyMzecCdcAboNmhxt7zvN/bOLHPw42NyQuux7dSVpyKDDC0O2w4nHzbGF5j2Rqs7DOYSsBhMB@CEWCYKlVtYYBOxn/RQ4ce9tGJQye92yN3fdQniBJHECV9gtRNlPZHCn5UDnpLp3E6JeTaNTpifdI4JiSI44mjPYP/FJPfxL09o3CSTEiQJm7uC4y@vuS@@wA)

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work with all positive integers? It [works fine up to a million](https://tio.run/##bVCxTsMwEJ3jr/B4po3VdkNpMwBCYugUiQUxHK6Tuji2ZV@KKtRvD26hgkrcck/vTvfeux3usfRBu93mfTR98JH4LnNyIGNlOzhFxjv5@AMqpiymxBsVkdSWfzKeKwxv1iieCCm3vTcb3qNx0FA0rnt55Ri7JPJyQTrR5RawYgQnyvpXL1HU2MsnR803iug6fW990huYTW@F7DFALGuAB59FtYA10lYG/wGL6eImTuai/EtFUWZmIYQ0jp7RDhoyRndYn@yDKmu1WjkxclaI6pzlyBj7P9KV9wtYZq@603F6573V6GquRM7Z@sghS3JczSpczmfnqnAyEawoTAtKYgj2AChORNEcEule@oFkyD8j6/LkYug4fgE), and I see no reason why it'd stop working.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181128/is-it-a-cyclops-number-nobody-knows/181174?noredirect=1#comment436477_181128
"...any positive integer can be tested". Example where it wont work anymore: 2096127. This is due to that i only test the first 11 of the OEIS A129868 Numbers. could do more maybe, but it will not work vor ANY positive integer i think

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't actually answer the problem, you should edit it to make it work or delete it. Marking an answer as non-competing isn't a free pass, it should still be valid.

Comment: It's funny how you first say everything is fine, and after i point you where the OP post that limit (that wasn't really defined before this answer was posted) you aggressively force to make it work now or deleting it without seemingly to know the timeline between answer and the point it was invalid :P

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come across as aggressive. I also didn't say everything was fine, I just asked to be sure whether the answer was valid. Also the timeline isn't really relevant, if the answer is currently invalid it should be fixed or deleted.

Comment: Currently it is unkown if this or any other answer is valid because OP don't really defined what he meant with any positive integer as a integer could be 2 things, one has a maximum value the other not. And after my last change it is working with the 32-bit signed Integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90778/discussion-between-grimy-and-serverfrog).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift, 161 bytes**

```
func c(a:Int)->Int{
    let b=String(a,radix:2)
    let f=b.firstIndex(of:"0")
    return a>=0 && f==b.lastIndex(of:"0") && f?.encodedOffset==b.count/2 ? 1 : 0
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxCsIwFIXhvU9x6VBasDUWp0DauZODT5AmuRIoN5DeYkF89hgVHDzDWf5vvXvkc0q4kQFTazkRN@2Q/1FA3uIYZnXl6OlW60PU1u@yb34N1dyhjytPZN1eB5SlKL85Ot4igR6UgKrKMtNF/8lPGTtHJlhnL4ir4zc0YSM@9jDCCSSI4pnSCw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 32 bytes

```perl
$_=(sprintf'%b',$_)=~/^(1*)0\1$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRisIwEEXf8xWDdLEVxYxQ1Af/ZFmpMppCSUoyunRZ9tPNNlZFozUPYRjm3jN3arJV7n2yXqWutqXm3fBjMxwn62z1N/1KcZTJT0ym3ksI7xfYHlg1bdE1Qsvoqmk/gh@yBgqGwZY0kx0IvEzsiso1ocCbaGs0F6V2oM1ZR07kMQIl9iE6gkCMAVJiBODvKwFSOpIGVuawV7AxrKCwFOxY0cUyEzh78kTZ6ylm83jrdh7fbr3IXxBC2HuCskRXRneIe0HI@U6AzwIMzWipcXt@frjnMg5zFvaHOZmaS6Odn1T1Pw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 201 bytes (compilable)

Hmm, a different approach in java, runnable on commandline (so there is much to cut out).

```
class Z{public static void main(String[]a{a=Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(a[0])).split("0");System.out.println(a.length==0?1:(a.length!=2?1:a[0].length()-a[1].length()+a.length-2)==0?1:0);}}
```

prints 0 for non cyclops and 1 for cyclops numbers.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you can remove `public `. Is there a `)` missing after `String[]a`? `a.length==0` -> `a.length < 1`, again later (maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

The shortest code should be this:

```
preg_match('`^(?<l>1*)0\k{l}$`', decbin($n));
```

Here the script to test it:

```
$inputs = [
    0,
    1,
    5,
    9,
    10,
    27,
    85,
    101,
    111,
    119,
];


function isCyclop($n) {
    return preg_match('`^(?<l>1*)0\k{l}$`', decbin($n));
}

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo "$input : ".(isCyclop($input)?'truthy':'falsy').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 96 bytes

```
n->{String[]a=Integer.toBinaryString(n).split("0");return n==0||a.length==2&&a[0].equals(a[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xa8MwEIV3/wqRIUhDhJzVqEOHQIdOGY2HsyO5SpSTI50DwfFvd1WXrukd3MG99z7uDHfYnU@XpfOQEvsEh1PhkEy00Bl2mNoQvAFklucrQ1HNxTC23nUsEVBe9@BO7Jpz/EjRYV83DGKfxFQcmGV6wd3b9KeA/sjo3kRJ4d0hxMevwlHINHhHfKM2ooqGxogMtVbPJ0hvsKcvrffbLdSqkeY2gk8c6rLJ7yxVcXwkMlcZRpJDxpFHbqXlqlVCvFDLXOpnvHaptf8llUqtsNU5z8s3)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 6 (26 bytes)

```
{so .base(2)~~/^(1*)0$0$/}
```

Comment: You can remove the `so`, since the output can just be truthy/falsey, but it ends up the same as [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181133/76162)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 87 bytes

```
a:qTa<=1{((a%2)=0)?(x:"0".x)(x:"1".x)a//:2}1=a?x:"1".xsc:x^"0"x=0|#x%2=1&(c0)=(c1)&#c=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcqxCoAgEIDhd1GUuyU9t6TDl2gODqc2o@WgenZLaPv4@dveepd8rLIwXQDiEnLEAppNNJPiAA1ICDk9xFL@ctas2zcpx9uqS0weakSGSuht5dQ70fwC)

Comment: Try a simpler approach next time.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
YTBa^0 2=#y&$=y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MsQpMc5AwchWuVJNxbby////RuYA)

A much shorter pip solution.

### Explanation

```
YTBa^0 2=#y&$=y a → input integer
YTBa^0         Yank binary representation of a into var y, split on 0's
       2=#y     Length of y = 2?
           &$=y and all items of y are equal?
                Implicit output of boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 45 bytes

```
!v:2%$2,:1%-:1(?!
1\~
*>l2=?vl3=?0${*
$0=*n;>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X7HMykhVxUjHylBV18pQw16RyzCmjkvLLsfI1r4sx9jW3kClWotLxcBWK8/a7v///7plRuYA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 66 <sup><s>69</s></sup> bytes

> -3 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat !

```java
n->{int r=0,i=0;for(;i<16;)r+=n-~(1<<i)==1<<i+++i?1:0;return r>0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU89b4MwEJ3hV5wyGTkgWDLEOJW6VUqnjFUHhxh0qWNHh4kURfSvUxvoW86653sfV/VQ@fXyM92Hs8EGGqP6Hj4VWnilKQSg9Zpa1Wg4hhWsODtntLLQssCDzcTMjMtJ75UPWkcwICebH17xD8lyi7IUrSMmsK52IiMubf7LqrrGTMo4OOf4Vu1LQdoPZIEOpRinRXxNuIo/HF7gFnKykye03dc3KOr6LGRMokW0jHaA9a6MCC/OZ3pu1TJThPDZvElOz97rW@EGX9yDmjeWId/AHjb8I/TvNBXevaNV9Fzs4qVYpMY0Gf/bj9Mf)

Don't hesitate to ask if this needs any explanation!

---

Alternative solution really close using Streams (**70 bytes**) :

```java
n->"0123456789:;<=>?".chars().anyMatch(e->n-~(1<<e-48)==1<<2*(e-48)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃDḲ=s0c=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWax7uaHZ5uGOTbbFBsu2S4qTkYqjEgsWGhpYQJgA)

Port of emirps's Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ḃDḲ=s0c=  # Implicit input
ḃD        # Convert to binary; duplicate
  Ḳ=s     # Check if palindrome; swap
     0c=  # Equals the count of 0s?
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Uiua, 17 characters (32 bytes UTF-8)

`↥↧≍⇌.∶=1/+¬.⋯∶=0.`

Explanation of ungolfed version:

```
↥⊃(↧⊃(≍⇌.)(=1/+¬)⋯)(=0)­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
↥⊃                   (=0)  # ‎⁡n is zero, or
                  ⋯       # ‎⁢the binary expansion of n
   ↧⊃      (=1/+¬)         # ‎⁣sums to 1 when all its bits are flipped
   ↧⊃(≍⇌.)                # ‎⁤and matches itself reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Adding to the collection of 8-byte Japt solutions; can't seem to come up with anything shorter.

```
¢¶¢Ôp¢èT
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=orai1HCi6FQ&input=WzAgMSA1IDkgMTAgMjcgODUgMTAxIDExMSAxMTldCi1tUg) (Includes all test cases)

```
¢¶¢Ôp¢èT     :Implicit input of integer U
¢            :Convert to binary
 ¶           :Check for equality with
  ¢Ô         :  Convert U to binary and reverse
    p        :  Repeated
     ¢è      :    Convert U to binary and count the occurrences of
       T     :      0
```